# Is Stack Overflow violating its Creative Commons license by closing questions?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, legal

I voted to close the question [C++ or Java or JS Library for creating browser add ons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24494736/c-or-java-or-js-library-for-creating-browser-add-ons) as off-topic as per requesting a library. The asker became upset, and said that Stack Overflow is violating the [Creative Commons license](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/legalcode) Article 4:

[image: Screenshot]

> I think this is preposterous. This site was about answering
>   programming questions and this is a perfectly legitimate question. My
>   question did not ask for a recommendation for a particular library
>   rather it was looking for an existential example in general. However,
>   the reaction that I see here is an illustration of elitism and it is
>   extremely counter productive and goes against very basic principles of
>   free exchange of ideas. The way this site has been reacting to
>   questions is quite reprehensible and warrants a revocation of usage of
>   the Creative Commons license as it violates Article 4.

It's not clear, but the user may have been referring specifically to Article 4(a)

> You may not offer or impose any terms on the Work that alter or restrict the terms of this License or the recipients' exercise of the rights granted here under.

I'm assuming that the user is completely wrong, but can somebody confirm or deny this, and if it's wrong, perhaps remove it? Legal citations shouldn't be given out lightly, I would think.

Note: **I am not a lawyer** and I don't pretend to be. :P

Comment: It might be worth posting a copy of 'Article 4' into the question. Also, as we often note on [main]: if you want legal advice, ask a *lawyer*, not a *programmer*.

Comment: I do. I'd like to be able to go one day without closing a question on Main but it's people like this that make it so hard to find a gem of a question. :(

Comment: how is refusing anything a violation of a CC license?

Comment: @DanielA.White that's what I want to confirm lol plus if something like that is incorrectly cited it should be removed so that nobody is falsely led astray

Comment: Well, that's *that* question gone. So, who's for shawarma?

Comment: @DavidThomas well first I need to accept an answer to this meta. And then shawarma.

Comment: Ok it's shawarma time!

Comment: All CC licenses have a clause that states that you are required to get your question answered if the question is published under a CC license. The only one that does not have that clause is the CC-BY-NA, i.e. Creative Commons Attribution No-Answers.

Comment: @unit3524344 Alas, it can't be triggered on purpose.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: You almost got me.. but I did check if such a license exists :)

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes yeah, I don't see any mention of questions and answers in [the license](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/legalcode)...oh, [there is no CC-BY-NA license](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/). I see, you were being sarcastic.

Comment: @NickDugger Not caring about licensing is how Stack Overflow got into the ridiculous state of using an entirely unsuitable license to distribute code. If there were an issue (there doesn't seem to be), we should care.

Comment: @JeremyBanks: If the point of SO was to distribute code, I'd agree. As it is, though, I'd say that, if you copy-paste non-trivial amounts code *verbatim* from SO into your software, complying with the CC license is likely to be the *least* of your problems. (Of course, there are [occasional exceptions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14420754/isaac-cipher-in-php), and those should certainly be explicitly released under some more appropriate license.)

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Whether it's the point or a problem, it is undeniably the reality and should be addressed. There are plenty of 20-line functions that are copied endlessly, and even if those might be considered fair use, it would better for everyone if the licensing situation was clear and appropriate.

Comment: @JeremyBanks: I agree that it's not an appropriate software license, but I don't see what's to be done about it. Those snippets were contributed to the site under CC-BY-SA, which AFAIK doesn't permit their redistribution under any existing software license. So either they're fair use or they're infringing, but that ship has sailed. You can't get a new license from all their authors (in particular those no longer using the site). It would be nice if future code were contributed to SO under a completely permissive license (equivalent to public domain) though.

Comment: Hmm, interesting, my initial thought is that he might be referring to article 4(d) - "if You Reproduce, Distribute or Publicly Perform the Work [...] You must not distort, mutilate, modify or take other derogatory action in relation to the Work which would be prejudicial to the Original Author's honor or reputation."

Comment: @SteveJessop For the past that's true, but for all future questions we could think about a dual/triple/whatever licensing.

Comment: @JeremyBanks Only the copyright owner, i.e. the original questioner or answerer can take legal actions against usage of their code in e.g. commercial products. Stackoverflow is completely on the safe side here - the users who copy and use the answers are not.

Comment: I can't see the original question because it was removed. I would therefore have to agree with his claim of censorship on that basis. Benefit of the doubt must be given to individuals, not collectives. That would be to the original poster, not to stack overflow.

Comment: @user426364: that's fine. But the question isn't about censorship (which SO is entitled to perform for all that we don't personally want to be censored). It's about CC licensing, and the benefit of the doubt on legal interpretations does *not* automatically go to some random person on the internet who's upset about censorship ;-)

Comment: I find programmers MUCH more logical than most lawyers and I'm great at picking out loopholes and rewriting contracts...

Comment: @Dave all I'm good for is writing loopholes.. I mean loops. D:

Comment: People really get their panties in a knot over this kind of stuff?  Well, let's see if this question gets closed:  "I can has cheeseburger?"

Comment: @Steve Jessop, I didn't mean to say that censorship is always recognized. It comes in many forms, most of which people would rather NOT recognize. Some random person on the internet is sticking up for your rights even if you don't recognize they are being taken from you. If you thought about censorship, you'd recognize it everywhere. Because it is everywhere. If you have ever told anyone to shut up, guess what. You're pro-censorship. We can talk legalese if you want, but tomato tomahto.

Comment: @user426364: yes, I often think about and recognize censorship. No, SO is not taking away my rights or those of that user. No, that user is not sticking up for my rights in respect of censorship. They're claiming that a particular license places a constraint on SO (not to delete content). This question is not about whether SO censors (it does), it's about whether that specific legal claim is true concerning the CC-BY-SA license. It's pretty simple, their right to speak does not imply an obligation on SO to provide them with a platform. They can speak in the street, I'm not required to listen.

Comment: @Steve Jessop. This is why I don't participate in online discussions anymore. Everything is what you say it is, not what I say it is. So, basically, you've negated my argument by saying that no one is under any legal obligation to protect users's speech. Duh. That's really how censorship got its start in the first place. This civilization prides itself on its dysfunctional legal process. It's not even that people don't know it's dysfunctional -- they know, and still swear by it. There's really nothing more for me to say here. Let's let the legal wheels just churn us up and spit us out, then.

Answer (score 197, accepted):

The claim is utter nonsense.

Article 4(a) of [The Creative Commons license](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/legalcode) begins thusly:

> You **may** Distribute or Publicly Perform the Work...

Emphasis mine.  Not must.  May.

The license under which users submit their content to SO grants SO permission to redistribute their content. It does not *force* SO to redistribute their content forever - if SO wants to stop distributing their content (e.g. by closing and deleting a question), that is in no way a violation of the CC license.

Comment: Even though it can be frustrating for the user (I think a low-rep user cannot see his own questions when they are deleted?), I agree though, that it's not SO's job to be an everlasting archive for bad questions.

Comment: +1 - I was tempted to respond, but this already hits the key point - I'm editing a line or two in above to make it even clearer.

Comment: The relevant law is *copy*right. SO has a copy of what the OP wrote in their browser window. If the OP neglected to retain a copy of the original when SO deletes its copy... well tough.

Comment: @Raedwald OP can still access recently deleted questions himself...

Comment: Why doesn't SO make up their own license with a clause that says, "if your s*** sucks then we reserve the right not to continue dealing with it!"

Comment: I think this is an area where the user may have confused things with the GPL, which I believe does have a clause saying that any source code must be made available for 3 years from the date of original release/publication, or something to that effect. That, however, is the responsibility of the person RELEASING the code (ie the USER on SE, not the SITE). Either way, it doesn't appear to have any relevance to any of the CC licenses

Comment: @GolezTrol - A low-rep user can see their deleted questions if they have a link to them (no matter how old the deleted question is). They can also see a list of their questions deleted in the last 60 days by clicking the "recent deleted questions" link on their Questions list in Activity.

Answer (score 29):

Legalistic blather like this is in the same bucket as all the other comments there that don't have to do with clarifying the question or why it was closed: "non-constructive".

Why are we even talking about this? If the user wants to raise some kind of legal challenge to SO's practice of closing questions, making little remarks on the site itself isn't going to get em very far.

Ignore it, flag if you want, and move on to focusing on something more meaningful.

Comment: Awesome. Last sentence of your's. `Ignore it`, `flag if you want`, and `move on to focusing on something more meaningful.` said it all :)

Comment: -1 Does not actually answer the question. At no point did the Asker ask what he should have done. He asked if a concern was legitimate. If you think a question is bad, downvote it, and if you need to explain, leave a comment. And, for goodness sake, Asker, don't encourage people by picking an answer that doesn't follow the rules.

Comment: An answer that challenges or explicitly denies the premise of the question is still an answer, @trlkly. See also [Is "don't do it" a valid answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8891)

Comment: @JoshCaswell You didn't do that, though. The question is "Is this guy's claim correct that Stack Exchange is violating the Creative Commons license when it deletes a post?" You didn't challenge the premise of the question nor did you attempt to answer it. Again, at no point did the Asker ask what he should do, which is what you actually answered.

Comment: More than two-thirds of this answer -- my first two paragraphs -- are precisely about the legal claim, @trlkly. Only the last is a suggestion for RUJordan.

Comment: Still, neither answers the question "Is this guy's claim correct that Stack Exchange is violating the Creative Commons license when it deletes a post?" Taken separately, the first paragraph answers "Are legal comments constructive comments?" And the second "Do such comments have any legal value?" The second also throws in the part that led to me saying you should have downvoted the question, as the obvious answer to the rhetorical question is that we shouldn't be discussing this, hence it is a bad question. I believe we are at an impasse; nothing will change my vote besides editing the answer.

Comment: I _did_ downvote the question, @trlkly, and you're more than welcome to express your opinion by downvoting my answer. We will indeed have to agree to disagree, but I'll keep your feedback in mind.

Answer (score 20):

Being generous to the person in question, they think that deleting the question restricts or interferes with  the license under which people have already received it.

I am not a lawyer either, but it seems unlikely to me that this belief is sustained in law. There are a couple of easy mistakes that would lead to this conclusion:

- that SO in some way restricts you from distributing any copies you may have made of the deleted question. I don't think it does, although it *looks* as if it does because SO's definition of "attribution" is to link to the question. This is not possible if it has been deleted, but I'm pretty sure that the resolution to that quandary is that SO doesn't get the attribution in the form it prefers, *not* that since it's impossible to attribute to SO's satisfaction you cannot redistribute. SO (as a re-distributer of content under the license) doesn't actually have the right to arbitrarily define what constitutes attribution, so I suspect that whatever definition it makes can only be considered the *preferred* attribution. Of course since CC licenses aren't widely tested in court, in some sense this person can come and have a go if they think they have a case.
- that SO's *practical* interference with your ability to download the question from them again, is in some way a *legal* restriction on your right to redistribute. I think it pretty clearly isn't, but I see how someone might misinterpret a right to do something, as a right to be helped to do something. The license gives you the right to redistribute a copy you took, but it doesn't give you the right to get another copy from SO.

Being less generous to the person, they are imagining properties of the license that they would like but which in fact do not exist: specifically a responsibility to maintain these "very basic principles of free exchange of ideas".

Being ungenerous to the person, they're making stuff up because they're angry.

The appropriate response depends what you can assume about the person who wrote it. Treating it as a genuine legal misunderstanding, it would make sense to make a reasoned counter-claim except that it's off-topic for SO comments, issues about licensing belong here on meta. So the person should be directed here, probably combined with deletion. Treating it as spurious invention it would make sense to delete it without remark :-)

Comment: I do not like your structure "being-being-being". Why can't you give a straight answer? Do you think in one way now, and in another next minute?

Comment: @VividD: I do not know what is in the mind of the person who wrote this comment. I am a rational being, capable of considering hypotheticals. "Being generous" is just an idiom that means "in the hypothetical case that the questioner is somewhat admirable". If you dislike my rhetorical structure then that's unfortunate, but since the question is not, "what is in the mind of the person who wrote this", I don't feel obliged to stick to only one possibility.

Comment: I understood your idiom, but reserve my right to like or not like your answer/comment/opinion/style/substance, and reserve my right to say so. Do you have a problem with that?

Comment: @VividD: of course I don't have a problem with it, although naturally I will sometimes respond to such expressions of dislike.

Comment: All right then. The real friend is not the one who always talks nicely to you.

Comment: But as a straight answer to your second question: since I'm considering one hypothetical and then another, to that extent only I think one way now, and another way the next minute :-) The person who made the comment might be legally confused or might be knowingly making up rubbish in the hope of creating legal confusion.

Comment: The comments above fascinate me far more than they should...

Comment: @AndrewBarber I am being surprised about you being fascinated

Comment: I am fascinated by your surprise, @gnat. It strikes me that while certain people are likely to be surprised, others may or may not themselves be surprised. Additionally, we may see cases where some are fascinated by this, and others not. In all cases, individuals should decide what they believe their best course of action is, and seek qualified, legal advice regarding it before proceeding. However, they should not necessarily trust this advice, because... <GAK>...

Comment: @VividD Being slightly humorous about the matter, I must say: Being that your negativity towards this user was obvious at first, I am slightly perturbed that you seem to be claiming to be one of this user's "real friends", by not always talking nicely to him. Or perhaps, I'm just Being overly complicated.

Comment: @jt0dd sometimes there just aren't enough +1's. :)

Comment: I am sorry I was trying to avoid a flame war but these posts are just picking a nerve about a pet peeve of mine. This happens way too often on the internet and even in general that "free speech" is used as a firewall to defend absolutely anything. People are entitled to their opinions and the right to express them, but these opinions have to be expressed in REASON and not as judgemental sound-bytes. "Do you think in one way now, and in another next minute?" is a judgemental sound-byte and @VividD that is unacceptable in any circumstances.

Comment: @gnat I am being perplexed about you being surprised about Andrew Barber being fascinated :D  But seriously, about the link providing attribution.  If you delete the question, you're no longer providing it, so attribution is no longer required either.  That seems pretty straightforward.  Resupplying a contributed work once does not obligate you to resupply it indefinitely.  I think that's the crux of the whole issue.

Comment: @jinglesthula: "attribution is no longer required either" -- I don't think that's correct. The license requires attribution, that's the "BY" part. Since the content includes author usernames, and furthermore since SO itself claims authorship as a compiler of separate works, the best form of attribution is to link to the question, which in turn links to the individual author pages where they're identified if they wish to be. But if SO takes down the question you're still obliged by the license to attribute to the authors and to SO. You'll just have to find another way to do it.

Comment: ... I've just realised there's a further physical impediment, actually. The "author" of a question or answer (who licensed SO to distribute it) might be more than one person, and only the edit history reveals all substantial edits. So once the question is deleted it might no longer be possible to credit all authors (which linking to the question does since the history is available that way). Tricky one -- if you didn't grab the history when you grabbed the content then you have no way of knowing whether you've identified all the authors of something that has been edited.

Comment: ... of course that still doesn't mean SO is violating the license, but it might mean that someone who continues distributing once SO has deleted the question is violating the license, unless they took their own copy of the edit history to distribute with the content. Lawyer needed.

Comment: @SteveJessop My point is that when the question is deleted, SO is no longer publishing, providing, or supplying the work.  There is no longer anything to provide attribution for.  SO at that point is not bound by the license any more than any other entity which is also not publishing, providing, or supplying the work.  Before the question is deleted, of course they are bound, and the link both works and serves well for attribution.

Comment: @jinglesthula: ah, I see what you mean. Yes, SO no longer has to provide attribution. Sorry, I thought you were responding to what I was saying about further distributors providing attribution in the form of the link.

Comment: @SteveJessop ah - gotcha.  Sorry about that :)

Answer (score 4):

Jeff Attwood mentions deleted questions on his blog in the article [New Programming Jargon](http://blog.codinghorror.com/new-programming-jargon/), saying that:

> Unfortunately, we don't have a good designated place for deleted "too fun" questions to live, but all Stack Exchange content is licensed under Creative Commons in perpetuity. Which means, with proper attribution, we can give it a permanent home on our own blogs.

10K rep users can continue to see deleted questions, and are still bound by Creative Commons restrictions.  I don't see any problems here.

Answer (score 1):

The Stack Exchange network is privately owned, right?  It's their site, they can allow or disallow content as they see fit.

I see this on forums that I used to administer, where sometimes when people claim "You're breaching my freedom of speech!" when we moderated out something that was inappropriate for the site.

Actually, no.  When you start paying for the hosting, then you MIGHT be able to have some input.  Until then, umm, nope :)

Comment: I agree with your free speech point, but I think that the original poster's argument was over the (apparent, but not really) violation of the Creative Commons license, specifically.

Comment: @Cupcake I think they were trying to use the Creative Commons license as a means to circumvent the private ownership of Stack Exchange (two words ;) ).

Comment: I think your two statemens do not hold: 1) Whether SO is privately owned or not is as relevent as if it rains or not; 2) Each poster (including you) "pay" to SO with their time and knowledge - SO lives from the content through ads etc. Posters do not depend on SO, but SO depends on posters.

Comment: @VividD Nobody holds a gun to the heads of anyone to post on SO.  Stack Exchange is a commercial entity who supply a resource *at their expense*.  Sure I put my time in, and that enrichens (I hope) the "product" that is StackOverflow.  They are ultimately responsible for what best achieves their aims.  My aims are to find resolution my technical problems and to help others to do the same.  SE's is to *ultimately* make money.  The two aims just happen to be mutually beneficial.  That still doesn't mean I have any say over what is commercially viable in the opinion of the owners of this site :)

Comment: @intracept please accept my greatest apologies for being nit-picky, but "Stack Overflow" [is officially two words](http://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance) (see *Proper Use of the Stack Exchange Name*), not one word like "StackOverflow". They should really do something about those logos, they result in ***a ton*** of extra edits needed by us OCD users to correct that sort of thing `:P`

Comment: @Cupcake Apology accepted, LOL :)  You will notice I did in fact get "Stack Exchange" correct in my comment ;)

Comment: XKCD explains free speech: http://xkcd.com/1357/

Comment: @AeroX I was actually thinking of this when I posted.  xkcd is great :)

Comment: Today I learned that free speech died because no one wanted to pay for it.  I guess it just wasn't valuable, after all.

Comment: This answer is entirely invalid.  The fact that they are privately owned is irrelevant.  The claim here is that SO agreed to the terms of a licence, and that that licence requires them to continue to host the content covered by the licence.  Who owns SO, or any discussion of "Free Speech" is entirely irrelevant to the claim being made.  The claim is invalid because the terms of the licence in question don't actually require what this user is claiming they do.  If it did, then SO would have to abide by them, private or not.  Of course, SO wouldn't agree to such terms...

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps the user was referring to section 4d:

> ... if You Reproduce, Distribute or Publicly Perform the Work ... , You must not
>   distort, mutilate, modify or take other derogatory action in relation
>   to the Work which would be prejudicial to the Original Author's honor
>   or reputation.

Closing the question was Obviously a derogatory action prejudicial to the Author's reputation...

Comment: It is neither. Closed questions do not affect one's reputation, either on the site or in the real world.

Comment: @CodyGray, actually, if they've been upvoted and then deleted, it does. To be honest, I don't think SO reputation and "real" reputation really match anyway. Maybe it shouldn't be called reputation.

Comment: I thought of this too. I think this could actually be a substantive objection. But there's a strong case to be made that SO is actually _enhancing_ the author's honor and reputation by preventing the rest of the world from seeing their bad question or answer!

Comment: @senderle That would apply to deletion, not closing...

Comment: @Servy, I disagree -- closing also reduces the number of people who see the post. Are you as likely to click on a link that says `[closed]`? I'm not. And if fewer people edit the question, it's less likely to appear on lists of questions with recent activity. Furthermore, closing often provides the author an opportunity to improve the question. Overall I think closing does a lot to help the reputation of an author.

Comment: I don't *think* that the CC license is intended to say that you can't judge, rate or criticise the work. If closing and deletion are prejudicial, then quite possibly there's a claim that so is downvoting (and publishing downvotes), or even stating disagreement with it (or publishing disagreement). That would make the license unsuitable for SO or for any kind of forum, so would be a *big* oversight on the part of Jeff and Joel's lawyers! I don't know, maybe "prejudicial to reputation" is a jargon term with a specific legal meaning that draws a line somewhere well-known to lawyers.