# Can I post a question on Meta that doesn't quite fit the Q&A format?

Tags: discussion, meta

I was thinking of asking a question here on Meta that's more suited as a blog
post or discussion forum.  I expect people will have questions for me in
response that might be too long to fit in comments.  So to cram it in to the
Stack Exchange format, I was thinking I could post something along the lines of
this:

> If you have any questions, feel free to post them as an answer here, and I'll respond in the comments.

Will that make it OK for people to post questions to me as answers?  Or is a
question like this completely unsuitable for the site because of the nature of
the Q&A format?

I know this is not OK for Stack Overflow because I spend all day long closing
questions from newbies who mistake the site for a discussion forum.  But I was
thinking that Meta was different.

Comment: Answers as feedback is okay, and used here on meta; answers asking for clarification? Why? That's what comments are for. And, regardless, what subject?

Comment: If you want to blog, write a blog. Can you elaborate what exactly you'd want to talk about and why it would suit meta?

Comment: Gonna say probably no.  Yeah, definitely no.  Nope.  All the nopes.

Comment: Very nicely done.

Comment: If you don't get this question, you should probably read [this currently featured mentoring announcement](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269992/1110381).

Answer (score 7):

Yes, there are certain types of questions that you can post on Meta that do not fit the standard format. These include, but are not limited to

- FAQ postings - they don't fit the format because they probably aren't an actual, real world problem you're facing, but rather a problem faced by many others that you're hoping to avoid.
- Rules and Features announcements - if you're one of the Stack Exchange developers (or maybe you're psychic and bet them to the punch) you might find yourself making an announcement about new features or rules entering the system. Again, these help to answer questions before they're asked.
- Community leadership/awareness - from time to time, the community takes part in various events such as Santa Hats, product placement (Skyrim on Arqade, anyone?) and as a recent example, a mentorship program. These are relevant and directly involve the community at large, but questions about such events would not be appropriate on the primary site so they're put on Meta instead.
- Bug Reports - while they might be disguised as a question sometimes, they're really community members raising awareness to the development team about potential problems. They aren't questions at heart because they don't have an answer (they can have a response, but not really an answer).

So yes, there are certainly a number of categories of "questions" that do not fit the traditional "I have a problem, I'll ask a question about it and get an answer" format that are still appropriate to be posted on Meta.

Comment: Don't forget using questions as a sandbox for the newly implemented features.  E.g., http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269754/stack-snippets-sandbox-try-it-out-here

Comment: Maybe we'll file that under "not limited to" =)

Comment: FAQ posts do fit into the question-answer format: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title e.g.

Comment: They don't really, Josh. The person who "asks" the FAQ is most likely an experienced user and isn't actually facing the problem themselves, which is supposed to be a hallmark of a good Stack Exchange question.

Comment: Huh?! [Can I answer my own questions, even if I knew the answer before asking?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17463)

Comment: Absolutely, there are some cases where the actual question asked is by someone with the problem, and it morphs over time into the canonical answer. I would consider them to be the exception, not the rule.

Answer (score -2):

It's no problem at all. Just one prerequisite: you need to first be [hired by StackExchange](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269992/volunteer-to-help-mentor-one-of-16-women-starting-a-career-in-programming?cb=1#comment85623_269992).

It's also possible that [having a relationship with the StackOverflow community](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269992/volunteer-to-help-mentor-one-of-16-women-starting-a-career-in-programming?cb=1#comment85696_269992) would be enough, but how strong that relationship would need to be is as yet unclear.

Comment: lol :-) (6 more characters to go)