# Mentor all underrepresented groups in ICT industry

Tags: discussion, feature-request

So, as we can see from [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269992/volunteer-to-help-mentor-one-of-16-women-starting-a-career-in-programming?cb=1) SO is going to mentor women because they are underrepresented and discriminated in ICT industry.

If you are getting SO into politics, I believe you should do this the right way, helping all in need.

Reading statistics about the ICT field I came to the conclusion that women are not the most discriminated against group in ICT, but black people.

The GSS reveals the following racial distribution among computer programmers:

White -- 75.6%

Black -- 8.1%

Other -- 16.3% (most of whom are Chinese or Indian).

The male to female rate is 70-30 in most countries.

I have met many women in all teams where I worked, being frontend or backend, but I never met a black guy or girl.

Comment: `If you are getting SO into politics, I believe you should do this the right way, helping all in need.` This is not a productive criticism of any social effort. "If you're donating to ALS research, why aren't you also donating to breast cancer research, since it kills more people?"

Comment: @DavidRobinson It's not a legitimate analogy. SO can have 15 mentors for women and 15 mentors for black people without any considerable extra effort. It's not like you have 10$ and you have to make a decision, ALS or cancer.

Comment: Exactly what is the ratio of white to black people in a given society?  Males and females make up approximately 50% each.  Therefore 30% is far below parity of the demographic in general.

Comment: @Claudiu, and what about black women? Do we multiply under-representation by 8.1% or something? Look, your stats are cool and all, but where I come from we don't really know what "coloured" means anymore, so we focus more on where progress can be made, e.g. gender.

Comment: To add to my above comment, it is very, very rare to find women in the highly technical roles.  In the twenty years I've been in this industry I could count on one hand the number of other female programmers I've worked with.  Most seem to be working in business analysis or other less technical areas.  So that 30% you're quoting may be for women in IT in general but not for fully technical roles.  That number would be considerably lower.

Comment: Are you actually proposing mentoring for _everyone_ (post title) or just a particular racial group (post body)?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi `where I come from we don't really know what "coloured" means anymore` I am curious in which place you are living that does not discriminate against black people. Closing your eyes does not solve the issue. Why can't you consider that progress can be made in different racial groups and not only in gender?

Comment: @Claudiu: `SO can have 15 mentors for women and 15 mentors for black people without any considerable extra effort.` It's no extra effort to select, organize and coordinate mentors? (If that were the case, why not just start it for 1500 women?) In any case, you might be missing that this is an expansion of an existing [Fog Creek Fellowship](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269992/volunteer-to-help-mentor-one-of-16-women-starting-a-career-in-programming?cb=1). Edit: Shog said what I was trying to say much more clearly in his answer.

Comment: @JaneS I agree with you, but that's not my point. And I'm sure you agree with me that black people (men and women) are discriminated in this industry, possibly as much as women. Especially for managerial positions, as you said. How many black CEOs do you know in the field?

Comment: @Claudiu I don't disagree with your point at all, but just the way you are trying to make it seems to be trying to undermine this particular effort that is being made _one step at a time_ to address various inequalities.

Comment: It has to start from somewhere. Kudos to [se] for pulling such initiative and wishing a bright future for such programs!

Comment: Sorry I had to edit to retract close and down votes. Let's discuss how this could be a feature.

Comment: I down voted your question, not because I disagree with your assertion about representation, but because I'm against implementing artificial quotas to solve nebulous social issues.

Comment: I'm in favour of minority assistance programs, but the OP is not raising this in good faith. They appear to be opposed to the initiative on the other thread.

Comment: @DavidRobinson Regarding your first comment, isn't the criticism that donating to ALS research is inefficient in lives per moneys valid?

Comment: Sorry, but the development is where the ability counts, not the group belonging. The most underrepresented group is and always will be the intellectually handicapped. You can't do anything about that. As for that all mentoring/dementoring stuff, I'm tired of it and I'll let that nonsense to SciFi, but pastafariasing it won't bring anything possible to common sense.

Answer (score 34):

Ok, sure, great idea - [**how?**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268779/can-we-make-this-meta-site-work-for-mentoring)

I'm serious - this isn't a trivial problem to solve. We're trying a test run with 16 people to see if this is even feasible, and there's a separate organization organizing the mentees. If you have any specific ideas or better yet connections, send 'em our way - there's a "contact us" link at the bottom of every page. I can't promise anything - like I said, we really have no idea if this even works right now, and meta posts + Google Docs sure as hell ain't gonna scale - but if there's a real need for this, and a real opportunity to meet that need... Then it's certainly worth a try.

But please, don't get all frustrated because we're not trying to boil the ocean on day 1. This isn't something we're really geared up to do, at least not yet, and we're not doing anyone any favors by overreaching and then failing to deliver.

Don't forget... If you're really interested in helping your fellow programmer *today*, you can find plenty of folks in need of a helpful shove in the right direction asking questions here. It ain't full-on mentoring, but it ain't nothing.

Answer (score -21):

Females are not particularly discriminated against within the industry per se, the industry is discriminated against by clueles, moronic parents and a majority of bottom-line-watchers who consider that a couple months out to bear a child is more of a disincentive that ignoring half the available workforce.

I have had the pleasure of working with several intelligent, competent, experienced and skilled software engineers who happened to be female.

Female engineers do not need to be mentored.  Parents need to be mentored so as not to consider the ICT industry as beneath contempt for their daughters and on a laddder-rung slightly below serial murderers.

Comment: _"Female engineers do not need to be mentored."_ No? Don't they? Certainly not, they'll know anything out of the box because they're female? There are differences how things are perceived by males and females, and any good mentor or teacher catches his clients there upright well (not that I'm the best mentor/teacher every time at all :-S ).

Comment: Why mentor the parents? Why not "mentor" the pencil-pushers who make these ridiculous policies?

Comment: I can't imagine a situation where this phrase would apply: *I have had the pleasure of working with several intelligent, competent, experienced and skilled software engineers who happened to be **male**.* . . . . It's akin to "I'm not racist, I happen to have a black friend, mind you". . . . And this is not about you, Martin, it's about the [memes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meme#Memetic_explanations_of_racism).