# An experiment: Stack Overflow TV

Tags: discussion, education

Stack Overflow is beginning an experiment called Stack Overflow TV, or SOTV for short.

It will be a series of fast, smart videos for experienced programmers who want to learn a new thing. The videos will serve as a complement to Stack’s Q&A, and are intended for that community. Of course, they will be licensed under Creative Commons.

The episodes will be shot at the Stack office in New York City, in front of a live audience, and will be given the production values of an episodic TV show. Think: three steps up from a conference video, and one step below a TED talk.

As with Stack Overflow, we are “optimizing for the artifact”. This means we will do rehearsals, coaching, and retakes as necessary to get the best product.

The talks will be code-heavy and philosophy-light. After watching the talk, the viewer should know whether this is a technology they want to pursue further.

We are looking for speakers who wish to be part of the experiment. In particular, we are looking for those who have a presentation that they are accustomed to delivering, and would like to make a proper production of it.

The topic needs to be a tag you’d find on Stack Overflow or Server Fault. Docker would be great. Ember, Swift, Postgres, Go, Chef… you get the idea.

What’s in it for you? Not least, you’ll work with Joel and the SO team to rehearse, refine and record a great presentation. We are not offering speaker fees, but will cover travel expenses within reason.

Please drop a note to tv@stackoverflow.com if you are interested, and we’ll chat.

Questions and comments are welcome.

**Update:** The tv@stackoverflow.com email address had a permissions problem and may have bounced. Please try again.

Comment: Huh, that seems pretty nifty. Shame I don't have anything particularly interesting to talk about. :(

Comment: And by *cover travel expenses* you mean *proportional to the distance travelled*, right? E.g. those outside of the U.S. could apply too?

Comment: Would it be possible for members of the community to weigh in on the writing of some of these presentations, without actually giving them?  I'm sure that there are a lot of people here that are knowledgeable enough on a topic to write about it without being able to actually go and do the presentation, or who might be able to add value in technical editing of a script.

Comment: what kind of timeline is this? next few weeks, months, over the next year? Some of us are pretty booked up, especially for volunteer work.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes, we’ll accept applications from anywhere. Our first choice is that we catch people while they happen to be in NY. Covering travel is to help people get here who we really want to do a talk, and who otherwise couldn’t make it.

Comment: @KateGregory Time scale is next several months to start. Developing and rehearsing and coordinating travel put it on that timeline, realistically. If it’s successful, we continue indefinitely.

Comment: This "question" has overcome my kneejerk reaction to downvote everything. Good job, sounds interesting.

Comment: Brilliant! /length

Comment: **Wow!!** Great to hear about the next level of SO.  Can we suggest Speakers(maybe in future)?

Comment: So Jon Skeet is going first, right?

Comment: http://youtube.com/stackhq/

Comment: Any thoughts of doing a live version if you get well known speakers?  You can always do re-shoots of parts after the fact to clean it up for the archival episode, but having a live stream with interactive questions could be quite interesting, perhaps as a later thing after it gets going successfully.

Comment: This is probably the first question in the history of StackExchange where the OP is looking for "questions" instead of "answers"!

Comment: How often do you plan on putting out one of these videos?

Comment: I think I'd watch these.  I love listening to the StackExchange podcasts :-)

Comment: By all means go for it, but I'm not personally a big fan of video tutorials. Videos are really hard to "skim" to get an idea of whether or not it's something I want to spend time watching. If you do them, please make sure there is a decent text synopsis sufficient to give a (potential) viewer a good idea of the content and level. Even better would be some index points so you can skip to the part you want.

Comment: I nominate Zirak to speak on behalf of JavaScript.

Comment: @Mrchief You must have missed the "Volunteer" post sometime... Last week, I think. ;)

Comment: There have been plenty such meta questions, @Mrchief. "Stack Overflow is getting a place of its own" comes immediately to mind, but there are many many others.

Comment: I'm guessing you're not covering inter continental travel?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum See the 5th comment.

Comment: Videos are the ultimate tool of the illiterate. I don't quite like the message you're sending here. It'd be much more useful for the potential speakers to *write* instead, and have some sort of a long-form SO or SE sub-site where such tutorials would be welcome. Just think of the controls available when reading text. There's no ^F nor a table of contents for a video presentation. You can't copy-paste from it. It's just seems to be about the most counterproductive medium for educating a programmer. Most of us read much faster than anyone can talk, you know.

Comment: TED talks are "one step above" the production values of "an episodic TV show"? Blimey, what are you watching, 1970s _Doctor Who_?!

Comment: TRWTF is endorsing the abbreviation "Stack" in this post >.< ;)

Comment: inb4 the Unicode Robot on TV

Comment: Who's going to give a presentation on [EBCDIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC "Extended Binary Coded Decimal Interchange Code")?

Comment: I could not agree more with @Kuba. Videos are the _last_ resort for me when looking for canonical help. It is only more appealing as a way of socializing at conferences and have random questions answered, but as a reference material it is awkward to learn from since it is inefficient for said reasons. Sorry for spoiling the fun, but would it not be better spent time to fix the outstanding issues with SO that many of us keep bringing up?

Comment: FYI: My email to tv@stackoverflow.com seems to have bounced. See: http://i.imgur.com/2LKH2BM.png

Comment: I do wonder whether it would be a better use of resources to fix SO's existing and ever-worsening problems.

Comment: I like videos. I found Microsoft's Build and TechEd videos very demonstrative in showing off new functionality that I had thought was too complex, but actually turned out to be quite easy with someone demonstrating it. I tend to load these videos up into my media server and watch them at my leisure.

Comment: No silver bullet, @Lightness. Any opportunity for improving the educational opportunities are worth *considering*, given the scope of the problem.

Comment: Different people learn in different ways, @Kuba. I don't find videos particularly useful myself, but I know others who see them as invaluable.

Comment: About time.​​​​

Comment: There are also those who see cplusplus.com and "Learn <language> in 20 Days" as _invaluable_. Just sayin'. :)

Comment: As opposed to written SO material, will you be able to tell the speaker later that he said something foolish, and how will he be able to correct the video then? You will pay him again to fly there and re-record it lol?

Comment: @Ipapp, new privilege at 500k, and you need good video editing skills.

Comment: @lpapp When you have a narrow, specific problem that you need help with, you're correct: videos are too verbose and difficult to quickly distill useful information from. What live discussion can do, however, is illuminate *new* areas for people. For someone just starting out in AI or data analysis, for instance, the field of neural networks may be a deep void for which they lack the tools to explore. These kinds of videos could equip viewers with a general overview and the terminology required to seek the answers they require. I think they'd be a valuable asset to the community.

Comment: @BraedenP: huh, so we need the too broad, off-site recommendation, lacks minimal understanding, etc close reason for videos then, too? Please do not bring that category back in video format!

Comment: @BraedenP It used to be that people wrote books on various subjects - in times when it was just as hard to edit a book as it was to edit a video. Nothing says a tutorial can't be written. I claim that everything that can be presented in a programming video, short of demo clips, can be presented much better in written form. Programming-related videos are crazily wasteful when it comes to content vs. bandwidth, even when looked at from the human perspective, not the link perspective. In 1 minute you could probably read the script for 5+ minutes of video.

Comment: @KubaOber: perhaps they will integrate [onelineocr.com](http://onelineocr.com) or something. Ah, lpapp, do not forget to smile, so here it goes: `:)`

Comment: @KubaOber Books are an excellent resource for in-depth exploration of a topic. What a short 5-minute video can do is explain *what* a particular field of study entails, *why* it is useful, and terminology required to *find* books and other resources that will facilitate further study. These abstract/broad kinds of content do not belong in SO questions and answers, though, so videos might be a nice conduit for that type of content.

Comment: @BraedenP And you can read that same information in one minute, when given it as text. I agree that the *content* may be offtopic on SO, and that's why I've said above that it should be a subsite or sister site. **SO-Overviews**, **SO-Tutorials**, or something. Never mind that such videos will be by definition inaccessible to those who can't see well. Captions don't do the job, you'd need to transcribe all the slides/snippets too. All the while you already have it accessible when presented as text.

Comment: Do the people traveling to NYC get to be chewed out by Joel on camera for comedic effect? I suspect this will be less about programming and more about Punk'd-ing people

Comment: @KubaOber What if the speakers and hosts add entertainment value through funny/interesting discussion? Watching videos is much less efficient than speed-reading through a bunch of text, but some people (dyslexics and other people who have trouble reading and understanding dense, technical texts) would undoubtedly be thrilled to learn through a more engaging format. It may not be useful for you (and probably not myself, either), but this is a *community* resource, and I think that many users stand to benefit from this kind of content in video format.

Comment: @BraedenP Here's an interesting observation from a conference of people who work on literature: most of the talks are *read*. As in: they write the talk, with proper English, punctuation, structure of argumentation - the whole deal. Then they read it. And you know what? One listens to it much better than to most talks full of umm, hmm, incorrect grammar, lost lines of reasoning, etc. The production value is in the content, prepared and written as text. The visual and audible aspect is entirely optional.

Comment: I can't help thinking this is in "Your idea is bad and you should feel bad" territory. I can't think of a *worse* format to absorb technical information.

Comment: @BraedenP If this is about entertainment then I think we have nothing further to discuss, because it's seriously offtopic.

Comment: Can we record the new versions of [JAvatar](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5xFxPk6dIp8) and [Javazone](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3vI_7os2V_o&feature=youtu.be) on Stack Overflow TV?

Comment: My email bounced as well.

Comment: @KubaOber Then I must be fundamentally misinterpreting the intention of this project. I understood "*complimentary* resource" as an intention to appeal to people who are not wholly satisfied by SO's current Q&A offerings. It seems fruitless to re-hash the current format into a video, so I was imagining alternative formats that could help people who are *not* looking for specific, technical examples. But maybe such a resource belongs elsewhere like Khan...

Comment: I share the opinion that videos were for entertainment, and text was for education. If you do want to make SOTV, I'd suggest focusing more on the entertainment value with a huge dose of education, rather than focusing solely on the educational purposes. I watch Twitch.tv streams a lot (people playing video games), and would probably enjoy some good personalities browsing and answering SO questions, while keeping up an entertaining running commentary that also educates me on the detailed hows and whys of the problems they solve. Hrm maybe I should post this as an answer...

Comment: @lpapp http://www.gocomics.com/foxtrot/2010/02/21 :)

Comment: @MattBurland Is correct.  Having a good text accompanying the video is key.  Railcasts' ascii casts do a great job at that: http://railscasts.com/episodes/417-foundation?view=asciicast

Comment: @Rachel Wait a minute, now it's about videos of people *while they answer SO questions*? Are we all even on the same page?

Comment: If this happens, *please* include a transcript for those of us who would prefer plain text over a video.

Comment: @Doorknob: It needs to be more than a literal transcript. It needs text that compliments the video. The link that basher included looks like a good start for the kind of accompanying text that is needed. It should include good descriptive text of what's covered in the video along with code snippets as appropriate that can be cut and pasted if you want to follow along. Nobody wants to have to try and pause the video and retype the code!

Comment: @KubaOber :) Was just an alternate suggestion. To me, video is entertainment, not reference material/education. And personally I'm of the camp that hates video tutorials. So when I hear "SO TV", I imagine watching an entertaining/intelligent programmer browsing SO and answering questions, while keeping up an educational/entertaining commentary on what they're doing and why.

Comment: I still do not get the `I know others who see them as invaluable` part. Video is good, but writing is not? How will they write code themselves or learn from official documentations, etc?!

Comment: @Rachel: that is what I was writing in the very beginning, too, that is socializing and entertainment then, and not focused Q/A. That is good for conferences to keep the spirit up, but it is not Q/A focused. Perhaps, that is fine, too, as long as it does not pop up for me to check and I can easily avoid it without extra effort, but then it is not a real Q/A oriented subsite. Having said that, I would still prefer spending time on more pressing issues, like [this stat](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/219032/number-of-votes-per-month#graph).

Comment: @MattBurland I agree. Complimentary textual resources would be great for people who like to follow along and get some hands-on experience. For example, a MongoDB introduction could include links to downloads and installation processes for various environments, as well as sample data sets, queries, and commands designed to demonstrate MongoDB's strengths and weaknesses as a platform. Alongside a human discussion and live demos, this could prove to be a much richer introduction than scrolling through a 10,000-word web tutorial. These would be quite resource-intensive for the SO team, however.

Comment: @Rachel I agree with your idea of having something entertaining and giving a glimpse of how the process of "stackoverflowing" works from various angles - those of askers, answerers, reviewers and mods. That'd be entertaining and engaging. Having a yet another source for technical tutorials done as videos - not much. Some vfx/gfx live coding tutorials are useful, everything else is meh. IMHO.

Comment: I think there needs to be one on Vanilla JS DOM manipulation.

Comment: No compensation at all for the speaker besides travel expenses seems a bit cheap for something you intend to have the production values of a TV show.

Comment: What a terrible waste of resources. Where did this idea come from that you can't stick to doing one thing *really well*, that you have to branch out into doing 100 things poorly?

Comment: I'm a fan of the idea in theory. I think asking interested speakers to contact an email address that bounces is *not a good start.*

Comment: While I don't disagree with the text versions (they are good too!) I find it strange that other developers don't like video tutorials. I love video tutorials for quickly seeing the results of a framework/technology/language. Once I watch a couple of quick videos I have a good idea whether or not I want to pursue that particular thing - and if I do I'll move on to text tutorials.

Comment: Fantastic idea ! I'm in. E-mail on the way.

Comment: I'll second @Doorknob that a text version is more useful than a video. But such a large amount of text is too much for a quick read, yet too small for a book. How about breaking it down into chunks of manageable size, perhaps organized as questions and answers?

Comment: @CodyGray But does Google do 100 things poorly? I think some companies have what it takes.

Comment: I have a Youtube channel, but avoid actually watching any videos (including my own channel) because my 'mobile internet' (can't get cable) costs me an arm and a leg..  Have to say I'm not enthused about the entire concept of 'teaching by video' either..

Comment: Now you know what's going to happen next right? Questions on stackoverflow - about some video they saw on SOTV :/

Comment: Most comments seem to be like "It's better to have something written, to use/try/copy-paste". Of course, it is. But as someone traveling ~3 hours per day (bus, train, ...), I spend quite a few time watching such videos, to discover new concepts, etc. And, I can't imagine myself reading things for hours in transports ... I think it has some potential

Comment: @TheMuffinMan if there's any company that does a whole lot of things poorly, it's Google. They cancel products all the time after those products have acquired a large userbase when they're no longer interested in the product or when the size of the userbase is too small in their eyes.

Comment: Seems like this would be an issue for anyone who did not speak the language spoken in the video.  No copy / paste Google translate.  Will it be offered in different languages?

Comment: I never understood where the video epidemic on the web is coming from. Why can't a tutorial be 2 pages of text with images and code instead of 5 min of talking?

Comment: The Stack Overflow homepage is Google. This will no longer be the case for videos. They are not discoverable, not searchable and not efficiently consumable.

Comment: @usr What are you talking about?  https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=how+to+search+the+internet&tbm=vid

Comment: I haven't personally been a part of the discussions that have lead to this idea, but if it's what I think it is I'm in huge favor. I routinely attend conferences because I love being able to hear about new technologies/methods from people who are passionate about them, and it's a lot easier to convey that via voice than through a Q&A format in text. I wouldn't expect SOTV to be a replacement for Q&A, just a nice way to get more in-depth knowledge. I don't quite understand the fervor here, to be honest. Why is everyone so angry?

Comment: An "experiment" is an experiment, a test, a try, an attempt, a trial. I find the writing in programming to be mediocre at best. Sometimes the YouTube videos are very helpful in understanding the thought process as the programmer writes the lines of code, and then talks about the rationale for a particular command or element.

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi Because it's meta... the mob here is always angry and out for blood :)

Comment: Just like every program grows until it can read email, every web site expands until it shows video.

Comment: Seriously people? Stop voting to close this for asinine reasons. It's perfectly on-topic and just because you don't like the idea isn't a reason to close it.

Comment: I like video tutorials or demos. If I can learn to cook through videos then I'm sure I could learn to code? Plus, webcasts have been happening for awhile now. Are these videos meant to be different?

Comment: Maybe if it had some overlay or side bar window that allowed the code or other text to be copied/viewed/searched. I'd like to see that all code shown is actually text piping that can be replayed in an IDE with some plugin.  I guess I get the desire to get into video when you see the success of sites such as PluralSight.

Comment: I assume SO isn't just doing this for its health? I don't see any reason why presenters shouldn't be paid for their efforts, and incidentally you would find that a lot simpler from the Intellectual Property point of view, as it becomes a work for hire.

Comment: @Cypher try searching for some phrase being spoken in the video. You won't find it. A Google search incorporates the document text in addition to the title. Text is important for relevancy.

Comment: You have a blog and ad-space, which is the ideal way to promote your own things. BTW, videos should be a "philosophy-heavy and code-light" medium, not a "code-heavy and philosophy-light" medium, because it's PITA to manually copy code from the screen to text editor.

Comment: @animuson I'm tempted to closevote for one simple reason: OP says "questions and comments are welcome" but does not actually interact with any of the responses. There has been no sign of OP despite the two comments he posted shortly after the question, and the "oops, mail address should work now" edit. An SE employee should know you don't ask a question and then leave for 2 days; and without any interaction from somebody who actually has anything to do with this project, it's not appearing to seek a discussion with the community but feels more like an announcement with upvoteable comments.

Comment: Also, please do _not_ use the name "Stack Overflow TV": First, this could be applied to the rest of the SE network - just as SE started with programming and then expanded, the video concept could be expanded to other topics; don't make this harder by branding it with the SO name. Second, a close coupling with SO would also make it even harder for noobs to understand what SO the website is about, and why we're closing their broad/off topic questions. Third, whatever you do, find a web2.0 word to use instead of "TV" as "TV" has a bad taste of big media corporations and crappy content.

Comment: @l4mpi: Well, SE started as SO, then generalized to StackExchange. Maybe SOTV will generalize into SETV. But your point about bad close coupling with SO is really valid.

Comment: Even though I agree with some opinions that is not nesseccary for SO, I'm open enough to give it a try.

Comment: Nerds on TV? You gotta be kidding me

Comment: @Krumia that's exactly my point, why not _start_ this as something related to SE instead of restricting it to SO? Then it could more naturally branch out to other topics.

Comment: @KubaOber, we're trying to get a Tutorials site up and running over at Area 51, but apparently not enough people are interested.

Comment: This is a bad idea in the long run.

Comment: @animuson: This is brand promotion. I don't see why it's on topic. Just because it's got "StackOverflow" in it does not make it on topic. Can I create a "Stack Overflow Hardware Store" or something and post it on Meta.SE? To reiterate myself, Stack got their own blog and ad space to do this.

Comment: To all people who are discussing whether this post belongs here, please come join us in this discussion on MSE: [Should Stack Exchange Inc promote its pet projects on meta sites?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238990/167646). That way the discussion here can be about the actual content of the post.

Comment: I can't work out whether this suggestion was six months too late for the last April 1st or is six months too early for the next...

Comment: If you guys are actually going to do something like this, I'd prefer small tutorials. SO has some of the best explanations I've ever seen. More people should know about them.

Comment: @KubaOber "Videos are the ultimate tool of the illiterate. I don't quite like the message you're sending here." What's with the offensive attitude? I don't quite like the message *you* are sending here. Who are you to make such broad sweeping allegations like this? Video is just another information exchange format. Those that find the format useful are by no means illiterate. If you don't like the idea, don't participate in it or use it. Otherwise, please stop making unfounded assumptions about the rest of the world.

Comment: Not saying it's a bad thing, but is this an attempt to monetize Stack Overflow? I imagine Microsoft would be willing to pay for a Windows Mobile promotion video.

Comment: Not quite sure why I have to travel to New York in order to make a video.  It's a very long distance from my home, and it's situated in a country that I don't like very much.  There must be video-making equipment closer to my home than this.

Comment: This could be potentially brilliant... Videos are extremely useful for learning a new technology as you have the human aspect of being able to learn from another person which I think is much more fun than reading articles on the internet... However it's not possible to copy and paste from a video... So maybe a video with some written documentation would suffice?

Comment: Video tutorials are useless. Take any this polished content generation idea and turn it into interactive tutorial pages instead (think Bret Victor style). Never videos.

Comment: Youtube for programmers, YEYI!!!!! \o/ :-p

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't about giving people programming lessons; it's a Q&A network for SPECIFIC errors, problems, questions, etc. Plus, many people here would like to have some sort of experience in the community, and not it being flooded with newbie coders, especially when there are better websites to fit that bill. (I.E. Codecademy, Gribbon, etc.)

Comment: " We are not offering speaker fees, " : - Flawed business model. You get what you pay for. And presumably SO will be making money from this venture?

Comment: I think everyone's objections here can be fixed by re-titling this StackExchange TV. Then you can have a `#developers` channel. That way, the "StackOverflow isn't a place for this" arguments are invalid - since its branded as StackExchange.

Comment: *What's in it for you?* You don't get any speaker fees, but **you get to work with Joel and SO team.**, sounds too pompous bordering on arrogant. By the way, who is Joel? A Nobel Prize winner? Why is it a "privilege" to work with him?

Comment: we want shop.stackoverflow.com back first :(
@Happy: who is Joel??? Blasphemy ain't allowed here!!!

Comment: @Happy It’s important that the incentives are the same as SO itself, which is a desire to contribute. It’s Creative Commons, and if we do it right it’ll work well alongside Q&A. We’ll make money to the extent that SE makes money, which is that we sell advertising. We don’t have any particular ad plans for the videos, we need to walk before we run.

Comment: I wouldn't mind having Stack Overflow video series for specialized technologies.  Like if I wanted to learn Maven or Spring or Ivy or Hibernate... I mean, I'm sure there are already video tutorials out there, but Stack Exchange has a reputation I trust, rather than some random dude on YouTube who might or might not really know what he's talking about.

Comment: I understand people not liking video tutorials for actual help, bit i would love to be able to kick back and hear about a new technology while Im eating breakfast. If you can get the production value and a decent length, ill tune in for sure. Would the be offered through existing channels (like youtube)? I prefer to throw them on the TV!

Comment: http://popcornjs.org/ could facilitate adding code demos and textual data to accompany the video

Comment: @MattSherman Right, so mention *that* as the incentive, not some irrelevant garbage about some Joel. I asked a couple of people around, and hate to break it to you, this Joel is nowhere close to being so famous that he is recognized only by his first name, unlike *Edgar*, for example. Somewhat amusingly, you seem to have entirely ignored the point I highlighted in **bold** in my previous comment.

Comment: Hi, when you publish the video, please add subtitles. thanks

Comment: [Off topic] @Happy: It's perfectly all right that you and your friends to not know who Joel is. I also agree that it should not be a *priviledge* to work with him. But http://www.joelonsoftware.com/. BTW who the heck is *Edgar*?

Comment: Edgar Allen Poe methinks. "it was the best of times it was ..." wait wait wrong one

Comment: I guess some eye-candy, sounds, and moving stuff never hurt. But gotta echo Kuba... it isn't likely to become too useful to us programmers.  we're readers

Comment: @Happy - Joel to me is like Jon skeet and John Carmack and other smart folk. It'd be nice to have coffee with them, but otherwise yeah i agree - just regular folks. Am I impressed? sure, good works.

Comment: I can't wait for it.

Comment: Any status on this?

Comment: I would typically agree with most of the comments here. Agreeing mostly with Kuba. That said, I do see some value in this. I find short to medium length presentations of that sort quite nice when I am cooking in the evening. I have watched many a 100 days of Android whilst cooking a curry.

Comment: According to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/320538/4284627, this project was dropped so I'm voting to close this.

Answer (score 559):

Why are you attaching to Stack Overflow a project that has nothing to do with what the site is about?

This is not a teaching website without minimal understanding. In fact, we emphatically do not do that. We don't do general topics. We don't do introductions. We answer questions from professionals and enthusiasts.

And what's with having it be in some official headquarters, run only by the owners? This is not a site run by a single person or organization, but a community driven website with community driven content. And it's going to be set in stone after the videos are produced, meaning no one can come in and make it better?

The only thing it seems to have in common with Stack Overflow is that it is about programming and being started by at least one person who works there. If Stack Overflow is to have a video project attached to it, it should be a Q&A session with various volunteer experts from around the world. Or video chats where people get together and work through coding problems.

You want to start a Stack Exchange TV network, fine. But don't attach it to Stack Overflow. Let it sink or swim on its own.

Comment: +1 exactly my thoughts. Stack Overflow should not be turned into a brand name that gets attached to unrelated projects, just to make them appear more interesting or successful than they are, or deserve to be on their own merits.

Comment: Stack Overflow *is* about teaching. It's just a specific *kind* of teaching. The Stack Exchange network is even more so; lots of teaching in different ways.

Comment: so if the site is for teaching why do questions about programming get closed? " if somebody wants to learn something" and about the tv network...I wonder when the commercials will start to run every 5 min ? :)

Comment: The comments I'm seeing about video being a bad learning medium for programming do seem spot on.  But this nonsense about "some office headquarters" - umm, Stack Exchange is a for-profit company.  I'm not sure why them trying to launch new ventures which they control is so mind boggling for some people.

Comment: @AdamRackis not to mention they mentioned they are looking for presenters? it is obviously not all in house.

Comment: Hmmm I don't get the idea of SO not being about teaching.  I (and others I assume) certainly learn a lot on SO.  If it is not about teaching what is it about.  Maybe we just have different definitions of teaching.

Comment: @stakx: That pretty much describes Stack Overflow careers, and yet that seems to be working out pretty well for everyone involved.

Comment: I hate to say it but you clearly have not noticed (or are choosing to ignore) the direction that StackOverflow owners want the site to move in. They've even said they "want StackOverflow to be a site where people learn how to code", as well as be a repository for *every code-related problem ever*. It hasn't been a place for "answering questions from professionals and enthusiasts" for **years**.

Comment: @Creator if you learned something from a question, then it has taught you something.

Comment: if you need some Spanish speaking host, just let me know!

Comment: @Mxyl but then you need a awnser and not a close vote.how can you lurn from a close vote.there are also questions about programming that have nothing to do with code.so its not all about teaching.

Comment: @Creator: Answerable, non-duplicate questions about common problems  don't get closed often.  It's more the duplicates, the rants, the blatant 10-second googlables and RTFMables, and the "I've never programmed before.  How do i build <insert man-years-size project here>?" questions that get closed.

Comment: @TylerH I don't think people are ignoring anything; they are resisting and asking for a different way of seeing matters.  I'd suggest a non-profit like Khan Academy might be a better brand for playing on this kind of project... where videos and tutorials are already the cornerstone... just call Salman!  What people don't want to see is reckless management of the existing institutional knowledge here; there's plenty of attention, so why not focus on tending the complaints vs. risking one's strong position by disrupting and [irritating the core](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/270683/211160)?

Comment: Well here's the chance for innovation. Why not try it, and see where it goes. I for one am excited about this experiment. Stack Overflow helps me save time, and this seems like another feature to help me do just that.

Comment: I agree with this answer, too. I would probably make the first question bold and stand on its own line or so. I wonder how many times more the "question" will be reopened. The community seems to have decided to close it as off-topic here on (M)SO a couple of times now, yet moderators keep reopening it with their binding votes. :/

Comment: I strongly agree with this Answer and would upvote it 10 times if allowed.  Try your experiment sure, there are folks who learn well via video and I'm sure it will have an appreciative audience, but please do **not** tie it in with Stack Overflow!

Comment: @MatthewNichols One can learn without being taught. Yes, we learn from SO, but it does not mean SO is a teaching site. Learning and teaching are not the same.

Comment: Why are you against SO expanding? So what if the TV thing does not perfectly map on what the site is about? People / companies should be able to expand to other kinds of things. What, should Microsoft have only settled on creating the Windows OS? No, they expanded and created Office, .NET, VS, etc. Give it a chance.

Comment: For one of my books the publisher had me do several one and a half to two minute videos that were of the type that showed the novice how do a single thing with visible, reproducible results. I insisted that we include downloadable code for each example so the user could follow along and the publisher didn't think it was needed. *That decision reduced the value of the videos dramatically.* I had to e-mail code to several folks. If SOTV is going to be those kinds of vids then I think the project would fail horribly no matter how well it is produced. @silencedmessage idea below would be better!

Comment: @EduardLuca: If Microsoft had stuck to a couple of specific technologies, perhaps they wouldn't be flailing so badly in the market with every new product they ship.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I agree that *some* MS products are really crappy (like IE), but they have some amazing products like Visual Studio. That's why I'm encouraging SOTV, because if you don't try, you can't succeed.

Comment: If you think Visual Studio is "an amazing product", I assume you never used the C++ part of it. Or something truly amazing, like certain well-known Visual Studio plugins.

Comment: @EduardLuca: Visual Studio "amazing"???? Ha!

Comment: "if you don't try, you can't succeed" is a really terrible reason to do anything, if that's your _only_ reason.

Comment: @HostileFork Oh, I don't disagree with you. I was simply responding to that comment which seemed to misunderstand the clear direction SE owners are taking SO.

Comment: learning/teaching is a positive side affect of SO. but not its goal.

Comment: @Creator Saying that close votes mean we're not for teaching is the same as saying close votes mean we're not for answers. We *are* for both, but only when the question is right. (eg. You don't learn math in English classrooms but you still manage to learn English.)

Comment: @Veedrac i just sayed its not all about teaching.at sombody's comment.

Comment: Do you know what Stack Exhange's mission statement is? "Make the internet a better place to get expert answers to your questions." This is an **experiment** trying a different approach. What if your question is "Do I find Go to be interesting and relevant enough toy career to spend the time to learn it thoroughly?"? A fifteen minute intensive overview from a Go expert could save you hours of reading and coding. You're free to prefer text to videos, but please recognize that this *does* have to do with SO, that others have opinions different from yours, and that this is *an experiment*.

Comment: I was watching a talk from Atwood and heard "... viewing a video tutorial which I thinks is really dumb" http://youtu.be/m4ZPBPUA30M?t=12m52s Not that I am against the idea of video tutorials, but I think it's funny how one of the co-founders probably would strongly disagree

Comment: @Ineentho This certainly wouldn't be the first time that Stack Overflow has done something that Jeff Atwood would profoundly disagree with since his departure.

Comment: StackOverflow would not suffer from being more accessible to Junior Developers and students. I am now an experienced programmer and still have very basic questions that are not easily answered by the documentation; however, I am often dissuaded from asking such questions due to the hostility on this site to "basic" questions. The whole point of StackOverflow is to enable people to have their questions answered. Sometimes, the most basic question yields the most interesting answers.

Comment: @Laura If you guys have already made up your mind on what you want to do, then why even bother asking users? Asking people for their feedback on your idea, and then criticizing them when they disagree with you is extremely *intolerant* and *immature*.

Comment: @Laura to everyone in this answer thread: notice there's nothing in that mission statement about **expert** *questions*; only *answers*. That should be very telling.

Comment: @Happy Several reasons to post this. 1. because the SO staff is very limited, and there are literally **millions** of SO users/readers from which to gather ideas/insight/potential concerns. 2. It is an opportunity to let users know in an open way that allows for feedback and interaction. 3. It allows users an avenue for offering their services for this request.

Comment: @TylerH Right, but the comment above from Laura says otherwise. If you seek feedback, you should be receptive to it, not get over-defensive each time sometime disagrees with your idea.

Comment: @Happy it seems like Laura is saying the same thing as you ("be receptive to people with different ideas").

Comment: @happy I'm sorry if it felt like I (or other employees) are criticizing people who dislike the idea. My intent was to explain our thinking a little bit more. We ask for feedback because even though we've decided *that* we're going to try something, community feedback helps us shape *how* and *how long* to try the thing we decided on. All I'm asking is to keep in mind that we're experimenting; this doesn't mean the death of Stack Overflow as you know it.

Comment: Good feedback, but I don't think you've understood our intent. (1) This *will* be for expert developers, like all of SO. These are not "Programming 101" videos. They are more like talks at dev conferences. (2) The emphasis is on stuff that doesn't fit into a normal Q&A. Why would we record people answering questions? The site we have does that way better. (3) Recording at SE is just a practical consideration. We wanted high quality video, so the best way to guarantee that was to record it ourselves. It's still possible that video isn't even the correct media for this. We'll find out by trying.

Comment: Just keep it simple as it is

Answer (score 228):

Okay, I have to ask you one simple question:

## Why are you doing this, anyway?

Even though you haven't exactly elaborated on the whole point of this project, I'm assuming your goal is in these quotes:

> It will be a series of fast, smart videos for experienced programmers who want to learn a new thing.

> After watching the talk, the viewer should know whether this is a technology they want to pursue further.

It's time for: *Meta.SO analogies, episode 1!*

---

### How teaching used to work

[image: old classroom]

<sup>(CC) BY Ryan Tyler Smith <[https://www.flickr.com/...](https://www.flickr.com/photos/ryantylersmith/14010104872/in/photolist-nm2s5h-no4SR6-nmj1hK-fheFND-5hYr4R-8SWTw2-HHs45-eVkUK-2geNU1-54jyTq-8oMKDS-4RSiX7-enj5vx-4tzd6X-g6AcU-gXQhKo-mX7cDT-x69t-8oMKGY-4S3Jfi-o4aviV-okD69Z-okrAmj-okmGtg-okryaq-okBm5w-o49zxQ-okD9hT-o4axzD-okBgZC-okrxn3-okDcaX-okmDxg-623Lm2-85sZie-85t2vi-oiBpuU-okBeUf-okDaMr-okDbFk-o49pjL-o49Bkh-o4awBB-oiBnWJ-o49BC2-okD9Pe-onp8Q4-85t1bH-85w8Hb-85sYza)></sup>

**Disavantages**:

- Things had to be copied by hand
- Research was slow and arduous
- No way to quickly and efficiently find things that you need to find
- Want to recreate a demonstration? Sorry, do it from your notes that you hopefully took

**Advantages**:

- You can doodle on chalkboards when the teacher isn't there

### How teaching works now

[image]

<sup>(CC) BY-NC securedgenet <[https://www.flickr.com/...](https://www.flickr.com/photos/55685248@N06/5856357447/in/photolist-9Vvn38-9Vyd8y-9Vydkj-9Vycf9-9Vvn9c-9VvmYe-9VvmTc-9VycoN-9VycXS-8anL2k-8anKwH-8anKz6-8aqZjS-8anKPg-eRB1Gk-8aqZBf-26zVJr-57iq2Y-57iprN-57iphf-57edCv-57eeqn-57eeci-fDeG8S-2X64cT-aKzvE4-6m6ker-6m6kgp-6m6kj4-6m6kbR-bQwjT8-X23T7-6YXtxy-6tSFn3-64h3us-4s6q3J-rKp7X-6m6k8k-5KS8Fa-gRHf1-7AuyhU-5Deno-C7QuJ-7keq6e-7xPXX6-4ahA7u-BMSGd-8pj8b5-dUjaJD-2iQ7TN)></sup>

**Advantages**:

- Searching for information is easy with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- Typing is a lot faster than writing
- Cutting and pasting doesn't actually entail using scissors and a glue stick
- Specifically *made for **programmers**, for Skeet's sake!*

**Disadvantages**:

- You can't annoy people by making screeching noises with your fingernails on a chalkboard

---

So how is that even helpful, aside from the colorful pictures you can look at?

If you want to help programmers "**learn a new thing**" and "**know whether this is a technology they want to pursue further**," maybe you should avoid doing it in a way that makes exploring, experimenting, and discovering new things that much harder!

A video is like an old classroom with a chalkboard and quill pens. You can't quickly find what specifically you're interested in (sorry, watch the whole thing), you can't try code samples (too bad for you, copy them by hand), and you're forced to go at a pace that you may or (more likely) may not enjoy. I mean, you even have to *travel* just to make these things? Who does that any more?

So please, *please*, *please*, ***please*** don't bring technology back to the Stone Age. I'm actually tempted to close this as off-topic: Questions on Stack Overflow should only be about programming. I'm reminded of Dilbert's manager, who lacks even a basic understanding of what programming is. If you want to appeal to programmers, please do so in a medium that's usable for us.

Comment: It sounds like these productions aren't meant to be tutorials or documentation - "the viewer should know whether this is a technology they want to pursue further." Meaning this isn't teaching specifically, but rather an introduction of some sorts. They should probably include a transcript so that those who want can search through the code etc, and maybe links to specific sections of the video, but I don't think video form is a bad idea for those who learn visually and through auditory means, or those who just want an introduction to a technology

Comment: +1 for railing against the production of videos, and using a picture of "teaching future state" that contains a room full of large screen flat panels.

Comment: +1 please don't bring technology back to the Stone Age.

Comment: Your answer reminded me [Edsger W. Dijkstra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edsger_W._Dijkstra).  *Dijkstra eschewed the use of computers in his own work for many decades. Almost all EWDs appearing after 1972 were hand-written; Even after he acquired an Apple Macintosh computer, he used it only for email and for browsing the World Wide Web*

Comment: _Typing is a lot faster than writing_ - I don't know about that one, I find getting my ideas down is quicker on paper, but writing prose is faster on the keyboard.

Comment: `You can't annoy people by making screeching noises with your fingernails on a chalkboard` -> yiiikes, I have just heard that noise in me!!!

Comment: >Typing is a lot faster than writing < depending what you write it might not be faster without experience, (Math f.e a lot of unusual characters , draw some graphs). Not everyone is typing with 10 fingers.
For the rest: agreed.

Comment: I don't know? Could you maybe put your answer in the form of a video? I find those much easier to digest! ;)

Comment: @Praveen Dijkstra taught algorithms and data structures mainly, AFAIK. Coding and technologies are different things. Especially as the videos are going to be code-heavy, I must join those who doubt whether video is a good platform.

Comment: People learn in different ways.  Some learn better by reading, others by hearing, by seeing, or by doing.  A text transcript would cover the first, an audio recording the second, a video component the third, and the end-user's own attempted application the fourth.  This idea doesn't take us back to the "technology stone age."  It presents information so everyone can benefit from it in whatever way works best for them.

Comment: I don't like how this answer uses "You" when the author means "I". Because I learn tons from videos. Channel 9, MS Build events,  YouTube, (television?) I heard Khan Academy is quite successful. I find it odd how people can say they don't learn from someone actually showing them. But I work with a really bright physics post-grad who hates videos, so I think this is a personal thing. Don't like videos? This product won't be for you.

Comment: Please don't assume you speak for all of us.  Some of us enjoy educational videos.

Comment: Doorknob, I like how you've presented this answer. Kudos to that. At the same time, some people _do_ learn better through watching a video, as Luke said in his comment. It's a bad idea to assume everyone learns the same way. I learn best by watching someone do something, then do it myself, personally. Videos are good for that. Keep an open mind on learning styles, friend. :)

Comment: @Kendra: sure, blind people may learn better through videos, although having said that, there are already techniques for reading text anyway and blind people would be fine with only audio, too, anyhow... So, please give us real and objective reasons why "they learn better through video", and such that outweigh the disadvantages. How often do you _watch videos_ at your company in your main job to learn technical things rather than reading documentation?

Comment: @lpapp Often. We even have an optional subscription for people who do learn better that way, which I do. I'm not saying I can't learn through text, but it always clicks easier for me to actually see someone doing something. It is not just a case of "blind people" and it's wrong to assume such. Everyone learns differently. Do you honestly believe it's impossible for someone to learn better through video, out of curiosity?

Comment: @Kendra: why do you think I am not honest? Anyway, if you really need confirmation, I can assure you that I am. We may have a different definition of better. My definition is efficient. Your definition may be entertaining and that is perhaps we differ? Either way, I am yet to hear objective reasons for videos that people brought up written text.

Comment: @lpapp My definition of better in this case is the same. I can spend two or three hours reading a tutorial without it clicking. Give me a five minute video made with the tutorial, and I'll have it even if I never looked at the tutorial. It's efficient in that it saves me time and hassle. Written text can sometimes be confusing to me, not for any specific reason, but often when I try to learn through reading, I'll miss words or phrases, and that will throw me off. Or the text is written in a way that is poorly phrased, or the text is poorly formatted. It is a real thing.

Comment: ... and you cannot miss words in a talk or the speaker cannot put poorly formatted sentences into speech?

Comment: @lpapp (cont.) Some people just have to see it happen to understand. Others can just read and get it. Heck, I know people who can see a picture of something, just a plain old picture, and immediately know how to fix things. People are unique, and as such, there are different learning styles. Just because it doesn't work for you doesn't mean it doesn't work for someone else. As I said in my first comment, keep an open mind on learning styles. If you don't find videos efficient for you, don't watch them. But why punish those of us who do?

Comment: @lpapp Again, I know people who have trouble with it. Some people type better than they speak (such as myself) and some speak better than they can type. It's all a matter of the individual. And I'm not talking about I'll miss words in their speech- I'm saying I understand better through watching. Seeing someone do something.

Comment: I am afraid I still do not get it. Bad grammar with typo, etc will get downvoted or fixed in no time. It is likely the latter due to the helpful contributors. Therefore, I do not see any problem here, yet I do not see how you would fix issues in a _video_ like that. I am sure some people will not like Q/A style either, or common knowledgebase, just project reference documentations. While those claims may be valid (or not), Stack Overflow is still not for this.

Comment: @lpapp Before this devolves into an argument, I suggest we agree to disagree. You learn differently from me. While I understand this, I'm having trouble with communicating it effectively with you. So for now, we should leave it at that. I can only hope you come to understand what I meant in time, but no matter how often I repeat it, if it's not making sense or you don't see it, I can't force you to. (Might I add I was being general? My disagreements were not aimed at SO directly, but at the overall view of learning styles.)

Comment: Some people prefer to hit each other with a bludgeon in the head to learn stuff. Sure, but SO is not for these people in my humble opinion. SO is for the objective majority. There was so much speak about SNR, well, do not spread the minority (noise IMHO) on SO. You can go with that to somewhere where it becomes signal. Others suggested youtube, tutorial site, etc.

Comment: @Kendra I'm curious how you find it easier to learn by watching someone program than reading the actual program. I would understand video being more helpful if you were watching someone, say, repair a car and you need to see the moving parts. But in programming everything is textual anyways. I've always found there's nothing more annoying than a video explaining code because then you always have to write out the code yourself if you want to mess around with it anyways.

Comment: @eddie_cat I've explained the best I can in my previous comments. I can understand it being hard to conceive it being easier, but it is for me. I can't think of a way to better explain it than I already have, unfortunately. If you don't learn that way, it can be harder to understand, especially with a text-based subject.

Comment: @eddie_cat And honestly, the writing the code out after it's been explained to me in a video more reinforces the video's lessons to me. So that's not a downfall in my eyes.

Comment: Just the obligatory link to point out that [learning styles don't exist](http://www.danielwillingham.com/learning-styles-faq.html)

Comment: _Posts feature request for the ability to use all my upvotes on this answer_

Comment: I don't know, I very much disagree with your "advantages" and "disadvantages" lists. I took the majority of my college classes the "old fashioned" way, in a lecture hall. I found it to be extremely effective. I've also tried to take a few with online video-based "lectures". These absolutely sucked—I cannot learn anything this way. I have tried everything to make it work, after my university went to teaching all undergraduate math and physics classes this way—two of my worst subjects. But it just doesn't. I really can't understand how one can learn from a video. You just need a personal touch.

Comment: Honestly what are you talking about? Youtube is filled with **videos** that teach programming/tricks/frameworks/whatever and do so very successfully. The medium is fine, especially if next to it you supply materials (slides, code, links, etc.)

Comment: It makes me sad how _How teaching used to work_ is the way I get taught now and I can only dream about _How teaching works now_.

Comment: @lpapp: Why do you assume you are in the majority with this opinion?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: have you read this thread without bias? The most upvoted answers say that this idea is a very bad idea, as well as the most upvoted comments.

Comment: @lpapp: Perhaps not. Is there a particularly relevant entry in the thread that would suggest the conclusion that you are in the majority? (edit) Well the OP, which suggests the idea, has the most upvotes.

Comment: and probably the most frequently closed question on meta, too, which is "compensated" by moderator binding reopen votes. Upvotes for the questions mean that it is good to discuss the topic, but about the decision the answers and respective comments speak. Just because I bring up a question whether meta is broken, it may not be broken just because the question gets lots of upvotes since it is worth discussing the topic. This question has by far the most downvotes I have ever seen on meta. Furthermore, it was initially about 1-2% the down/up vote ratio, it is now about 20%.

Comment: @lpapp: All we have are 2 little numbers. Those numbers tell us very little other than how many users decided to click the up arrow, and how many decided to click the down arrow. You speculate on the reasons people clicked the arrows, but I find no reason to believe your speculation.

Comment: There is nothing to speculate about, even if you were correct (which I do not believe, sorry), you can sum up the comments and answers against it, it is very easy to find the trivia. Why do you think most of the people speak against it? Why do you think it is the ever most downvotes and closure obtained question? Do you really think the majority wants this to happen? If the answer is yes, I simply think you are biased, which you are entitled to, but I do not agree with.

Comment: @lpapp: Most of the people *aren't* speaking against it. Most of the people who are *speaking* are speaking against it. But that is a completely different thing from most people speaking against it. Because people who would speak for it are already spoken for, in the OP. Why should they feel the need to say more? If the OP already says something they agree with, they can simply speak their agreement with an upvote.

Comment: @lpapp: *"Do you really think the majority wants this to happen?"* -- I have no idea. There is not nearly enough data to conclude one way or the other on that. There is almost no data at all.

Comment: It would be [**harakiri**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seppuku) from Stack Exchange to go against the heavy objection of the community rather than doing their own SE business separately. Anyway, those people matter who speak up with valid reasons. So far, there has been no _objective_ reason brought up for videos other than "I like it because I like it" as far as I am concerned. I was hoping for some rebuttal, but nothing arose.

Comment: -1 you are missing the point. Some people learn better by video. It's not stone-age learning, it's individualize learning.

Comment: Interesting that you don't agree with moving images for learning, but find still images appropriate for getting your point across

Comment: @lpapp Wait, so "I learn better from videos than reading text" isn't a valid argument in a discussion about different mediums for learning things? In that case: When I was young I learned best when someone told me things in German (may be because it's my native tongue), so *clearly* we should close english SO and all use a German site. I mean if it works best for me it obviously must be universally true?

Answer (score 143):

**Alternate/Additional Suggestion for SOTV**

First off, this answer is not really about your original idea. Your original idea prompted some thoughts that went in a different direction, and I wanted to post it as a suggestion for consideration in the future.

I watch [twitch.tv](http://www.twitch.tv/) streams a lot (people playing video games), and was thinking that Stack Exchange could have a lot of success with something similar.

I envision watching a programmer browsing SO and answering questions within a specific tag, while keeping up an educational and entertaining commentary on what they're doing and why.

Added bonus for having it streamed real-time with a chat like twitch does, so the person streaming can interact with viewers.

Benefits:

- Promotes your core product
- Supports your core product by providing some great quality answers
- Scales well with other Stack Exchange sites
- It's a unique idea. There are tons of video tutorials already out there, but I don't think I've ever seen programmers streaming programming.
- You would probably get more viewers for videos by providing entertainment first and education second, rather than vise versa.
- You'll probably build up a small library of great video clips demonstrating many different educational things, such as how to use SO, how to program in X, how to use technology Y, etc and therefore contribute to your original idea
- Its a cheap experiment to setup if you want to try the live streaming - just create a twitch.tv account. You could even incentivize volunteers with ad/viewcount based profits

Comment: You know what else this idea of yours can be used for? Creating smaller videos that can be replayed, and putting them somewhere that new users that are confused and want to learn better how to use SO can watch them. Livestreams for education on the subjects, other videos for use on the site, and the main idea of videos exploring general technologies.

Comment: Awesome- Pretend you have an extra 5 upvotes from me. :)

Comment: or just use youtube.

Comment: As much as I'd love to dare-I-say mentor new users better, I doubt that people who won't read a short help article will watch a video. (There's also a higher potential for a language barrier there, since web pages can be translated and videos ... not so much.) (cc @Kendra)

Comment: Also wanted to chime in and say that I rarely ever watch videos for educational purposes. As someone said in above comments, you cannot easily skim through them to get to the good and relevant parts. However, I am intrigued by that "infotainment" idea. Over at YouTube is a channel called "Numberphile" that also has a sibling show called "Computerphile". I really enjoy their videos. If you manage to get "rockstar" and "legendary" computer scientists to talk about interesting and amusing IT stuff, I will be the first subscriber. Also tongue-in-cheek commentary or some news format sounds fine.

Comment: YouTube supports live events now, and it's for the general public, not just invitation-only like it was a while ago...

Comment: I gotta be honest - this sounds absolutely dreadful. But then, I don't get Twitch either. Anyway, if you *like* this idea, check out [the Stack Overflow rap](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J9z30ulAizU).

Comment: My friend used to have a ustream channel where we would code and people would watch, ask questions, etc. I'd be so down to run a stream for this.

Comment: Some people already stream coding on Twitch (specifically games for mods), but I'm not sure how well this would work, since I'm not sure how interesting answering most questions would be...

Comment: @Shog9 To be perfectly honest, I didn't get the attraction to watching other people play video games at first either until I started watching some streams that friends recommended. I'd definitely be interested in watching some of the better-known or intelligent programmers in my favorite tags theorize about and solve problems on SO in an interactive stream :)

Comment: @Shog9 - I don't get Twitch either.  But to be honest, I do kind of like short videos on YouTube of some COD or GTA dude cursing someone out when he keeps getting killed.  Guilty pleasures...

Comment: @Shog9: Ditto for me. I'm a big gamer and have been for decades and just don't get the appeal of watching somebody else having fun instead of me. Maybe it's a generational thing? And don't get me started on "e-sports". On-topic: I'm not a fan of the OP's suggestion, but if enough people like the idea? Live and let live.

Comment: +1 I like this idea. Basically a Twitch.TV for programmers?

Comment: @AnnaLear You do have a point with that... But it would still be something worth doing. And I know some people that learn how to use things better when shown. My suggestion was more for the people who want to learn and just aren't getting it in writing well. Different people learn differently. :)

Comment: I would watch Jon Skeet answering questions

Comment: @Jeff That's exactly the kind of thing I was envisioning :) Being able to watch/interact with the top names in my favorite tags (or any intelligent programmer in my favorite tags really) as they reviewed, explained, and answered SO questions would be really cool. I would learn a whole lot.

Comment: @rachel yeah! Jon Skeet's channel = 99.9% of all traffic :P

Comment: There's nothing to stop someone from starting up a twitch channel to answer SO questions now, but it would be far better if we could get the SE dev team's support and some links on SO itself. In addition to SO managing who's stream they promote, maybe they could also do something like *"if you have X reputation in a specific tag, we'll feature the link to your SO stream somewhere"*. Also for the record, I know of twitch streamers that make 6 figures. It pays good if you can do it well.

Comment: I wouldn't mind seeing either a Stack Overflow *Let's Play* ("5 hours of jquery answering"), or a speed run ("quickest to get 1000 rep"), or a 100% run ("get all the badges and approve 50 edits").

Comment: Personally, I particularly don't see how this would work out. My experience browsing SO is basically "WTF is this? DV, CV. WTF is that? DV, CV. Oh look, here's a specimen of the coveted endangered species Decentus Questiens, too bad it is a duplicate of another hundred questions." Well, maybe other users have a better SO browsing experience that they'd like to share.

Comment: @NobuGames this was actually a suggestion that had been brought up - I like the idea of having devs (sometimes even our own) and answer questions submitted by the community. Make it more casual, more community involved, while still serving a lot of the purposes we've come up with here.

Comment: This is a completely serious question… How do you find time in the day to sit and watch people play video games? I mean, I get how you can do it once or twice, maybe on a weekend when you have nothing much else going on. But I have those weekends fairly infrequently. And there's absolutely no way that I can find an extra hour in my day that I can spend watching online videos. Who knows, maybe I'm just a weirdo. I still find it almost impossible to believe the statistics that Americans watch something like 4–5 hours of TV a day. I don't even own a TV.

Comment: @CodyGray I was pretty surprised at that statistic too. I usually watch something while I eat dinner most days (I usually eat at my desk), but that's normally only 20-30 minutes at most. Occasionally I'll watch something on weekends or right before bed too, but that's not too often so I probably average 4-5 hours a week total. I'm sure it helps also that I have no kids, and a pretty quiet social life :)

Comment: Somehow I feel like watching a day-in-the-life would be like watching [The Website is Down](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uRGljemfwUE)...which could be actually amusing, as well as informative.  It isn't a bad idea to try out--people could see what tools answerers use behind the scenes (virtual machines, IDEone, etc)--those who don't have moderation privileges could see what buttons people have to push and why they push them.  Sounds informative, and nothing stopping anyone here from being the first to front-run SO TV with the better/cheaper/more-unique idea...

Comment: That sounds like a great idea. I definitely see myself watching this if it's good enough, meaning if the person doing it really is an expert who knows a lot if answers right away and is entertaining on top of that. I imagine those people to be kind of rare, but if there is someone who would do it, I'm all for it! I'd even subscribe to that twitch channel to give him some money.

Comment: I think a general Code/Programming Streaming site would be a better idea than specifically watching users answer SO questions. Some people have streamed their programming sessions on Twitch, but it's technically against their ToS.

Comment: I sometimes wonder where do @Shog9 find those stuff....

Comment: The only way I'd be interested in watching *someone else* browse SO is if it were done In the style of Mystery Science Theater 3000, that is if the commentary was more interesting than the SO content. Could be very funny a few times, but I don't think I'd watch more than a couple episodes.

Comment: I had the same idea. This makes much more sense then SOTV.

Comment: @AnnaLear It would be nice if the 'small help article' were better signposted. I've been here for a few years now and I've never seen the fabled help articles, nor do I know how to find them if I wanted to read them. Have you ever considered that people don't read them because they can't find them?

Comment: @Pharap New users are shown the how-to-ask/how-to-answer pages when they first post, and they have to click through a thing to confirm that they read it. They almost inevitably either don't or do but ignore what it said.

Comment: @AnnaLear So basically you're telling me people only get one chance at reading the pages and if they didn't because they were in a hurry to register then it's tough luck?

Comment: @Pharap Nope. They are linked in the sidebar from the "Ask Question" page: http://i.stack.imgur.com/CHqMc.png

Comment: @AnnaLear Thank you, that was very helpful, I now understand why I've never been able to find the help pages - they are somewhere I would not have expected.

Comment: @Pharap Help articles about asking linked from the ask page? Inconceivable! :)

Comment: @AnnaLear Actually I find that location bad too. It's in the area typically filled with ads or uncommon content, and is usually ignored by most people browsing sites of SE's style. Pharap, I was looking for the faq page on another SE site yesterday and was getting annoyed by not finding it anywhere too. I finally found it in the "help" link in the footer (and later in "Help > Help Center" up by my username). I expected "help" to be a generic manual on how to use the SE sites, or tech support, but turns out it also contains the info that used to be in the FAQ too. I agree, not very intuitive

Comment: @Rachel Yeah, sidebar's not great. Numerous discussions have been had on that topic. Thing is, I'm not convinced that just moving the links would fix all our problems. I can see the argument against putting something important there on the sites (*ahem* community bulletin), but there's literally nothing else there on Ask Question.

Comment: @AnnaLear Maybe put it on the home page. It might just be because I'm using ad block but the sides of the screen are pretty bare, so maybe they'd be easier to find the help if it was filling some of those gaps on the main page.

Comment: @Pharap We don't support Ad Block and there are better ways to spend space on the front page.

Comment: @AnnaLear Ad Block is another matter entirely, though I can respect any website's dislike for it. I think it would be interesting to see if placing it on the front page reduced the number of people that haven't read it. Either that or some other way to more actively prompt users to read it, particularly the first few times they ask questions/post comments (doing it more than once may help to imply its importance).

Answer (score 91):

Some of the responses that I've read here have unequivocally reinforced something that I've been concerned about for quite some time:

***We have over-trained some of you, and that's preventing the exploration of new ideas.***

In 2008, Stack Overflow *was* a new idea, and a *great* idea - there was nothing that existed where:

- I could actually *edit* things to improve them
- I didn't have to scroll through 40 pages of 'me too' just to find a broken link that everyone was raving about
- Questions I asked didn't get side tracked (or outright hijacked) with tangentially related bike shed painting
- *The best stuff actually rose to the top!* - and that was magic. Why hadn't anyone thought of that before?

Through the years, we've realized that some things tend to break our platform, like pure mindless fun. We also realized that our platform *tends to break other things* like library recommendations that aren't narrowly-scoped - when everyone has voted and gone home, the artifacts they leave *don't* always age well.

That doesn't make those things *bad*, it just means that we can't be everything that every programmer would want in a single place. *That doesn't mean we throw our hands up and just say 'oh well, we'll never have those things', it means we look for opportunities to do new things instead*.

Let me talk about something I'm quite proud of, our spam protection system. It's not perfect, but it does keep between 15 to 20 *thousand* turds out of our pool every day. Want to know what that's built on? Redis, mostly, and the boiled brains of the ones we managed to catch red-handed. Why is that important?

I put off learning how Redis worked until finally seeing someone do some really interesting thing with hash sets on a 15 minute tech talk interview. The learning curve was much shorter than I imagined, and I immediately loved it once diving in. That 15 minutes was *well* worth it. I don't normally watch tech talks unless it's about something I've been considering.

If we're going to *try* something new, something that *might* just help one or three of you make a more educated decision on where you're going to spend the limited bandwidth you have for trying out new toys, what harm are we doing? How are we negatively affecting the brand and community that we've established? These are something *outside* of normal Q&A, something that many of you have been wanting to see us do. This doesn't change how we do *one* thing very well, this is a whole different thing.

This could be a thing that people will find very useful. If it can save someone from downloading and trying something only to think an hour later *"I'd like that hour of my life back, please"*, ***then why not?*** It's worth a shot, and if we don't continue to look for ways that we can be even *more* relevant to people that write code for a living *in ways that don't break what we've gotten right*, well :)

Comment: You have not over-trained us.  You have well-trained us.  This is off-topic for SO.  If you want to create this site, and when it's ready link from SO to a beta to try it, go for it.  It's not any more off-topic than the careers site, so great.  But if you bring it to the community to discuss it, inside the site dedicated to discussing the community, then this is the response you're going to get.  It's off-topic.

Comment: @Erick - would it help if you thought of this as a new feature of Stack Overflow, rather than some random website Joel Spolsky is creating for fun?

Comment: It just means SO has gotten too big a monster for the "owners" to tame

Comment: This started as a community of programmers that worked together to solve problems and provide great answers that were easy to find. Then things changed. Suddenly we were told things had to fit a specific scope and definition for the site. Even though we might want to ask the community here a question that they would be best qualified to answer, we suddenly had to go elsewhere because the question didn't fit specific rules. Some users left, and those that remained had a higher concentration of rule-enforcers. And now you're suddenly surprised that Stack Exchange is subject to these rules too?

Comment: That said, I think it would greatly help if you added more specifics to the question itself. For example, I was picturing hour long videos instead of 15 minute videos. And tutorials for introductions to languages/technologies, rather than brief comprehensive overviews. With such a vague description, everyone has a different idea of what is being proposed here, so I think it would greatly help if more specific details were provided

Comment: Has there been any progress on this yet?

Comment: It's interesting, of course, that recorded videos fail on the advantages mentioned.  If I see a typo, I can't submit a correction.  If I learn faster or slower than the presenter is speaking, or I want to see whether this video shows significant amount of code, or demos a complex application, I have to scroll through thousands of frames of video.  There won't be competition between multiple answers on the same topic where the best can get voted to the top, rather only videos officially filmed at SO headquarters will exist.  Basically, the proposal is for Yahoo Answers TV.  But even YA! votes

Answer (score 38):

I really don't see the point.

Stack Overflow is not a place where you can discuss about how to code. Stack Overflow is not a place where you can discuss about what technology/framework/language to choose. Stack Overflow is not a place where you can discuss *at all*. Anything opinion-based is literally banned from this website. If you're new to a framework and have a general question about it, Stack Overflow is not the place for you.

Stack Overflow is about asking specific questions and getting specific answers. Stack Overflow is a reference for all programming issues you could have. It's the top 10 results when you're googling for an error message you don't understand.

**So please, tell me how is Stack Overflow even remotely related to video tutorials?? I don't get it.**

Comment: I can't believe all the narrow minds here.  The people who run stack overflow (no, I mean actually run it, who collect a salary) are clearly trying to do some bigger things than what SO normally does.  And why shouldn't they?  They have probably the biggest, smartest audience of devs in the world: why not try to parlay that into something more.  This may or may not be the best idea, but it's quite silly to say that SO shouldn't do X, because SO doesn't usually do X.

Comment: What about chat, the third(?) place (meta being the second) - aren't discussions allowed in chat? This could be the fourth place.

Comment: @AdamRackis Sorry, just trying to find some consistency in there. The FAQ of Stackoverflow currently says: _Don't ask about Product or service recommendations or comparisons_, while the goal of those videos is described as: _the viewer should know whether this is a technology they want to pursue further_. If I ask this on Stackoverflow my question will be closed either as too broad or opinion based within seconds. I don't see any valid reason I should upvote this feature. Stackoverflow is a Q/A site for specific developer issues, not a place you start learning X or Y. That's just unrelated.

Comment: @ken2k I would agree completely if they said they planned to do questions like this. If they're doing a programming based video to introduce people to technologies and not putting it on the main sight, but instead just giving it the name Stack Overflow TV to show the correlation of programming, I don't see as big an issue. I would argue... Different media, different rules. Chat vs. questions, for instance.

Comment: `If I ask this on Stackoverflow my question will be closed` - It's pretty standard for the SE team to use MSO to announce new features and happenings that they're working on.

Comment: @AdamRackis I was talking about the content of the videos, not the announcement itself. Pretty normal to talk about that here indeed.

Comment: @ken2k - in that case you're making an even sillier argument.  SE team is trying to do something NEW.  Something they haven't done before.  I don't know if these videos are a bad idea, but saying the videos should have to have content that comports with existing SO standards is kind of senseless, don't you think?

Comment: @Adam Because the most successful companies stick to doing one or two things *really well*, lest they lose their competitive edge. Resources are finite; new projects shouldn't be started just because they sound cool. Especially when your core brand (Stack Overflow) is festering. If the SE team has extra time, there are a lot more important things that they could be working on. The first rule of good management is knowing when to say "no". You have to decide what your mission is and focus on doing that. ken2k's point is that this seems to contradict SE's core mission.

Comment: @AdamRackis: Nobody is telling them _not_ to do videos. Yes, some people have pointed out the disadvantages in videos as a medium for teaching, but general backlash is about Stack abusing their position to bend their own rules for them. They could have used their blog and ads to promote it.

Comment: @Cody - I'm glad the people at Google didn't have that mentality when someone pitched the idea of Android. I don't know how much the SO brand is festering, but I also don't think the resources they're putting on this (some video production equipment / people) are really taking away from cleanup up SO: Joel has plenty of devs on payroll at SE.  Anything not getting fixed is likely for reasons other than lacking resources.

Comment: @Adam: It's not about a couple of technical bugs; it's about a _fundamental_ problem with SO that is well-documented on meta lately. It's all well and good saying "we have good devs here, why not use them?" but when you're in the middle of a brain drain with your experts _leaving in hordes_ due to fundamental misclarity about SO's core mission, well, that doesn't seem like the right time to further confound the problem. Also I think you vastly underestimate the effort required to implement this idea.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - I wasn't aware SO's devs were leaving.  That probably is a problem if true.  What I was trying to say is that the types of problems facing SO are incredibly hard.  The hard part of fixing them is figuring out what to do, and how to address them.  I don't think this idea prevents that, and if they ever do figure out HOW to keep the low quality crap off SO, I assume they have the devs to implement it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Where did you hear that? I'd be interested in hearing what former devs at SE say about why they left

Comment: @Rachel: I'm not going to reproduce here the contents of the largest meta.SE threads all year.

Comment: @Rachel: http://meta.stackexchange.com

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit ... I see. When you said *"you're in the middle of a brain drain with your experts leaving in hordes"*, followed by Adam's comment of *"I wasn't aware SO's devs were leaving"*, I had assumed you meant SE employers. I see you actually are referring to SO users. Ok different story then :)

Comment: @Rachel: Oh, yeah, sorry.

Comment: Similar things that are, by your standard, "unrelated" to what SO does haven't caused doomsday. See: Careers 2.0

Answer (score 34):

*The following line is what made me interested in this project:*

> the viewer should know whether this is a technology they want to
>   pursue further.

*I don't work for a traditional software company*, and we have a wide range of experience in my department.  We are often experimenting with new technology, and it has become a regular task to demo a technology for the group and decide whether we should use it in upcoming or active projects.

Providing a comprehensive demo of a technology without becoming an expert in it first can be difficult.  Stringing together pieces of tutorials from the web and assembling a quick and dirty use-case often leaves out crucial features or limitations.

**If the Stack Overflow TV provided the following, I think it could be very useful to a wide audience:**

- Demonstrate the strengths and limitations of the technology
- Provide simple, real world use-cases
- Compare the technology to its competition
- Remain Objective (as much as possible)

**Remaining objective** will likely be one of the greatest challenges to this project, as the presenters obviously believe in what they are presenting.  I've seen some concern in the other comments and answers regarding SO providing recommendations for products.  If this is done objectively enough, I believe that viewers will understand that it's not a recommendation or endorsement, rather an informational "quick-start".

Comment: I feel people are assuming videos will be primarily "how do I add 2 numbers together", or some code example. If videos are conceptual, or a broad demo of a technology, I can really get behind that.

Comment: I think the other biggest objection is that `Stack Overflow is a Q&A site`, and `my question would be deleted`.  That's what Stack Overflow is now, but why is change so terrible?  They are planning to add a *feature* to "`serve as a complement to Stack’s Q&A`".

Comment: And (if it wasn't clear), I do agree with you. Though interestingly I would think the topics should be more about Programmers.SE, rather than Stack Overflow (concepts rather than specific questions).

Answer (score 26):

As long as you put these out on a regular basis then it could be interesting.

I'm unlikely to ever watch them, but I much prefer text to podcasts or videos - simply due to time.

However there are many people who are different, and prefer videos and/or podcasts.  The issue with your current podcast is that it isn't regular, and it isn't very compelling.

If you can produce videos on a regular basis (start out at one/month for now, then ramp up as you schedule forward) then you may end up with content that will attract an audience you don't currently cater to.

If your release schedule is irregular, though, or you don't make the videos reasonably compelling, then this is likely to become another albatross around your neck.  Something you have to do, but no longer want to do because it's not gaining the traction/audience you were hoping.  Not unlike your podcast.

I wish you luck! I hope you find what you are searching for with this endeavor.

Comment: No need for CW anymore!

Comment: CW is dead anyway

Answer (score 23):

There are two axes of criticism here:

1. Stack Overflow is again using "in-band" communication leverage of its Q&A meta-channel--*which is trusted on good faith to be spiritually belonging to the volunteer community that built quite a lot of it*--to do promotion for projects that are tangents. Such posts would be looked on harshly if non-SE-employees posted their own similar ideas.
2. If Stack Overflow is considered a system which has finite resources to spend on addressing issues--expanding into new areas is not what the online MMO Q&A game addicts want right now. They want those resources applied to get the problems in the game patched up.

*(It's funny that the sidebar advertisements promoting the role playing stuff remind me of how this really is very, very similar to trying to manage a D&D campaign. You want to get everyone to play nice, to keep people from walking away from the table. I think the stakes are higher here as I consider it education and a piece of planetary-scale problem solving, but games educate too in a way.)*

I think #1 is foundational. In that vein, I have re-entered an off-topic close-vote in protest on this basis. Of course I'm not blind and know you run the site and can delete any vote I raise or post I make. But...I'll point out that you do control the ad space...and you have a blog. No one will get on your back any more than the "get a goob at Stack Exchange" ads that you don't charge yourself for (well, in a sense you might, if you had paid ads you're not running). But worth it for more clicks and less backlash.

Posting in-band here isn't fitting. There are other voices saying: *"we are giving you feedback that you're encroaching on the part of the space that was promised to the community to manage issues of the game they bought into."* Please think again the agreements of those coming to play at a D&D table, and the risks of appearing unfair to the point that people want to walk away. You benefit much more when people say "that was a good game, we'll be back next week!" vs. knocking all the pieces off the table and saying "YOU, SIR, ARE A TYRANT!"

*(Though that can make for its own funny melodrama. Depends how zen you want to get. I'm trying to stay in character, a little.)*

As for #2, that's fuzzy. I wouldn't like people telling me what I should or cannot do with my money and time; outside of pre-existing agreements, where I should live up to my promises. If someone told me I was a programmer and shouldn't make videos I'd inform them quickly that I left an engineering job in Seattle and went to attend film school in LA in 2005. Video isn't perfect for all things, but until we get our Diamond Age primers we're stuck with video, Ajax-Rube-Goldberg, and some [Bret Victor stuff](http://worrydream.com/MediaForThinkingTheUnthinkable/) *(which is often well-shared by means of video, for anyone doubting the value of the medium.)*

So I don't feel as strongly that anyone has a right to mandate that SE doesn't use its investment dollars to expand; that's outside the "implied contract".  I can only share a personal feeling that you may take or leave.  That feeling comes from the observation that growing pains are overwhelming, yet I have not perceived the kind of "continuous advancement" from the site tech there once was.  It's a spooky kind of Craigslist feeling, almost like the original developers died a long time ago--and now maintenance zombies run it, because nothing is changing at a speed one would call impressive.

I love unicoins and hats as much as the next person, but why haven't there been more trials of strongly supported feature-requests?  I'll still plug mine as deserving at least a shot to see if it can make a statistical dent.

[Pre-flight screening checklist for first/early posts--adaptively pick three items, tune with metrics](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265671/pre-flight-screening-checklist-for-first-early-posts-adaptively-pick-three-item)

If you would just promote your video projects and women in technology ideas through the ad space, and announce new features at a rate that everyone felt the wheels of progress were turning...I don't think anyone will care if you make videos or buy solid gold computer desks. Yet the game has some implicit rules that the players feel you are breaking, and some of us are speaking up about it.

Comment: Perhaps we need to create videos explaining our feature requests and bug reports? I think a 5 minute short of the Stack Overflow homepage with periodic refreshing would be sufficient to make the point.

Comment: I guess the other criticism is the overloading of the Stack Overflow name. Personally I don't have much criticism of that, because S.E. have created a successful brand that they naturally want to use for other initiatives. But it does leave us needing to differentiate clearly between Stack Overflow the *site* and Stack Overflow the *name*.

Comment: Addendum to #1: Asking a non-question on here as a SE employee is especially ill-received if the OP then leaves for two days. There was virtually no interaction of OP with any of the responses except for the initial "oops, we failed to set up a mail address, fixed now" edit. We can clearly see how the "ask questions as an answer and we'll respond in the comments" model fails in this case, as it turns into "express your issues and hope anybody from SE ever reads them". And as Ganesh says, issue #3 is an unclear distinction between SO and side projects, potentially confusing even more new users.

Comment: That was really well said.  I think the argument *for* using MSO for this stuff, instead of the blog, is that the community can give feedback more easily here.  An answer with 100+ upvotes stands out a lot more than a blog comment.  Maybe I'm just more easy going in my old-age 30's - I take it for granted that the people who run this place can hijack MSO once in awhile for stuff like this, while I can't.  I would never expect any different.

Comment: @AdamRackis Well...if that were the angle, then it should be framed as a question like: *"We live in a video era and have been wondering...how might StackOverflow incorporate video features into the site?"* vs. *"We have made a plan, and are doing it, and here is an ad for the thing we are doing--so e-mail us now."*  We don't know what reactions would be to the former because that is not how they've approached these new initiatives that people are complaining about.

Comment: @HostileFork - fair.  Or even "*We live in a video era, and we have the following plan for incorporating .... What do you all think?*"   They probably could improve some of the soft skills the SE people have when they make these posts.

Comment: @AdamRackis Yup.  Or put their proposal as an answer to the question which can be voted independently from the question, and peer to answers that others might offer.  (We cannot compare--for instance--@Rachel's counter-proposal popularity to theirs because they tied their plan in with the "question".)  When you have a free labor force working for *your* success (and success of the Internet/world, hopefully), it does pay off to take steps to avoid alienating them.

Comment: Regarding your first point...meta is still the place for the community to discuss and manage its issues. Posts like this one are relatively infrequent and *don't prevent anyone from beginning or participating in any other community-started thread*. Discussions started by SE staff can and do coexist with discussions started by users. You all are plenty happy to see staff here responding to your bugs and feature requests; why are you so hostile when we want to share new ideas with you?

Comment: @Laura Science "proved" that women are not inferior to men, rather [less differentiated](http://qph.is.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-ba7c85e19585f68031d863702588d951?convert_to_webp=true). Hence the majority of problem users in moderation (disproportionate to usage by gender) are males. Am **I** allowed to post on Meta about my project to mentor low-bell-curve men? I'm joking--but the point is that things become tyrannical if **you** can do them and others cannot. I have [cool projects](http://blackhighlighter.org/) too, but I can't just post them here and not have them closed. It's about fairness.

Comment: @Laura To add to the comment by HostileFork above, regarding your "You all are plenty happy to see staff here responding to your bugs and feature requests" - please do browse questions with the "feature-request" tag. Most of them have no official response whatsoever. The hostility might partially come from the fact that people feel completely ignored if highly upvoted proposals do not seem to grab your attention, but loosely SO-related side-projects do.

Comment: @HostileFork you may be interested in the [meta discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238990/should-stack-exchange-inc-promote-its-pet-projects-on-meta-sites) on the use of meta for this type of announcement.

Comment: @Laura but how can you even call this a "discussion started by SE staff"? OP posted this "question" and stuck around just long enough to respond to the first two comments and fix the mail address, then left for three days, then posted _one_(!) comment about the reasoning behind not giving the speakers money (which is, btw, helpful). The mentoring post was a discussion because SE staff actually interacted with the responses and cleared up many things that were unclear. Just like the mentoring post, this one would certainly benefit a lot from clearing things up, but nobody from SE does so.

Answer (score 5):

Stack Overflow is two things for me:

- A community of very talented experts, offering valuable assistance
- A website offering most of the answers of my daily Google questions

So as a member of this community what would I have loved to see in videos?

- Community related things

  - **Interviews** of some of theses great guys.

    - Who are they?
    - Why are they doing that?
    - What did they learn doing it?
    - What makes a question worth a response for them?
    - Are they part of the entity known as Jon Skeet?
  - **What's new** on Stack Overflow or on Stack Exchange?

    - What are the trends on meta?
    - Things we've fixed
    - Result of elections
    - Under the stack: meet technicians, executives, etc
- **Newbies** related stuff, I'm pretty sure they will look at videos more often than read the warnings and FAQ

  - How to write good questions
  - How to search in previous answers
  - How to find gain reputation fast with great questions and great answers
  - Common misbehaviours
  - Anything that could help people to become part of the community.

Your proposal is about technologies: "should I invest some time in this tech", etc. This is a very tiny aspect of what a So-TV could do for Stack overflow. And it's something really hard to do. If I had enough time to make a perfect technology videos "X versus Y" or "10 big ideas to start X in the right way", with drawings, animations, great ideas, some jokes, stuff for newbies and tricks for experts... I would become a youtuber and hope some retributions on the millions of fans. But usually I do not have this amount of time and motivation, and I peak one or two questions like I would play a game.

My point here is not that everybody will react this way, but finding the great video teachers, the ones which make videos session worth a play, means building a new part of the community, I'm pretty sure theses videos stars will not be the same individuals as the current gurus. It will be a **long** quest. with a lot of bad stuff maybe.

So if you invest some time on video, I think you should certainly start with the basics and experiment technology-sessions as a very small subset of other subjects.

Answer (score 5):

Why don't you make videos on the subjects covered on meta?

So we watch the videos, follow charismatic speeches and use Stack Overflow better. Stack Overflow's problem is that so many users have a very vague idea about how to ask questions, answer and vote.

Your business is not teaching programming: that's what your customers (we) do. Your business is to organize people into something more sophisticated than a mob.

Answer (score 4):

There are sure a lot of people criticizing the idea in these answers! And to be honest, I'm not convinced either. I guess the big question for me is, why do you want to do this? Is it:

- To make more money (a perfectly valid reason for a for-profit company)
- Because you think it will complement SO Q&A in a particular way
- You want to try a new idea, like you did when starting SO at the beginning?

If you gave me a good reason why you want to start SO TV, I would be more willing to get on board with the idea and have a better idea of how SO Q&A and SO TV will eventually relate.

Answer (score 3):

I see a lot of comments along the lines of "Intros aren't what SO is about."  There are tons of people every day who ask a question on SO or programmers.SE for the first time thinking that's precisely what we're about, and they are rebuffed.  I think it would be great to have a convenient place to point those people, and I for one welcome the idea.  Everyone's a newbie in some areas, and videos are one of the best ways to introduce a topic, even if they are a poor reference.

I think it's a mistake about the speaking fees, though.  You should consider exceptions for well-known authorities:  Rich Hickey talking about Clojure, Dries Buytaert on Drupal, Simon Peyton Jones on Haskell, Linus Torvalds on git, Larry Wall on Perl, etc.  You get a better feel for the philosophy behind a technology from its creator than from any other source.  To be honest, on those kinds of topics, the quality of production and content is going to have to be pretty high to get me to look on SOTV for an introduction instead of a lecture straight from the source.

I think volunteer speakers are better suited for smaller, more general topics, something like "Immutability:  what is it good for?"  That's the kind of thing I would look to SOTV for, especially if it saves me from filtering out the cruft, and reliably points me toward more in-depth resources.

Comment: I don't know, I think "you can't ask that question here; go watch these videos instead" is still going to be counted by most people as a rebuff. If introducing a chat room feature didn't solve the problem of people wanting to ask off-topic questions, then I fail to see how Stack Overflow TV will.

Comment: I would pay money to hear Linus give a talk on GIT.

Comment: @AdamRackis https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4XpnKHJAok8

Comment: The creator of a technology is certainly not the best impartial critic of it. I would prefer some independant experts on docker, mongodb or other fuzzing trends. -- but *that* is the hard part, choosing *who* should introduce a technology on SO, this is an editorial choice.

Comment: It has been said before that you could point them to the various SO chats. There newbies can interact with experts, free of charge. You can even copy/paste code.

Answer (score 3):

There is only one set of videos that we need that would really apply for Stack Overflow.

## Title: How to ask a technical question

Discusses the common issues with how to get to the point of writing a good question. Your own debugging, research, distilling the examples and the language of the text. It could show best-case examples from the commonly closed questions.

These would then by joined with:

## Title: How to effectively answer a technical question

Discusses how to elicit information to the salient bits and then how to best convey that. It would in many ways be the next step of the first video. The questioner in the first video would be the encouraged to refine their question further and the answers would be distilled by third parties into canonical answers.

Both of these are extremely relevant on Stack Overflow and to many Stack Exchange sites. But the general idea of discussing new technology wouldn't really be appropriate here as many people above me have stated with excellent reasons.

Answer (score 2):

What's the end goal of the experiment, SOTV or SETV? Can we foresee a [*Seasoned Advice*](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/) episode? Something like *"Pumpkin muffins by [SAJ14SAJ](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all)"*..?

Of course it has to start somewhere, and where else but the head site of the network?
I agree with all that raised the "get hands dirty" approach: reading explanations and dealing with bare code are a must, and a ***programming*** video may be clumsy for something that's pure `text`.

But, for high end discussions and conceptual/operational/life-experience presentations, yes, please, [100k+](https://stackoverflow.com/users?page=6&tab=reputation&filter=all)'s videos à la TED talks would be prime time.
What about `"Pekka 웃: Being a programmer on an Atlantic island"`?
Eight thousand views per day!

---

Comparing [videos to the Stone Age](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270574/an-experiment-stack-overflow-tv/270593#270593) may seem bad, but it's not. People passing knowledge to other people was done orally and face to face well before it went all papyrus and then all interwebs. [Video on education](http://www.ted.com/talks/salman_khan_let_s_use_video_to_reinvent_education?language=en) is another step away from Gutenberg's middle ages. TV and Internet are 20th century technologies that together allow us to connect with our fellow humans in ancient ways. Audiovisuals never reached all of its educational potential; only taking a step further on the last few years with cameras everywhere and easy YouTube for a lot many of us.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you're tired after a day of work, and you just want to sit back, relax, and watch something. I watch scientific lectures a lot, and they are much more enjoyable than reading the papers they are based on. The last 50+ years show that watching TV is one of *homo sapiens*'es most favourite things to do.

Some examples I would find interesting to watch:

- A helloworld example with Hadoop and some cloud. Show what can be built in 1 day and $10.
- Comparing 2 or more best-of-breed products side by side, such as 2 popular IDEs.
- In general, I would find anything about the relationships of several different technologies to each other, and to typical design problems, more interesting than overviews focused on just one technology. For example: the relationship Java — Hibernate — MySQL I would prefer to watching something about just "Hibernate" (which I might have no idea about).

Folks are adamant that this site is not about recommendations, period. And yet, recommendations are one of the site's de facto most useful features.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a great idea! Stack Overflow is a website specifically focused on answering programming questions. It is not the right format for tutorials. Creating a new service for short, focused, video tutorials would be really valuable.

[It is well known that people learn in different ways.](http://www.ion.uillinois.edu/resources/tutorials/id/learningStyles.asp) Some people learn easily by reading written tutorials, others prefer to hear or watch someone else do it. When you combine the senses, there's a higher chance that the information will be retained. Personally, I am a paid subscriber to many websites which offer screencasts and video tutorials. I find them extremely helpful in learning new subjects. I rarely seek out written tutorials on subjects that I know nothing about, or have no interest in. However, I would much rather watch and hear someone teach me something. Also, some people experience impediments (such as dyslexia, vision loss) which make it difficult to long articles/tutorials.

Answer (score -1):

Notwithstanding the arguments about whether video is a good medium for a tutorial, I think
Stack Overflow would be redundant here - by being **just one more place for tutorials** instead of losing its core strength as a place of

- Troubleshooting
- Research
- Problem solving

A tutorial has an aim to arouse interest in the subject, and I think that is the basic intention revealed here by the OP.

Here is my direct take on that one:

- If someone already knows Stack Overflow, he isn't at a stage to need this kind of guidance.
- If someone doesn't know Stack Overflow, he already has other sources that can tell him whether to pursue a subject / area or not.

So why this? And why on Stack Overflow?

**Suggestion:**

Maybe, make a list of YouTube video URLs that can serve as a quick-start or a for dummies kind of guide to each subject. They can complement Q & A that are too verbose for certain problems. Far better & cost-effective than those introductory tutorials by experts.

**P.S.:**

Notwithstanding everything I voiced, and considering this is adopted in practice, I still don't understand the need for in-person presentations like TED. Stack Overflow being a torch-bearer of remote work, there must be better way to leverage expertise across the globe without physically being together - unless this is some kind of conference imparting specialized technology knowledge, which I am sure this is not, at present.

So *chat/present* -> *record* -> *upload* -> *shortlist* -> *publish* would be a far better workflow.

Answer (score -1):

I like the idea, but also like the comments/critique on *making the experiment more useful* . So perhaps:

- Speaker/subject matter expert does the talk
- After the talk, a "hangout" (or whatever, basically a *live*) Q&A session where the speaker *answers questions from the audience* are also recorded as part of the show.

I think this would enhance *"...the viewer should know whether this is a technology they want to pursue further."* and further SO as a place of learning, teaching, helping, solving.

This suggestion isn't "original", in fact, it's a "copy" of "developer conferences" e.g. Google I/O where: `Presentation -> Q & A -> recorded -> made publicly available`.

Hope this helps...

Answer (score -2):

Unless it's a joke (what month is it? April?), I'd vote yes for this. And I'd suggest features to be added in this.

**Videos can be relevant to Stack Overflow**

We can put them in tag wikis. That's because tag wikis are the place where people look if they want more information about the tag. And if the information is in the form of a video, it'll be better. Another feature we can put would be to post multiple videos in a single tag and upvote/downvote them as per the quality and relevance of the video to the tag.

Even if you won't implement my ideas, I'd still vote yes for the video feature :-)
Go for it!!!

Answer (score -2):

Unlike nearly everyone else, I like the idea. Why?

**It Teaches Stuff**

While it may be a departure from the traditional Q&A, it still accomplishes an intended goal - teaching. It may be a great way for some programmers to learn about new concepts, technologies, etc. To those that don't learn visually, don't watch the videos, but it could be great for people that do.

For those that say it dilutes the Q&A idea, past experiments not using Q&A haven't caused the apocalypse (See: Careers 2.0)

For those that say it is unrelated to the aim of the website, consider that it still teaches.
Regardless of the format, why not just do it, so that people can learn stuff - the goal of this site. It's not like it is replacing Q&A - what's wrong with more ways to learn?

Answer (score -2):

Why are people saying this is such a bad idea? Perhaps it might not be something you personally are interested in but so what, a lot of other people could be.

I think there is a fairly simple solution if you disagree with the idea, don't contribute to it and don't participate.

As long as it doesn't affect the current ***free*** community service you get, who cares?

Answer (score -4):

Yes, leverage technology, of course!  Humanize this site a bit. After all, most of us are people and not binary-consuming keyboard jockeys. It makes sense to branch out based on what Stack Overflow does best -- answer questions. Because it is a vast repository for any inquisitive fact-finders of all walks of life, providing answers that can be consumed by the most people is how it will continually expand its usefulness and value. Talk about building confidence in the answers; real experts are sharing their knowledge directly through the camera, not through some semi-anonymous post.

**Remember, you don't have to watch these videos, but videos illustrate and build confidence in ways simple words appearing on a screen can never do.** Videos reinforce much more effectively, because it uses visuals, time, and sound -- it's how our brains are wired best to absorb as much knowledge as fast as possible. If you're just using Stack Overflow as a "snippet snatcher" and you think these videos will be a waste of time, don't watch them -- save the site bandwidth for someone who will.

If providing answers is Stack Overflow's main mission, then proliferating useful knowledge is its business and that means expanding the channels and diversifying how it can deliver those answers to more and be even more useful. People learn and absorb material differently, and we as a community could offer to type and edit the transcripts and there will be volunteers who will be happy, and thankful to be involved.

Videos are a great way to dig deeper into subject material and relate on a person-to-person level. They instill confidence because they're open and not anonymous, but also, they could make learning more difficult material easier for dumbies like myself. Lastly, it could be fun and encourage more involvement from the younger generations. Some don't like change, but did video really kill the radio star or did that radio star just decide he didn't want to show up on TV?

Comment: If a radio star is a radio star because he likes radio and not TV then, yes, video killed him.

Comment: That is a suicide.

Comment: No, it is not. If you want to be ridiculous about it then it's more like genocide: altering the environment to a degree that a species goes extinct. The radio star didn't decide to be a radio star: they were born with the inclination not to be a video star.

Comment: Sorry, I never wanted to be ridiculous, I was apparently just born that way.  By not seriously considering improving and adding methods we use to help people learn (the goal of providing answers is to learn) seems ridiculous to me.Let's just agree to disagree about it, keeping an open mind to new ways to reach people because brains are wired differently and people learn differently.  That is an admirable goal

Comment: Perhaps but not at any cost

Comment: Btw, using your analogy above: we're altering the environment, yes, we're altering it by EXPANDING it.  Giving your "species" more room to thrive, more tools to survive.

Comment: Then the final sentence in your answer is irrelevant to the discussion, and should be removed.

Answer (score -4):

I agree with a lot of what has been said here, and would like to make a single point if I may:

**As long as the video integration doesn't get in the way of what SO was created for, go for it.**

If I can ignore this feature as easy as I can consume it, no harm done.

Answer (score -4):

Great effort... You people thought of it, and I think it's great (period).

People always say: *try not to bash into the walls too much*. Do not try new things. Don't invest in innovations. But who cares?

And if you had obeyed such sort of *pessimistic critics* before, then Stack Overflow wouldn't have been there in the first place.

So: go for it. Great effort.

The videos will be like [TED videos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TED_%28conference%29), and it's awesome that guys who help people find answers over at Stack Overflow will get to interact with the same people (what's more awesome is that Stack Overflow is ready to compensate the travel fare.)

Answer (score -7):

I guess it is against the Stack Exchange philosophy. Which is, from my understanding, about `Question -> Answers`. YouTube is already there for showing video.

---

Update: from my comments:

> The Stack Exchange Network is better than any forum because of its implementation design,
>   the format. So then the format of that video / layout / tagging should
>   be as good as Stack Exchange is and much better than YouTube. Whether it is good
>   content in those videos or bad it is not so important - people vote
>   and then bad content will disappear. The format/design/user experience/searchability is
>   important.
>
> I'm an end user of Stack Exchange. And for me it is question-answers site, where only one
>   answer is marked as right + votes. That's it. Whatever "philosophy"
>   it follows officially. So it has nothing to do with teaching. I do not
>   see it. A know good site for teaching, like [Coursera](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coursera) or similar. But
>   if one already decide that it is good idea, well - we will see. I'm ready
>   to like or dislike it.
>
> For example: Google is not YouTube, and YouTube is not Google. YouTube sucks
>   compared to Google search. It is nearly impossible to find something
>   using YouTube's search. So I use Google search to find stuff on YouTube. Well, Stack Exchange may
>   tag a YouTube video to make it better. No need to store video on its own
>   servers. So YouTube is just a storage with bad search. Google does search.
>   Stack Exchange does tagging. Maybe it will work out, then we can search by tags - that is a question of categorizing and filtering then. And that should come with subtitles to make it possible to search by content. Or let Google do it over the Stack Exchange like it does now.

Stack Exchange without Google is zero... Well, 0.2, not zero. So far, so Stack Exchange + video should be searchable  by text and tags I guess. And there is much stuff to improve in Stack Exchange itself (I wish it would be even better)... before jumping to video.

Speaking about improvements:
**For example, once I did an experiment: I did downvote without a reason for some guy's post (the post itself was good enough). And then everyone start downvoting that post, so that it goes from for ++ to --. People tend to follow someone's idea without even thinking. That should be improved. People should not be able to vote up or down without a reasonable/comment (at least as anonymous). Imagine if you have a good video for 'experienced developers' and then one newcomer with high scores downvotes it, because he found that it is too complicated for him or just do it for fun**.

> For me even this conversation is not "format", because there is no "right
>   answer". It looks like like a general messy forum.

Comment: "You shouldn't create new things because old things already exist" is not a very compelling argument. Also, I don't see any reason why these videos couldn't be shared on YouTube, just like you can find TED talks there now. The philosophies of SE have always been "increase the signal to noise ratio" and "make the Internet better." Q&A is just one way of doing those things. There are others.

Comment: Stack Ex philosophy is about building a robust, amazing knowledge base; you have a myopic view of life if you think that can/should only ever mean Q&A.

Comment: Also youtube has so many bad developers showing their bad skills and earning views and upvotes for it ( not all of them ofc ). If i were to make a mysql tutorial with php and would be using mysql_* function which are deprecated, i'd be the king of the hill.

Comment: The SE is better than any forum because of its implementation design, the format. So then the format of that video / layout / tagging should be as good as SE is and much better than YouTube. Whether it is good content in those video or bad it is not do important - people vote then bad content will disappear. The format/design/ux/searchability is important.

Comment: I think StackEx could be an arbiter of quality and it could create a great learning resource.

Comment: I'm end user of SE. And for me it is question answers, where only one answer is marked as right + votes. That's it. What ever "philosophy" it follows officially. So it has nothing todo with teaching. I do not see it. A know good sites for teaching, like coursera or similar. But if one already decide that it is good idea, well - will see. I'm ready to like or dislike it.

Comment: Just cause the irony amuses me: (1) If Google had decided not to build a search engine because it had already been done (which it had), there would be no Google.  (2) That same Google...you know, the search engine company?  Owns a little pretty-far-from-search-related video sharing site called *YouTube*.  Branching out seems to have worked OK for them.

Comment: And SOTV isn't SO, and SO isn't SOTV.  It's not like they're going to be putting videos on here.  It's effectively its own project, just with SO's name attached.

Comment: Well Google is not YouTube, and YT is not G. Y sucks comparing to Google search. It is nearly impossible to find something using YT search. So I use G search to find stuff on YT Well SE may tagging YT video to make it better. No need to store video on its own servers. So the YT just a storage with bad search. Google does Search. SE does tagging. Maybe it will work out.

Comment: But... but... SO doesn't get any cash from Youtube videos! And indeed that's what it all boils down to. Nothing is stopping anyone from making such videos today and uploading them to Youtube. It seems blatantly obvious that SO just wants a piece of the advertising cash, by "inventing" something that was already invented over ten years ago.

Answer (score -13):

Best-case scenario:

I think this is an amazing idea. It'll (no doubt) enhance/solidify the Stack Overflow brand (not as if Stack Overflow actually *NEEDS* it).

If anything, it just means Stack Overflow is "A BIG DEAL"; and every time someone is linked to an embedded Stack Overflow video, they'll be reminded of the brand, and how pervasive it is as a technological resource/powerhouse. It could also intrigue current high-school/college students to use the site.

Worst-case scenario:

Stack Overflow might even get bought out by a larger company, and begin charging for Stack Overflow resource material. And then... other sites will rise up to counter-act the newly implemented pay/pay-as-you-go model.

SOtv sounds pretty cool, but...

I don't want what happened to [Business of Software](http://businessofsoftware.org/faq/) (BoS) to happen to Stack Overflow. Where BoS used to be FREE!!!!!

But now, NO! You have to PAY to watch those videos. (Hear that Joel? CHANGE THAT!!!)

In retrospect:

I understand everybody has to eat, but if Stack Overflow were to do this, in a non "f*ck you" kind of way... I can see nothing bad coming from it. Just make it FREE!!!

Comment: What is BoS?​​​

Comment: from the site: "Practical learning from the best in the field:  Speakers at previous editions have included Dharmesh Shah (Hubspot), Seth Godin, Joel Spolsky (Stack Exchange), Clayton Christensen, Alexis Ohanian (Reddit) Geoffrey Moore, Scott Farquhar (Atlassian), Eric Ries, Kathy Sierra (JavaRanch), Jason Fried (37 Signals)" ........ url: http://businessofsoftware.org/ ....... some videos: http://businessofsoftware.org/2014/08/where-are-they-now-bos-speaker-alumni/