# When is it ok (if ever) to provide a video example?

Tags: discussion

Video examples have a ton of drawbacks.

- Many people cannot view them at work
- they could be hosted somewhere and then removed later, resulting in broken links.
- They're a waste of time when text will work
- They could be the result of lazy writing

However, given that, is there **ever** a situation where a video link is acceptable?

For instance:

- animation glitches that are difficult to describe
- supplementary info that is also described ("and if you want to see what I just described, I made a quick screencast")

I can see the argument where the drawbacks are similar to using JSFiddle or other external links, especially if the video doesn't have audio. Just wondering if there is unwritten community consensus on this one.

Comment: A video may be super-helpful, but the biggest problem with them is that they *can't be searched*. If the information can't be communicated by text or code examples, then it's ultimately useless for any sort of actual search.

Comment: I hate video examples, personally. I guess they are acceptable as supplemental material. But I know if I see a video in a question I will immediately move on to something else--I have never seen them used *in addition* to a good question, only in place of one.

Comment: You can easily go back to the second point you made and say `many people are not supposed to be on Stack Overflow at work`.

Comment: @cybermonkey Is there a workplace that forbids stackoverflow? If so, what else does that workplace forbid? Searching javadocs? cppreference? Dictionaries?

Comment: @cybermonkey now that is just cruel.

Comment: StackOverflow for TV (and video) purposes [was deemed a terrible idea](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270574/an-experiment-stack-overflow-tv).

Comment: @Cubic The last time I checked not *everyone* on Stack Overflow worked in programming.

Comment: Other con: they aren't accessible. Blind people cannot see video and, up until now, we don't have video-to-speech programs...

Comment: @Bakuriu Not to sound insensitive, because I have no knowledge about the subject, but how easy is it for blind people to write and debug code?

Comment: @Compass I believe it *was* asked on SO or meta if there are blind people programming and I remember some nice answers. I personally know a blind developer. Surely being blind doesn't help, but it is possible and we should take into consideration such people.

Comment: @Bakuriu Fair enough. I had just never considered the subject before, and from my perspective would probably put the loss of my sight before loss of hands as the biggest impediment to programming.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Your answer, *on SO*, needs to answer the question.  If you want to include a video *in addition* to that answer, you're more than welcome to, but if your post wouldn't [attempt to] answer the question without the reader following the link to the video then it would be Not An Answer and would be subject to deletion.

Comment: I like that simplicity for providing answers.  What about in providing helpful information within questions?

Comment: @timshutes The same general principles apply.  The question should be complete, high quality, and answerable without the reader following the link.  If you want to provide a link to a video *in addition* to an otherwise complete and quality question, then you're welcome to.

Comment: @timshutes I should also point out that links to videos being hosted on another site are often one of the *first* things that corporate firewalls block (youtube, vimeo, etc...) making such answers "you should check out this blocked link".

Comment: IMO Video is the same as images - acceptable if it helps illustrate a point, but doesn't change the core content requirements.

Comment: In many cases, forcing the OP to phrase the problem in a text format will require them to step back and think about it enough to provide a useful high-quality question, where in a video it would be easy to do a screen capture showing "something" with a narrative something like "SEE?!?!!1?!!1one!" which would just be a video version of a low-quality question.  For questions, I can see video being a nice supplement in a very few cases.  For answers, I can't think of a programming case where a video would be required to provide a useful response (answers are usually technical rather than visual).

Comment: Think of the value of SO to the visually impaired.  Video questions/answers would be largely useless for users of screen-readers.

Comment: @jinglesthula That can go both ways; imagine the value of a video to someone who doesn't speak the same language (or who doesn't read/write well in that language, even if they can speak it and understand it verbally).

Comment: @Servy True.  I think people for whom a SE site is in other than their native language are probably going to be best served by something like google translate.  If the site is in their native language but they are illiterate, I suspect that at least SO will not likely be of use or interest (I could be wrong, and that certainly doesn't hold true for other SE sites).

Comment: @jinglesthula I answer a lot of graphics questions, and videos can be extremely useful in diagnosing problems. While it's a minority of questions even in that domain, I can sometimes tell exactly what's wrong after seeing a couple of seconds of animation. No amount of text would be equally conclusive, and not even still images are nearly as useful in those cases. I totally agree with Servy that it should always be an *addition*, but it can be a very valuable addition on occasion.

Answer (score 21):

I think embedding a gif could counter most of those drawbacks.

- Don't need to rely on an external website which can be blocked
- No broken links
- Usually short and to the point
- No sound; you still need good writing.

Since you cannot do a voiceover, text will still be mandatory. An animated gif will only be there to show what you cannot express correctly, not replace your entire post.

There's probably multiple free screen-gif-recorder on the web, personally I use [LICEcap](http://www.cockos.com/licecap/), which is open-source.

As an example, here's me typing the beginning of this answer:

[image: a gif]

It took about 10 seconds to setup.

In the past, I recall having used gifs at least once, on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24966433/resharper-8-typing-property-closing-brace-adds-another/24966641#24966641), to support something which appeared unclear to me.

But even if it can be a great visual aid, it is still pretty distracting/annoying, so use sparingly.

Answer (score 18):

Additionally, glitches and other 'moving' problems have been successfully conveyed by animated gifs of just a couple of frames.

To me, videos take too much time to make and watch. I cannot quickly grasp the key element of a video in order to decide whether that answer is worth viewing completely. With text, in general, I can.

Answer (score -9):

It's good when a post (answer or question) includes a video to complement the code.  But *only if the code generates a video as a result*, or the code does video processing, and you need to illustrate the result of the code working with video.

But if the video is posted without a code, this is very bad.