# Should we inline a blinking animated gif?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, images

I've read [When is it ok (if ever) to provide a video example?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278267/when-is-it-ok-if-ever-to-provide-a-video-example), but I couldn't find advices regarding blinking animated gif.

In the following question, should we inline the gif (using the `[![…][1]][1]` markup syntax), or would it hurt the eyes too much?

- [Xcode 9.2 iOS simulator is not launching any apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48476753/xcode-9-2-ios-simulator-is-not-launching-any-apps)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In a nutshell: **GOD NO!**

[image: GOD NO!]

That GIF in particular is almost seizure inducing and should most certainly not be inlined. Even more subtly animated GIFs suffer from a *"Sh*t, tiger!"* reflex: human attention is attuned to things moving in our peripheral field of vision; it may be a tiger lurking in the bushes, and we want to pay attention to it. That can seriously distract from reading, writing or just plain thinking. So let's keep pages as static as possible.

Comment: [blinking tiger](https://www.litter-robot.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/Slow-Blink.gif)

Comment: …slouching dragon.

Comment: "That GIF in particular is almost seizure inducing" - that might justify a disclaimer on the not-inlined link to the image.

Comment: Fun fact: I scrolled down far enough for the gif to be out of view before reading this answer.