# Has Jon Skeet answered the questions asked in "Thanks a million, Jon Skeet"?

Tags: discussion

> **Update: [Podcast #123 – Jon Skeet Wants You To Be a Feminist](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/03/14/podcast-123-jon-skeet-wants-you-to-be-a-feminist/?cb=1) has been released.**
>   <sub>**Note:** although there are answers to a few questions on the podcast, it does not include the full Q&A session, which has yet to be released.</sub>

[Thanks a million, Jon Skeet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362019/thanks-a-million-jon-skeet) was published near 2 months back.

Hairboat, who published that topic, said:

> What would you like to ask or share with Jon, either here in text or conveyed in person when he sits down with us in a few weeks? [...]

So SO users asked lots of questions and now **8 weeks** have passed.

I would like to know if he answered these questions?

If not, when will Jon answer them, and how will we know that he has? Where should we check?

Comment: It's only been 3 weeks. The typical timeframe in which things get done is 6 to 8 weeks.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there'd be a similar post by Abby, when the time comes.

Comment: @BoltClock Or 1.1M Skeet rep

Comment: @Machavity Or he's waiting for 1048576.

Comment: @rgettman   1048576?

Comment: @Iam It's 2^20.

Comment: By that time he'd be 2M.

Comment: @BoltClock I thought it was _"6 to 1e1000"_ weeks.

Comment: I'd upvote @BoltClock's comment, but it is at 42 currently, which is an answer, so I don't want to change it.

Comment: My respect to Jon Skeet, and Reading town with wonderful people, but I request a feature to filter out Hot Meta questions - it would add two checkboxes [ X ] Jon Skeet [ X ] Tag burnination - these clickbaits steal my productivity. Or maybe we can filter by tag and create a special TAG?

Comment: @GuySchalnat At the time of my reading your comment, the current upvote count for BoltClock's comment was another auspicious number >42, albeit less Douglass-Adamsy.

Comment: Aren't people tired of the *6-8 weeks* joke?

Comment: @Adelin I'm sure they'll eventually get tired of it - wait six-to-eight weeks

Comment: @Orangesandlemons - godamit I loled...

Comment: @BoltClock Now 8 weeks also gone

Comment: The guy is way too busy answering SO questions, he has no time for META

Answer (score 42):

From that same question:

> We’ve also got plans in the coming weeks to celebrate Jon’s achievement and thank him for his hard work and dedication to helping his fellow programmers and the Stack Overflow community. Part of the celebration will include an IRL Q&A with Jon himself

So if you haven't heard anything, it's probably because it's not been celebrated yet, or hasn't been transcribed yet.

> and how will we know that he has?

I think at that time a blog post will be made, which will then be linked to in the yellow box now showing only "Hot Meta Posts".

**Update**: well, it's here (or at least [partially](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364647/looking-for-transcript-of-jon-skeet-podcast#comment565199_364647)): [Podcast #123 – Jon Skeet Wants You To Be a Feminist](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/03/14/podcast-123-jon-skeet-wants-you-to-be-a-feminist/). I'd love for it to be transcribed though, as you asked in [Looking for transcript of Jon Skeet podcast](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364647/looking-for-transcript-of-jon-skeet-podcast).

**Update 2**: now [there's a video](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/05/01/jon-skeet-answers-your-questions-irl/?cb=1), as Jon himself also [answered below](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/367066/). Still no transcript.

Comment: But you must hurry! He just won't stop earning points!

Comment: Will he answer less questions that day due to travel/interview?

Comment: "*IRL Q&A with Jon himself*"... on [Stack Overflow TV](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/270574/2821954)! (okay, I know that's a bad joke...)

Comment: @usr2564301 "So Jon, how hard was it to earn 1M points?" "Well, a lot harder than the second million, let me tell you" :P

Answer (score 26):

[Yes<sup>1</sup>.](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/05/01/jon-skeet-answers-your-questions-irl/?cb=1)

---

<sup>1</sup> I owe the community a blog post with answers to the questions we didn't get to in the office. One day...