# Is the new "marry whomever you want" title image out of place?

Tags: discussion, logo

There are a lot of current events and social issues taking place in the world.

Is it a good idea for Stack Overflow to become politically active, especially for events that have nothing related to programming?

Questions are flagged for having opinions and being off-topic.  Should those rules be enforced if the site itself is being hypocritical.  Perhaps this is setting a bad precedent for the future?

---

*Note: Personally, I commend what is happening in the U.S., but don't feel that Stack Overflow is the best forum for it.*

Comment: You know why the banner changed though, right?

Comment: I am not against it? but are we going to change logo to pink on AIDS day, black on terrorist attacks, white for peace or etc?

Comment: It's a site about programming.  Set up a site about politics or the law, or gay marriage, if you want to change it; it doesn't apply to Stack Overflow.  The internet privacy issue (SOPA) *may* apply.  Programming-related news may apply.  Gay rights is not programming-related.

Comment: In support to you http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297886/681929

Comment: So because @Joels Spolsky has a particular emotional ties to it and he is a creator, he's going to do what he wants.  It's not about being neutral on social issues; it's about an issue being off-topic to Stack Overflows content.  It is entirely hypocritical and bigoted.

Comment: No… the question hasn't been asked there.  The question asked there was a plea for someone to display it for a few days and the answer was that they would.  My question applies directly to the philosophical foundations of the site, "should it be displayed?" and it is a much more important question.  This question should be **reopened**.

Comment: See also: ["What is the policy for Stack Overflow and political matters, such as the logo color change?"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297908/what-is-the-policy-for-stack-overflow-and-political-matters-such-as-the-logo-co) , which covers your question more directly.

Comment: @vol7ron I hear you. In chase of wide acceptance of gays they saturate the patience (oh, tolerance) of *really neutral* people. It's like yelling "save the nature", "stop aborts" or "go vegan" in library or museum. I never hated or abused people I can't understand, nor planned it, and that's what I get back. Why not just spawn gay.stackexchange.com?

Comment: @BradLarson That question is a little closer to a duplicate as mine, but still not close enough.  It's better in that it's more objective as "What is the policy?"; however, my question is still "should it be the policy?"  Another question is "What determines the policy?"  Apparently if something gets enough votes from the "community" (because let's be honest, it's not the whole community that saw or voted for that answer), then it goes directly into action? Any motivated group can get users to come in and vote something up.  The creators bias are showing, but this site should be free from bias

Comment: @user3125367 http://lgbt.stackexchange.com would not be a bad idea.  Again, I don't really care how someone chooses to live their life; but whether it's a pro-penguin group, KKK, PETA, or some Global Warming interests group - what we perceive as good or bad - it shouldn't have a place for coding/programming.  SOPA and PIPA, maybe;  Dennis Ritchie's death, yes.  Michael Vick's dog fighting - no.

Comment: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/72607/lgbt

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270123/find-a-better-mechanism-for-stack-exchange-facilitated-recruitment-attempts  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297919/whats-the-next-political-move

Comment: What's happening is a segregation of the supporters of the site.  What is transpiring is people are starting to contemplate their contribution to the site.  That is the exact reason you don't get involved in political issues.  Why?  Because now a certain group of people feel alienated and that usually results in disambiguation from Stack Exchange, then law suits, then new competition (alternatives).  This is the exact thing I would like to avoid - I enjoy the community (users and creators) as they are and would like to avoid this disruption.

Comment: Prediction: none of this is actually going to happen. The community has seen much more dramatic rifts - actually *substantial* ones - over site policies. The place is still doing well and will continue to do so regardless whether there was a rainbow in the logo for two days.

Comment: @Pekka웃 you're probably right; we're all moving to a point in time where everyone has short attention spans and the need for instant gratification.  Still, developers love to be challenged and to create something "new".  So I could also see this as a call for competition; it aligns people and that sometimes has a synergistic affect to give new causes momentum and sustainability.  It all depends on which people care and how much they care.

Comment: There's a lot of things about SO that would make a valid call to competition - the extremely narrow scope, the deletionism - but a gay flag is hardly one of them.

Comment: No, those are features; this is a fundamental philosophy.  This particular social issue doesn't really affect me - I'm happy for everyone it benefited - but what happens when it's a social issue I don't agree with?  I've promoted SO so much. StackExch was built with the community in mind, until one of its creators wants something.  That doesn't scare you?  SE has so much information about you; at least Google and Facebook have some checks and balances within their organization - this seems like Stack Exchange doesn't when it ultimately does whatever the creator wants.

Comment: All this because of... a rainbow flag in the logo? That is set to be there for two days? seriously?

Comment: `SE has so much information about you` really? How much of it is actually data that isn't already public? Pathetically little. If you, at some point, find that SE has gone somehow evil, you are free to take [*their entire data dump*,](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange) which is licensed to the public, for free, and start a competing service. Yes, you have to acknowledge SO and link to them but the knowledge can all survive without SE the company. That level of transparency is so many light years away from Google or Facebook, it's hard to put in words.

Comment: @Pekka웃 1) I don't think I can say it enough, but how many ways must I say this? - it's not about the flag, it's about the decisive choices that have been enacted and what little control/voice you have as a participating member of this site.  2) If you think the posts you make and the data you see is all there is, you are sorely mistaken.  I don't want to question your expertise as a web developer or systems engineer, but I challenge you to think what other information might be contained or ascertained and how having someone's identity can be abused.

Comment: "Decisive choices that have been enacted" - you're acting as if every site change over the past five years had been made after extensive consultation with the community, and careful gauging of all its doubts and sensibilities. Nothing could be further from the truth. The site is a private property and has always been shaped by unilateral decisions on the part of SE, occasionally taking feedback from the community into account. And how you make the leap from "gay site owner puts flag in logo" to all these vague sinister machinations "until one of its creators wants something" still escapes me.

Comment: @Pekka웃 I am done with this prolonged discussion.  How the site was five years ago or 1 week ago is insignificant.  The issue has already been presented, whether you acknowledge it or not.  Every decision is not the same and I have not yet seen this particular discussion on SO/SE yet, regardless if the company is privately-owned and operated, or not.  There are license agreements and debates taking place and that is why this question is important, to answer these outstanding questions; no matter the stance.

Comment: Finally, to the one ignorant question… `All this because of... a rainbow flag in the logo? That is set to be there for two days? seriously?` if that's how you feel, if it's not important or this is silly, then I guess you're in support to take it down because silliness would be fighting against something you don't care about.  Obviously it's important enough to someone to put it up and it's important to other people that feel it should come down for various reasons; some have merit.  My initial question stands *does Stack Overflow want to become politically active, despite the hypocrisy*

Comment: That statement does no signify he finds it silly or unimportant. Rather that the fuss that is being made over it seems somewhat out of whack given the short timespan that the logo change will be active for an occasion as momentous as this one.

Comment: What browser are you using? It shows up fine on Opera, Firefox and Chrome on Vista

Comment: @Bart The "seriously?" suggests it's silly that people would have a problem with it and it is disregarding their feeling towards the decision - mind you, the *rainbow flag* isn't the issue, it's the principle that the rainbow flag could be anything - you both are failing to see the issue.

Comment: @random the topic is about the logo on http://www.stackoverflow.com not http://meta.stackoverflow.com — curious why meta was not changed; it would at least be a little more appropriate there than on www.

Comment: @Pekka웃, The question is asking whether non-tech sociopolitical issues are appropriate here. It's [speaking out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_they_came_...#The_text) to ask if we should start cheering for the left-wing, cheering for the right-wing, or whether should we just keep ourselves out of non-tech sociopolitical issues. It's not about the rainbows.

Comment: @user3125367 No, how are we forcing anyone / persuading anyone to be gay? We're celebrating what has happened, and it's not hurting anyone. And also, guys, SE is a dictatorship not a democracy. They can do what they want with the site btw. Especially if 78.96% (80%) of the votes are for it - this is the feature request: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297859/can-stack-overflow-and-metas-logos-be-changed-temporarily-to-the-loveoverflow

Comment: @Tim - Votes on a locked question aren't necessarily indicative of the overall opinion split. Early voters are more likely to be supporters. The question was locked prematurely.

Comment: Yeah they can do what they want, but it's a bit arrogant toward users who don't identify themselves with LGBT movement. Imagine you bought a ticket for an airplane and airline owner is a nazi and paints a plane with nazi symbols, so you look like nazi when entering and leaving the plane.

Comment: Why would you buy a ticket if you already knew the owner was a nazi? Why would you then get on the plane with the symbols on there? @doc

Comment: @random O.K. for more precise analogy - owner is painting the plane with nazi symbols while you are already flying, having no idea about his views.

Comment: It's a bit extreme to compare homosexuals to nazis, but I think @doc's analogy is that imagine you're already on the plane and don't care if the pilot was a Nazi or not, but then when you look out the window you see the symbols flying.  I think his analogy is he is already on this SO plane and while he can get off, it'd be a big hassle.  There's Paparazzi taking pictures when you land and the one "screenshot" with your profile and that brand can affect your work, career, or livelihood in certain countries.

Comment: I understand what Doc is saying, but that is not the original meaning of the question I asked, but I think meta should have an area where it could be discussed and pursued in more detail.  However, it seems the community and admins want to close anything that differentiates from themselves or the creators interests, even if it might benefit the site and the wellbeing of its members.

Comment: And of course I am not comparing homosexuals to nazis. I have nothing against homosexuals. Against LGBT political movement - yes. Example is extreme to show the point.

Comment: It's a privately owned site, they don't need to answer to users who want to oust its board of directors at some annual general meeting

Comment: @random I don't think anyone thinks it's not a privately-owned site, or that it's some open source project.  I keep seeing this.  Yes it's privately owned.  It's privately owned.  It's privately owned.  Understood.  The owner can trash it all, turn it pink, turn it into porn.  I fail to see the fact that it's privately owned as a reason not to listen to its users/customers, especially when they are essentially the business.  The generated content and page views come from the users.  The value is in the user base.  Why wouldn't you want to at least consider their opinion?

Comment: They listened. They replied. That you don't agree with their response doesn't mean that there is now a need for an inquest, royal commission or some other "they must respond to our allegations and demands post haste" type of court

Comment: They didn't listen or reply.  Someone asked a question to show support, someone said, "hey that affects me, i like that" and does it.  Someone else freezes the page from any further comment.  Anyone new coming along cannot be listened to because they can't participate — the question was frozen and the users are being silenced in any follow-up questions.  @random be very careful in how you phrase your response because it seems like you encourage this behavior.  BTW, I don't seen anyone saying that.  If you believe that, then I encourage you to re-read this chain of comments from top to bottom

Comment: Just FYI: your inability to vote to reopen again is not a bug. You only to get vote to reopen a question once. You don't get to vote again if it's later reopened and reclosed, or if your vote expires. This is to prevent the same 10 people from repeatedly closing and reopening a question forever.

Comment: @JeremyBanks that makes sense, but I would think if the reason for closing has changed, then you would be able to vote to reopen again.  Sometimes there's no point in reopening, a person concedes the question is off-base; but other times, someone that closed maybe wasn't paying full attention, or didn't completely understand the content.  So it's important to show there's a desire to reopen.  If a person can't choose to reopen based on different closure reasons, it comes down to who has the bigger support net of people for or against.

Comment: Have you asked this of other services you use or have accounts on? GitHub, YouTube, Twitter, they're in support, do you ask the same of them for the user contributions to be open to similar policy movements? But yes, fully in support of SO, SE, whatever, shutting down spurious comments and discussions they've already settled, especially when the users keep trotting out how SE are akin to Nazis

Comment: _but are we going to change logo to pink on AIDS day_ - @HaveNoDisplayName - **Red**. The ribbon color for HIV/AIDS awareness is red, not pink.

Comment: @random I fail to see where or how I direct my attention is of any significance to Stack Overflow.  SO has rules specific to staying on-topic.  It punishes users and closes/deletes questions that go off-topic.  Github, Twitter, Facebook don't have topic-related restrictions.  I consider SO to be that much more professional for having these rules and staying out of sociopolitical events; but yes, when I see something where others are being hypocrites, I certainly contribute my time and voice.  However, I prefer to stay focused on the subject of SO/SE, since that is where we're at right now

Comment: _Because now a certain group of people feel alienated_ - Is this supposed to be irony?

Comment: @BSMP `Because now a certain group of people feel alienated - Is this supposed to be irony?` No.  Are you under the impressions that all users of this service are from the U.S.?  There are people that feel alienated for different reasons.  I would think that the homosexual community leaders of SO would take this opportunity to not alienate anyone.  In doing so, it's another form of hypocrisy.

Comment: They've chosen to direct their support behind the ruling. You've chosen to direct your attention on their support behind the ruling. A logo is not a question and does not fall under any kind of topicness or scope about quality of questions

Comment: @random do you have a hard time reading?  You're repeating the same thing, which everyone knows.  I suspect you're being argumentative for the sake of arguing.  The OP on this page deals with, *should they be doing this?*  Not what they did or what anyone believes.  It's a meta question about Stack Overflow.  ***Should it be done?***  It's simple.  It hasn't been asked before. -- Is this a policy that the creators should be doing.  It's similar to a public relations mindset.  "We know we can do this, we have the power to do this, but should we be doing this?"  This question shouldn't be closed

Comment: As a user, I'm curious what your reaction will be when it's something you disagree with.  What if they changed it to a picture of Ray Rice beating his girlfriend?  What if they changed it to a girl being human-trafficed?  Again, my stance is indifferent to the actual ruling, my question transcends the ruling and is more about the decision that went into the site, but what happens when it is something I don't agree with?  I rather know now and be able to discuss this with the owners/managers now.  This site is partially a reflection of me.

Comment: Fully in support of human trafficking as a slippery slope for arguments

Comment: `What if they changed it to a picture of Ray Rice beating his girlfriend?` then I re-evaluate, at that point, whether I want to be a part of these sites or not.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298007/is-the-new-marry-whomever-you-want-title-image-out-of-place#comment213047_298007

Comment: @Tim I'm not actually making a big problem out of it. But there are people that *still* not understand nor care — and we were surprised it has to be on main page, that's it.

Comment: @random You miss two points, imho: despite the site is private, we are still clients and *we* generate profit, not soneone else. It is unprofessional and unrespectful to make decisions like that "oh, I'm <xyz> too, just put it on front" without careful social research. Second, you have to look for specific european brands at your home — a big chances you supported an earlier-nazi or nazi-friendly company (a lots of them popular brands now). Not that it all very serious, but... :)

Comment: This is getting to a point where I'd suggest someone post an actual answer. All these comments aren't going to achieve anything.

Comment: @Bart it probably won't get any answers now, but a big point is it shouldn't be closed in the first place. I'm fine with the negative votes, but I think people are being naive or short-sighted. It's easy to be blinded by emotion, but I would like to appeal to logic and reason.

Comment: Re my dismissing it as "just a flag", Bart puts it perfectly in the answer below, much better than I thought to. It's not a call to action for a social cause, which would be problematic no matter how good the cause. It's just a symbol of celebration.

Comment: @DeerHunter Nonsense, there was a steady trickle of 5 up 1 down all evening, I was watching it. It now sits at -150 +500 ish. There are a large number of votes still going on the for and against answers. It was not locked prematurely, the change had been made. I'd also like to say that it was the people objecting to it that caused it to be locked. It was closed and reopened 2 times, and at the point of locking it had 3 close votes. What for? "Not being about [so] of all things"...

Comment: I am in general in favour of people being allowed to do what they want with their private businesses. It is their property, and therefore theirs to do with as they wish. Is it appropriate? Maybe, maybe not (depends on how long it is there), but people can always leave. The problem is that the other side of the coin is not respected. People with even moderately opposing beliefs to this don't enjoy the same freedom. They are generally lambasted and hounded and in some cases have lost their jobs. So I find it rather distasteful in that respect.

Comment: @Pekka웃, Ray Rice beating girlfriend is a bit extreme... I don't think anyone would be supportive of him except maybe his family members. What if the **banner now reads, 1)** "Osama has been hanged, let's celebrate"? or **2)** ["export of cryptography from the U.S. is now allowed/banned, let's celebrate"](http://goo.gl/PZpbeH)? or **3)** "referring to a black as nigger is now banned/allowed, let's celebrate"? or **4)** "nazi [literature have been burned](https://goo.gl/ElR5sx)/preserved, let's celebrate"? or **5)** "killing animals for food is now banned/allowed, let's celebrate"?

Comment: @Pacerier I don't think those are great examples, but to humour them anyway: I would be glad about some, dismayed about others. Some of them might even get me to stop participating in Stack Exchange because I'd realize the people running it have views completely incompatible with mine. Now what?

Comment: @Pekka웃, I'd think we both agree then that it's good to avoid [this disruption, as mentioned by](http://goo.gl/ekRXQE) vol7ron.

Comment: @rghome that there are some regrettable and outrageous examples of people with "incorrect" views becoming subject to mob justice doesn't make the cause unworthy, and doesn't have anything to do with celebrating a Supreme Court decision. Gay folks have been lambasted and hounded, lost their jobs, and worse, for decades, if not centuries. There are still countries where homosexuality can be a death sentence.

Comment: @Pacerier not really - it is not an actual disruption if you don't choose to view it as one, IMO. It's reasonable to expect tolerance for it even by those who disagree with the SC decision (yes, I know there are perfectly legitimate reasons for that) or with celebrating it, or with gay marriage. It is obviously not making a statement about any of its users and their gayness or their position on gay rights. It is not actively soliciting support for a social cause. It really is a nonissue.

Comment: @Pekka웃, IMO it's reasonable to expect tolerance for the [5 issues I mentioned above](http://goo.gl/rk5F40). As you've mentioned, they are **by definition** not actual disruptions if you don't choose to view them as such.  On the other hand, [you also stated](http://goo.gl/nVbgPv) that these issues while being non-disruptive *"might even get me to stop participating in Stack Exchange because I'd realize the people running it have views completely incompatible with mine"*. I sense internal conflict of viewpoints due to [lack of coherence](http://goo.gl/UxGDDu) and consistency.

Comment: @Pacerier nonsense. None of your hypotethical examples is likely to be celebrated here in the same one as this one was, and you know it. Also, if people are going to walk away from SO because the rainbow flag, or the SC decision, or gayness offend their sensibilities, then there's little we can do about it. If you make every one of your decisions depend on no one getting offended, you will very quickly find you can do nothing at all.

Comment: @Pekka웃, How likely was cryptography to be considered military equipment under U.S. law before WWII? Hindsight will always be 20/20, are you sure the points I raised are not likely?   [Point #2](http://goo.gl/Z0VTZC) is likely to be celebrated if Joel has strong views on that subject. Point #3 is definitely likely to be celebrated **if Joel was [black](https://goo.gl/o0m2vy)** or has strong ties with one. Indeed the kind of oppression black people face is [way beyond](http://goo.gl/I1oQns) what lgbt can imagine....................................................................................

Comment: .........................‌​....................................‌​...............................................‌​......................The OP is not advocating that decisions should be made only when exactly zero people gets offended. OP's question is simple, 1. Is it professional? Should it have been done? 2. In the future should we do it? For example, **should** we celebrate it's **anniversary** every year?

Comment: @Pacerier if the CEO of the site were black, and we were living in 1865, would you begrudge his celebrating the passing of [the 13th amendment?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thirteenth_Amendment_to_the_United_States_Constitution) That seems like a more apt comparison than the banning of a word. (About that, by the way and off topic, if you like offensive but hilarious and intelligent comedy, check out [this South Park episode](http://southpark.cc.com/full-episodes/s11e01-with-apologies-to-jesse-jackson).)

Comment: @Pekka웃, 1865? Not even close. Blacks are still being oppressed [today](http://www.usatoday.com/story/news/nation/2014/11/18/ferguson-black-arrest-rates/19043207/) and **[right](http://goo.gl/dYPZsW) [now](http://blogs.wsj.com/law/2014/01/08/study-49-of-black-men-are-arrested-by-age-23/)**. While it may neither be offensive, hilarious, nor intelligent, you may want to look at https://www.quora.com/Why-do-some-black-people-disapprove-of-gay-people/answer/Desmond-Hardy for more info.

Comment: @Pacerier all valid points, but all hardly relevant to what we're discussing. It was still a turning point perceived as a liberation, a newly gained right that the state had so far wrongly withheld from them.

Comment: @Pekka웃, My point aligns with the point of the OP's question. The point is that in the near future we can look forward to more social issues regarding "equality" and laws that enhances it, along with [people on the site with starkly differing social viewpoints](http://goo.gl/9MrgGr). The OP's question is asking **should** these events be celebrated in the future? Dismissing his question as "because of a rainbow flag", or "unlikely to happen" is missing the crux the issue.

Comment: @Pekka웃 what does being black have to do with programming? Yes - I'd have a problem with this logo changing in that case. If we encountered World Peace and had a day to celebrate, I'd have an issue with SO changing its logo. However, if you want to celebrate or recognize something controversial that relates to programming, like Alan Turing's death, then fine. I might not agree with it, but at least it's related to the subject.

Comment: I'm re-reading these comments, most of which were in the wee hours of the morning.  I would like to say, it feels like we (as a group) covered many different aspects, viewpoints, and clarifying questions.  It's one of those topics where no one has been too much of a troll, or said anything unreasonable; basically, a logical conversation that I wouldn't have minded with the TV off, over a beer.  For that, we can thank Stack Exchange.

Comment: I certainly feel the title is much more out of place than the logo. Shall I marry my dog? I love them. Shall I marry my child? I love them also. The whole "Love is love" argument is extremely flimsy. Love can also be incestual, pedofilic or bestialitic

Comment: **Too much noise**, for an icon temporary change... It's only been a nice demostration of approvement. And it lasted a week-end only. And it wasn't invasive. And the SO owners are free to do whatever they want, after all. So, as I said, too much noise.

Comment: I only wish I hadn't completely missed the new logo even though I am on the site several times a day, every day! Now let me add that to me it's inconsequential...a couple of days, it's not a Nazi Swastika, it's not a hammer and sickle or a confederate flag (Topical huh?) and the site is privately owned, but helps me regularly...

Comment: @OurManInBananas does the site help you, or is it the people that answer the questions (the community) that helps you?

Comment: @DerGolem it lasted longer than just the weekend, but let me understand your comment. You think what happened is insignificant and what irritates you is how people reacted to what happened? You want to have a say in how people spend their time and how they should think? Interesting. I can't speak for everyone but I have no problem with someone demonstrating their support on their Twitter feed, at their house, on the news; but here there was one logo change (only on SO) on a site that is about programming. It would make sense if the site was social-studies.stackexchange.com, but it's not.

Comment: @vol7ron I was just **happy** of the logo change, since I'm in favour (I don't know in which language to say it, really). Since **it harmed nobody** (not even the suicidal lemmings!), `why do you complain`?

Comment: @DerGolem how we feel about something is totally separate from what's  appropriate.  There are people that it affects and there are people that don't approve.  These types of social conflicts happen often in the U.S., which is why it's important to not take a side, but to deter that kind of behavior.  But I acknowledge the fact that you are happy, so you see no wrong in it.  Let me ask, if there are new owners tomorrow and the ruling is reversed; if they put up a rainbow flag with an X through it, what would your stance be then?  No one is ***harmed*** in either case - it's a logo.

Comment: `if they put up a rainbow flag with an X through it, what would your stance be then? No one is harmed in either case` I think that gay people would feel **offended**. Isn't it somehow **harming** them? Keep in mind that they are **more sensible** than us.

Answer (score 84):

I'd say the "risks" everybody is debating here are terribly exaggerated. I don't really see any signs of this site or the network as a whole being transformed into a bastion of political activism.

Nor is the transformation of the logo really political activism, is it? It is not a political issue. It's a celebration of an event that happened. A celebration of another part of our population receiving basic human rights. Nothing is taken away from anyone. Nobody is being harmed. Just a significant segment of our population has been granted additional happiness.

And this wasn't a call to action. If this would have been posted months before and we were actively encouraged to contact our political representatives of choice, then we would have a problem. No matter how much I'd be in favour, that's something the site should stay away from. But that's not what happened here, is it? It's a celebration of a done deal. And if such celebration would result in the occasional transformation of our logo, I could accept that. Want to celebrate the anniversaries of basic human rights with a Google Doodle-like logo, go ahead. Birthdays of the computer science greats such as Ada Lovelace? Fine with me. But even that I don't really see happening.

Now for all the "Nazi airplane" or "Ray Rice wife beating" examples that are dragged into the discussion in the comments, I can't even begin to imagine why any of those would be a good illustration in the light of current events. They are all examples of people being oppressed, being harmed, or you being associated with those who segregate, opress and harm. And that's their flaw. The tiny rainbow logo does none of that. It's inclusive, not exclusive. And if you fear that somehow, somewhere, someone thinks less of you because all of this, I'd argue the problem is there, and not here. But perhaps that's just me getting political.

Anyway, long story short, do I think SO/SE should be used as a political platform? Absolutely not. Do I think we're in for a bumpy political ride from here on out? I see no evidence of that. But if I'm proven wrong, we can still all pack our bags and leave.

Comment: Nail head. Thank you for this; you're being less incindary than I was going to be.

Comment: Most of the ardent nay-sayers seem to regard SO as "their" site and thus they are empowered to have a veto. Strange as it sounds, SO is still a privately owned company - even though it may seem totally community driven (indeed, where would it be without its vast user base). The particular (*temporary! temporary!*) change that prompted this question is more of a personal statement from the SO founders, and they are totally entitled to take actions that some, a large part, or even a majority of users are opposed to.

Comment: BUT WHAT IF THERE WAS A SWASTIKA?

Comment: Seriously though, well put and a great differentiation between "call to action" and "symbol of celebration". That was exactly my feeling when dismissing the whole thing as "putting up a flag" in the comments above (to the dismay of the OP), but I didn't think to put it this way.

Comment: The day there is a swastika, I'm getting over to Meta as fast as I can to find out who done effed up in what kind of a hilarious way, only to tease them relentlessly to a point where a contest is held for the best drawing related to the event so we can all get swag @Pekka웃.

Comment: @Bart but [it's already started!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169746/my-gravatar-is-a-swastika-generate-new-gravatar) ...  plus, where is my original 2009 question on the same topic? It's all coming together!

Comment: [Here it is.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32007/swastikas-in-fractal-images)

Comment: You are from what country @Pekka웃 ... hmmm ....

Comment: VAT IS ZAT SUPPOSED TO MEAN

Comment: I don't agree with your answer, because the event of granting some rights to some people by the **state** is **by definition political**. And it's clear for everyone that rainbow logo is associated with LGBT movement, which is a political movement supported by [left-wing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socialism_and_LGBT_rights).

Comment: That process and the debates before it have certainly politicized the issue. And any debated topic can easily be politicized. But still, that is not what happened here on this site. Certainly not in light of the personal statement made by one of the founders of this site. Furthermore, pushing the LGBT movement firmly into the left-wing camp is doing them, as well as their supporters on the right, a disservice. There are plenty of clear examples of support on the right as well. It is not as if being gay or wishing your people well, firmly aligns with a specific political spectrum.

Comment: @Bart I repeat - when state is involved into something it's by definition a political issue. And in this case we are talking about recognizing gay and lesbian marriages by the state. Celebrating it is also an act of political activism just like celebrating Labour Day, Independence Day, Victory Day or European Union Acces (in some countries) is.

Comment: Then I'd say we're at a point where we'll have to agree to disagree @doc. Or disagree to agree. Or any of those.

Comment: @doc, @ Bart, Whether it's related to politics or not is a red herring. Because regardless of whether the issue is political or not, it remains a **non-tech** social issue. The question is whether stackoverflow should be cheering for **non-tech** social issues or not.

Comment: I think the "Ray Rice beating wife" is a bad illustration. There are [better illustrations](http://goo.gl/6k6ALM). For example, is SE (Joel) for limiting [Export of cryptography from the United States](https://goo.gl/PoVUUT) because it protects national security, enhances SIGINT, and [helps us "fight crime and terrorism"](https://epic.org/crypto/legislation/freeh_797.html)? Or is SE (Joel) against it because it intrudes upon [the first amendment and our freedom](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/96/Munitions_T-shirt_%28front%29.jpg)?

Comment: Why do you keep reposting that @Pacerier? This is the 3rd version now?

Comment: @Pacerier right, but the question also asks `Is it a good idea for Stack Overflow to become politically active?`.

Comment: @Bart, Apologies, errors can only be edited for 5 minutes. So I'd have to delete and re-post to edit.

Comment: Ah, I didn't see any difference. No problem. :)

Comment: But that's the thing - Stack Overflow isn't "becoming politically active" by this. And I think most of us very well know this.

Comment: @Pekka웃, @ doc, Politics can mean different thing in different context and does not necessary have to do with state politics. Indeed it seems like the OP's [definition](http://google.com/search?q=define%20politics) of "political" has the same meaning as "social". It's the "politics" in "[office politics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Workplace_politics)" and "[human politics](http://goo.gl/63zUJY)". Of course, OP might have meant to refer only to the strict intersection of state-political issues, social issues, and socio-political issues, but the context of his message shows otherwise.

Comment: Yesyesyes.  I was going to answer this, but this answer pretty much nailed it.

Comment: @Pacerier I think the context here is that SE is celebrating state politics on gay and lesbian marriages. Maybe I get it all wrong, but so long you haven't convince me about SE being innocently social.

Comment: Yes, Ray Rice was a bad example for several reasons. I was trying to think of something you don't agree with, but that a lot of people do - I failed. At a time, slavery was common and had majority support. You're saying there is no issue today that you disagree with, that the logo should change to? So now that gun permits are now recognized in all states, should we put a gun in the logo? It's another controversial topic, but we're celebrating, so it's okay. What does it have to do with programming!? Nothing. But change it to a gun anyhow.

Comment: Also, there is some confusion or misrepresentation happening. No one - at least not me - said its a call to action or political activism, but it is sociopolitically-related and it is recognition/celebration of both a social and political cause.  The point "It's okay because I see no wrong" is so selfish. If this is ever reversed in the future, do we celebrate that?  Call it "Freedom of State's Choice Day"?  It's celebration and not hurting anyone, but what the hell does it have to do with programming (that's not a stretch).  If SO goes public, do we have a problem with the Board changes it to?

Comment: The precedent this sets is what you should consider.  A Board of Directors comes in and says, "we're going KKK".  Many users disagree, but they can leave if they want.  Even though that's the case, we all have vested interest in the site, even if we are not owners. We have learned from and contributed content to each other. We have been contacted by companies with job offers, or offered some ourselves. We have benefitted from it, but also paid with time and knowledge and participation.  That should mean something even if we aren't owners.  What we choose to celebrate matters.

Comment: We're getting into a lot of hypothetical overboard ifs here. And surely you don't think the support of an organisation which would pretty much explicitly exclude a significant portion of our users from using the site is a good illustration of the point you're trying to make. Especially not in the light of what actually happened. As for a precedent or risk, the whole point of my answer is that there really isn't much of one. You're drawing this fairly simple celebration out to lengths it doesn't deserve.

Comment: @vol7ron: Let's say the SCOTUS overturned [Roe v. Wade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roe_v_wade) at some point; that's in the same ballpark as far as scope and in the opposite direction on the political spectrum. I personally wouldn't be happy about that decision; if SE celebrated it by changing the logo for the weekend, I wouldn't like it, but what would I do? I'd probably roll my eyes, vote on some of the inevitable Meta answers, maybe use SO a little less that weekend, and then come back _because the logo, and the operator's politics, are **irrelevant** to the site's usefulness_.

Comment: @Bart I use extremes to demonstrate a point. Extremes do happen, but what's more shocking is when you discover people that support those extremes and this isn't a far-fetched extreme; nor is it too much hypothetical. It's taking the actions of today and discussing which direction things are going based on where we were *yesterday* and introspectively asking, is that a good direction to go?  Examples and hypotheticals are only used to support an argument/case, not be the argument.

Comment: @JoshCaswell you described how people are reacting now. Do you think the owners/creators/maintainers don't care what we have to say? Do you think they should? If this happened more frequently would you use SO even less? If there was an alternative site that offered what SO offers, would you consider using that instead? Would the creators care that people are thinking about that now, even if that site might be in development and not offered publicly yet? For me, I like the users, I like the community as-is and don't think these disruptions are necessary.

Comment: Some people [are reacting](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/298004/) a bit [more strongly](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/297879/1) than that, @vol7ron. Not everyone, granted. And yes, I would have it in the back of my mind that SE had done that, but it's a long way down the slope from changing the logo. As for the users' opinions, they've definitely been put forward and voted on in multiple Meta posts over the past few days. I haven't tallied up the votes, but the positive score on Joel's response to the initial post probably outwieghs all the other posts combined at this point.

Comment: @JoshCaswell I hadn't voted.  I don't think the people's got very much mattered in this case, but since it's being used as justification, I want to address it. I would ascertain the overwhelming majority of users didn't vote. I think a small fraction of users even know what meta is and those that do (even high participants/contributors) use it. We also have to keep in mind that any time Joel does anything people blindly upvote it. If you look at some of the other answers saying not to, they also received lots of popular upvotes.

Comment: I really couldn't care less about the logo change, but _the **legalization** of gay marriage isn't political_? That's like saying the abolition of slavery wasn't political. How "political" something is has nothing to do with it's inclusiveness or how much you like it. It's determined by its controversy and the state (or other governing power/authority/etc) being involved in making laws/rules about it.

Answer (score 39):

Personally, I feel that this discussion and 'issue' is a symptom of a different underlying problem: basically we all spend most of our time going along with the pretence that the SE sites are run 'by the people, for the people'. Of *course* we know (those of us on meta) that that's not true, but it's not pleasant to have that suspension of belief shaken when we realise that some things can happen just because the 'owner' Joel* pushes for them.

I think this is visible in the answers and comment threads here: initially defenders of the logo change invoke 'logical' reasons, but then when pushed, fall back on "it's a private site, they can do what they want".

I tried to broach this subject [before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76333/site-autonomy-and-governance-community-driven-democracy-or-benevolent-dictators), but I'm not sure I got my point across.

Ambiguities about governance always end up creating problems.

(<sup>*</sup> The [Jobs banner](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109160/dennis-ritchie-goes-into-the-night-without-a-quote-on-stack-overflow) was also Joel's personal initiative)

Answer (score 38):

> but don't feel that Stack Overflow is the best forum for it.

You're 100% correct, it's not. This wasn't a call to action, it wasn't taking a stance (because it's now the new rule of law) and it wasn't the outcome of dense suits holding an emergency meeting where everyone was worried what would happen if they didn't 'rainbow up'.

I wish I had numbers on just *how* many developers can now have better health insurance through their partner; I don't, because many gay developers *still* feel a great deal of trepidation about disclosing a same-sex partner for fear of losing their job, or any shot they had at advancing in it. But there's hope, and we celebrated that by changing a nominal amount of pixels on your screen for a few days.

There *really isn't* anything else to read into it. Please don't [multiply entities beyond necessity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam's_razor).

Comment: Not sure I'm ever going to select an answer to this question. Really, it was asked with an answer in mind, but I wanted it to serve as an avenue for discussion that might lead into other questions that could result in action items. That said, I haven't read all answers yet, but I think this is reasonable and mostly correlates with my line of thinking.

Comment: `dense suits holding an emergency meeting` being a European, this sounds familiar...

Comment: This monkey speaks a lot of sense.

Comment: Hi, I'm the devil's advocate. My client is not very happy about the recent events - in fact, he's so traumatized that he spends the days in bed muttering "the children... please think of the children". So I persuaded him to do something fun to cheer him up, like designing a new exoteric programming language. Unfortunately when the poor chap opened StackOverflow he saw that logo and burst in tears, and he's been locked in his room since. My client, who is a staunch advocate of traditional Christian values, feels excluded in here. And, even if I may not share his values, I think he has a point.

Comment: _"because it's now the new rule of law"_ In one country.

Comment: inb4 in SE's country #dontcare

Answer (score 28):

The owners and operators of Stack Exchange and Stack Overflow have made it amply clear that while we as users and contributors are not permitted to use the site and our audience here to promote our political and social beliefs, they, as the owners may.

See the accepted answer here:
[Can Stack Overflow and Meta's logos be changed temporarily to the "#LoveOverflows" logo?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297859/can-stack-overflow-and-metas-logos-be-changed-temporarily-to-the-loveoverflow?cb=1)

It is clearly now policy that they as owners of Stack Exchange can and will use the goodwill and site traffic generated by our contributions to promote any political or social cause they see fit.

If you do not care for this policy, you should no longer contribute to Stack Exchange.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267368/are-political-avatars-and-profiles-ok but if you want hate speech, that's another thing

Comment: I just wanted to add that while there is censorship, it seems the creators/admins do permit us to discuss our beliefs through our comments (and profile), which has enabled us to have this very discussion - though they were closing it early on. So we might be able to promote our beliefs to a degree, but don't have full control in modifying the site as a whole to do so and don't have the necessary tools to disassociate ourselves from the parts we disagree with.

Comment: You have always been "permitted to use the site and our audience here to promote our political and social beliefs" through your profile and your avatar: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267368/are-political-avatars-and-profiles-ok as long as you do not use those items to directly attack others. As I state in my answer there, moderators have taken a hands-off approach to this as long as specific groups or individuals are not being attacked.

Comment: @BradLarson - the logo of the site itself is different. It's not expression of an individual, but of the site, which represents its members.  And if the managers of this site view it as a political and social platform, it can lay no claim to be a site of authority and "record" on the subject matter, because one must always take into consideration that there may be other motives besides accuracy and professionalism driving the direction of the site, its mods, etc, since it ultimately exists for "ulterior motives."

Comment: @vol7ron `don't have the necessary tools to disassociate ourselves from the parts we disagree with` Sure you do, you could describe such a disassociation in your profile text. [At least one user](http://stackoverflow.com/users/103167/ben-voigt) has chosen this route.

Comment: @DavidRobinson I meant screenshots and posting photos, or even full control of the display of the profile page (like what you could do with MySpace). I said "disagree with", but this applies to more than disagreement. We can certainly use words, but it's limited.

Comment: @Ben, What a brave answer! Not many betas dare to go against the alphas on this site, let alone a non-beta. You should give yourself a pat on the back.

Answer (score 27):

Entirely inappropriate IMO, and **disappointing:**

- It's inappropriate as explained in the question: It's a political
  statement, regarding events that are not at all related to
  programming. **Inappropriate**.
- It's disappointing because generally this is a site that holds its
  members to very high standards of professionalism in their behavior
  and claims to be a "site of record" regarding its subject matter. So
  it's extraordinarily hypocritical for the managers of the site
  itself to conduct themselves differently than what they require from
  its participants. If I posted something here about the Supreme Court decision, regardless of my own feelings about it, it would be flagged.

Is there nothing immune from politicization today? No rest for the weary? 
   **Disappointing**.

Comment: The length of this thread and the fact this (reasonable) answer is being down voted proves that this kind of thing doesn't go over well. The logo should not have been changed. I need SO too much to think about canceling my account, but I will be removing my careers profile. Will it matter? Of course not. But I, like Joel, want to make a small statement.

Comment: excellent answer.

Answer (score 16):

To add to the great answers from [Bart](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/488657/bart) and [Robusto](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/298047/187606) -

People are acting as if expressing a stance on a social issue were a binary thing - that you're either "socially/politically active", or "neutral" (the state in which Stack Overflow supposedly was until now, although that is [arguable](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114005/how-does-sopa-threaten-stack-overflow-stack-exchange)).

Robusto's answer is [much closer to the truth:](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/298047/187606)

> It's equivalent to wearing a pink ribbon or a red poppy on a lapel. It doesn't even rise to the level of a bumper sticker or T-shirt.

being "politically active" is a sliding scale, and what happened to the SO logo is at the very, very beginning of that scale. It is light-years away from "promoting a specific social policy".

Plus there are *very* personal connections to the issue among the employees, incuding the CEO.

The point of this is that like you're expected to tolerate a pink ribbon on a colleague's shirt at work, it's reasonable to expect your tolerance for the changed logo for a couple of days no matter what your views are on the issues behind it.

There is no reason to assume that there is some secret ideological ploy to, now that precedent has been set, slowly move further and further up that scale, as some users have expressed fearing (sometimes conjuring up very dystopian imagery).

I promise that if SO starts soliciting funds for a super-leftist LGBT rights organization, or the Tea Party, or calling for one or the other presidential candidate to be elected with huge banners, I'll be writing outraged Meta posts along with you.

But any of that's rather unlikely to happen in the first place. And I think most of us, if we're honest to ourselves, know this.

Comment: But just calling for Hillary to be elected is far on the scale from putting the gun to the head to vote for the Hilary. At least be consistent and allow SE to take any political actions they like (even tho it's arrogant toward some users).

Comment: @doc they've been very restrained in that respect even in the [SOPA](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114005/how-does-sopa-threaten-stack-overflow-stack-exchange) context.

Comment: How come the meta logo wasn't changed? If Spolsky really wanted to celebrate he should not have done a half-assed job in celebrating. No; this was purely about recognition - "I like this and so should you".  Only this has had a detrimental affect on some people. "We can't do business with you, we saw you associate with SO" because your profile score was on your resume. Again, I'm happy for him and others it's affected, but how we feel about it is second fiddle to its effect.

Comment: Things have gotten very serious - the first part about that comment was supposed to be a joke :)

Comment: @vol7ron "No; this was purely about recognition" - Well, yes. Purely about recognizing that a thing that's important to many developers and to a number of us internally happened. ;) You don't have to like it. Nobody has to like it. We did a "quick and dirty" change by updating the sprite file that Stack Overflow uses because Stack Overflow is what most developers care about. This wasn't about promoting an agenda, which is why meta, other sites, and other services (like chat) didn't change along with SO.

Comment: Even though I read Spolsky's statement, it's wrong of me to say what the purpose really was; I can only infer. Those working behind the scenes that were there to discuss and enact the policy actually know. I'm guessing Anna was one of those people.

Comment: But what about if Stack Overflow starts soliciting funds for the LGBT wing of the Tea Party? Will an outraged Meta post be sufficient? `:-O`

Answer (score 13):

Your question seems to hinge on the definition of what "politically active" might mean.

To me, changing the stack in the tray of the logo from monochromatic to prismatic is, if it can be construed as activism at all, probably the mildest form of the practice I can imagine. It's equivalent to wearing a pink ribbon or a red poppy on a lapel. It doesn't even rise to the level of a bumper sticker or T-shirt.

And forgive me, but I simply don't see the harm in such a modest celebration of a victory for human rights. If you think a few multi-colored pixels have altered some cosmic balance between the forces of good and evil, well, I congratulate you on your imagination.

The SO folks are people. Don't expect them to behave like robotic non-observers just because they run a series of web sites that deal largely with technology subjects. In my view, they ought to get to be happy and to show it.

Comment: Good point regarding "politically active" definition. Originally, I wasn't suggesting this was a political statement, instead I was thinking about the direction this site is going based on the actions it has taken. However, the more I think about it, this is definitely politically motivated, even if it's in celebration. It says, "we recognize the judgement and are in full support of it and other causes like it." It's an alignment of interests, social and political.  But the question I was after is more, what should the site behave like in the future?

Comment: "It's equivalent to wearing a pink ribbon or a red poppy on a lapel" - Incorrect analogy: What's on your lapel is related to your person and simply represents your own personal view. The logo of a public website on which thousands of posters participate is a banner for the whole site and is a representation of the stance of a public facility and to some extent its participants - similar to the idea of public accommodations in federal law.

Answer (score 12):

I thought that site owners, moderators and community expect from me not to talk about my religious, social or other not related to programming beliefs/convictions.
I would be grateful if they also stick to this.

Comment: Except you are wrong there http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267368/are-political-avatars-and-profiles-ok

Comment: I have a temptation to create an avatar with "support gender quotas in marriages" message, but still I think it would be inappropriate. I'd rather talk about programming instead of trolling.

Answer (score 9):

**Site wide recognition of current events shouldn't extend to highly controversial issues.**

This issue is much more controversial and likely to cause an argument than holidays or other civil rights causes.  Due to its controversial nature, Stack Overflow should not even hint at supporting one side or the other, especially considering the highly praised neutrality of the site.  For example, Google often posts doodles for holidays and other important events.  However, the only recognition the Supreme Court's decision received was directed to people who specifically searched terms such as "gay marriage."

This issue is very personal to me and I would prefer to not be distracted by it when I am simply trying to learn more about software.

Comment: `the only recognition the Supreme Court's decision received was directed to people who specifically searched terms such as "gay marriage."` Actually, below the search bar it said `Android is marching for Pride. Join the celebration!`, with the second sentence a link. Just saying. I had to look to Wikipedia for an example of doing nothing (other than having an article).

Comment: @Nateowami, [Cookies](http://samy.pl/evercookie/) and [Geolocation](https://www.ccsl.carleton.ca/~jamuir/papers/TR-06-05.pdf). To verify if so or if not so, use Tor within a new VM and access `https://google.com/ncr`

Answer (score 6):

I think it's definitely out of place. "Marry whoever you love"... unless it's two other people, or a relative.

From a semantics standpoint, it's making the implicit assumption that marriage is a 1-on-1 relationship and that there are no restrictions on blood ties.
Both assumptions are arbitrary, unless one elaborates further on what exactly marriage *is* and why the government should have any stake in it.

Different people will answer in different ways, which is why the issue is very subjective. Either way, I feel it has no place here.

Comment: Someone had their feathers ruffled? These inconsistencies I have pointed out seem quite objective to me - why they would not be arbitrary?

Comment: What has this got to do with the question at hand? You targeted the specific event, not the general case, which is what this question is about.

Comment: Yes - and these inconsistencies are all the more reason why this should not be publicly highlighted on this website.
I do understand where you are coming from, however - my post was not directly about the meta of publicizing social issues on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Excellent point.