# Feature requests and bugs need more feedback from Stack Overflow developers

Tags: discussion

The developers at Stack Overflow are doing a great job.  [There is a steady stream of changes to the site.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange)

However, there are a [great number of feature-request and bug posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=[bug]%20or%20[feature-request]%20-[status-*]%20is%3aquestion%20closed%3ano%20hasaccepted%3ano%20score%3a20) that get no official word from the developers.  There are many that are well received, or are asked for *over and over* again, but there's no consistent response or updates from the team.  Yes, some of those posts are not well received, but that's the *community*, not the *developers*, response.  One way or another, these posts should be getting a relevant `[status-*]` tag to show that they've been acknowledged by the team.  At the moment though, official answers and use of the status tags is sporadic at best.

Meanwhile, the team has put out two featured posts about entire new *sites*.  This is not a judgment of those features, but there is no doubt that they will require a *significant* development effort.  When I see those posts but no response to requests about the *existing* products (especially SO and Chat), I get a little discouraged, as it appears that more effort is going towards entirely new areas rather than improving the core in a significant way.

Development is just not transparent enough.  Even the list of recent features I linked at the top is *"unofficial"*.  It's been indicated by the team that these posts show up in an internal issue tracker, but that's not visible to us.  **Getting more official, regular feedback on feature requests and bugs would be greatly appreciated.**  I think it would also make for a healthier environment for users to make such posts, as they would see that they could get some sort of official word rather than just (dis)approval and discussion from the community.

Comment: Meta Meta somewhat similar: [Can we have a guaranteed pipeline for responses from Stack Exchange?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263662/can-we-have-a-guaranteed-pipeline-for-responses-from-stack-exchange)

Comment: I've pointed out an error recently and development fixed it within some 48-72 hours. I think it's important to differentiate between bug fixes for the hell of it, and bug fixes that improve the stack exchange sites making it more successful as a business.The latter will always take priority over the former. As someone who opened a site up to suggestions, I recently plenty of crazy (well supported) ideas which were simply unrealistic or impractical or are so minor they don't affect day-to-day usage much

Comment: @user3791372: There are dedicated status-* tags for "interesting, but not right now" and "haha no way". If a request gets a lot of community support, it seems unreasonable to dismiss it out of hand without officially saying "yeah, that's fine, but not a high priority" and ideally giving some sort of reason why.

Comment: @NathanTuggy What's important to you / another user may not be important to the Stack Exchange company. No explainations needs to be given unless you're a shareholder.

Comment: @user3791372: This is true, but only trivially so. That's basically just restating "we aren't contractually obligated to be open if we don't feel like it". Well, OK, fine! That's not to say it can't be a competitive advantage to put deliberate effort into ensuring openness. SE is perfectly entitled to be as opaque as they wish. We are perfectly entitled to ask them to be more open, and to vocally and publicly express our dissatisfaction with reasonable shortcomings in that regard as often as we like.

Comment: Well Stack Exchange is the network, not the company. The company is now Stack Overflow (again). And well you know, "*Stack Overflow is you*". Which means that Stack Overflow does value all of our opinions collectively as much as any shareholders'. So what is important to us (collectively not necessarily individually) *is* important to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Within a business environment, democracy never works. There has to be someone to say "no, that's a stupid idea" and prevent company resources from being wasted. Whether that's said in private or public is up to the company. However, most keyboard warriors here probably wouldn't like being told that in public and it would be harmful to the community. Unless you're giving money to Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange what exactly do you expect?

Comment: Them to say "NO!"... minimally. @user3791372

Comment: @TinyGiant not being responded to is a "No" and it's as pretty darn minimal as you can get!

Comment: @user3791372 Yeah, and a lot of the time we don't even get that, that is what we're asking for here.

Comment: @TinyGiant - You're asking to "not be responded to"? Noted.

Comment: @user3791372: So then why is there a status-declined tag? No one is saying "all these ideas we think are great must surely be implemented." No one is even saying "all the ideas anyone posts must be responded to in person with 5 paragraphs."

Comment: @user3791372 No obviously we are asking for **some sort of response from the Stack Exchange developers on any of the numerous feature requests and bugs that have not yet had their existence acknowledged by the Stack Exchange developers**

Comment: @NathanTuggy Just file it alongside "Why do men have nipples"?

Comment: So, in short, "Dear development, answer me in future or I'll write another question on meta asking why you haven't answered." And hats off to @rene above

Comment: @user3791372 Seriously you have a problem with us wanting some kind of acknowledgement that they have even been viewed by a Stack Exchange employee? *Something* to signal that it isn't being completely ignored?

Comment: @TinyGiant I don't. I have a problem with people expecting work done for free and whining when they don't get it done. Just because this is a disposable culture where lots of things can be received / fetched for free, doesn't mean developer time is free. Stack overflow is going in its own direction, not the direction you want it to go. Priorities have to be given to tasks

Comment: @rene: Filtering only by `score:20` reduces that to [59](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=[bug]+closed%3Ano+answers%3A0+-[status-*]+score%3A20) and [126](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=[feature-request]+closed%3Ano+answers%3A0+-[status-*]++score%3A20) respectively. That's a lot more achievable, and, again, no one is asking for *all* posts to be answered officially, only ones with some highish score.

Comment: No one here is whining about work not being done, in fact if you read the question it is very specifically being very gracious of all of the work done. We are specifically *not* asking for all of these feature requests to be implemented or bugs fixed. We simply want some acknowledgement from Stack Overflow employees that they have seen the posts that are well received by the community. @user3791372

Comment: @rene thanks for the stats, I was having trouble figuring that out. I agree it would take time. However, most issue trackers don't just leave things open, they either close, or address, each one, even if it's just to say no. I'd find it ok if they just did this going forward, ignoring the backlog unless there's a new development.

Comment: I wonder how many people complaining would be willing to fund a part-time short-term developer of maybe $30k to go through the bug and feature requests for them?

Comment: @user3791372 if the team feels that that's the only way this would happen, then an official post explaing that would be a good start. You might even be surprised how many people would be willing to chip in to help. However, I think you've misinterpreted what's being asked and are becoming hyperbolic about that tangent.

Comment: @user3791372 If Stack Overflow didn't want us to report bugs and submit feature requests there wouldn't be those specific tags.

Comment: @user3791372: That sounds a little like ["we accept pull requests"](http://jeffhandley.com/archive/2013/02/25/The-We-accept-pull-requests-Addiction.aspx)... except worse, because it's "we accept people digging through our lists of stuff to maybe do". Let's not go there.

Comment: @user3791372 Stack Overflow has raked in [north of $40 million](http://blogs.wsj.com/venturecapital/2015/01/20/stack-exchange-raises-40-million-to-answer-developers-questions/) in VC funding. There *should* be a budget for a part-time short-term developer in there somewhere if that's what's keeping this from happening.

Comment: @Pekka feel free to ask for your money back? In the long-term, that money will be a very well spent investment which I would think would make any VC the money back and a healthy return.

Comment: @user3791372 not sure what you mean. My point is this can hardly be an issue of resources.

Comment: Money given to grow the SE sites in either a manner the investor has a say in or with complete trust given to the SE owners. My point is, just because someone else has given money to the SE team doesn't mean others can start dictating how it's spent. If you paid money to the team and they're not spending as you agreed, then ask for your money back. If you didn't give any money, and you don't like it, then put up with it, or leave?

Comment: @Pekka웃 make no mistake, this **is** an issue of resources but the money is not the problem, fitting extra developers in a team, making them productive without disturbing current velocity is the problem ....

Comment: **Attention!** I saw this discussion.

Comment: @Shog9 I am expecting an essay on it on my desk by 10am tomorrow morning.

Comment: @Shog9 Just for measurements sake, approximately how long did it take you to read this question and write that?

Comment: How much we love it that someone with a diamond is pingable in the comment thread....

Comment: I donno, @tiny; an hour something? I'm on vacation and a bit distracted today.

Comment: I see a pattern, on the best discussions you are always on vacation...

Comment: @Pekka웃 Three rolls of parchment or four?

Comment: @Shog9 well, you got my attention. :-)  But did you just see it, or did you and the team reach some sort of official decision on it?  The later is what I'm asking for more of.

Comment: I saw it, I read it, as I see and read dozens of other meta posts each day @davidism. When I have something to say, I comment - but I'm not yet convinced that an "I saw this" indicator would add much in those cases where I don't really have much other input.

Comment: Not sure whether this is better than the "good old days", where we had Jeff, who was almost religious about responding to feature requests and bug reports, but would summarily decline them regardless.

Comment: @Shog9 Just to be clear, an "I saw this" indicator is exactly what I'm *not* asking for.  I'd like a consistent experience for users making feature requests and bug reports.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit personally, I really liked seeing his responses.  It showed that someone on the team devoted time to it, even to deny it.  Better to see a reason that you may not agree with and can respond to than be met with silence.

Comment: In my experience, you get out what you put in, @davidism. The first and most important response is from the community; if no one using the sites cares about your bug or feature, then why should we - after all, we work for them. If others like your feature or are also suffering from the problems caused by your bug, then we will get to it eventually.

Comment: @Shog9 not saying you need to care about every poorly thought out post.  For the ones that have been well received by the community, while it's obvious that the team will have seen it too, it would still be nice to know if it's `planned`, `declined`, etc., or even have a post with some reasoning, without having to guess or trawl through and  interpret long comment threads.  As I say in the last sentence in my post, I feel that an official response is important, it's part of the "you get out what you put in" cycle.

Comment: "Yeah, we agree this should get done.  We're thinking [xyz], but we'll have to put it on the backburner", or "it's a nice idea, but we don't think it's necessary because [abc]" don't seem like unreasonable responses.  I'd expect something like that on any other issue tracker.  I definitely wouldn't expect a well made report to sit unaddressed if the project is still active.

Comment: @user3791372 - "Work done for free"? Who does work for free here? When we write an answer to a question, we usually do work for free. When we spend time trying to reproduce a bug in the site, reporting a bug, writing a request for improvement, we usually do work for free ...for the site.

Comment: @user3791372 - "Priorities have to be given to tasks" Tell that to the team managing the sites here. Often, priorities **are not given** to tasks. That's why Davidism wrote this message here.

Comment: @Shog9 Has this been discussed internally? Anything you can share with us?

Comment: See Thomas's answer below, @Stijn (he was dev PM when that answer was posted). That said, I have to admit this is a sisyphean task; I've probably written more answers to feature-requests than any other employee, and those answers are still a drop in the bucket compared to the volume of feature-requests being posted. There are a couple dozen of us addressing these on various sites now, but the chances of *keeping up* are somewhere between slim and none.

Comment: see also  [How are feature requests processed and discussed with the SE development and product design staff?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326608/839601)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is an incomplete and probably somewhat un-satisfactory answer, but there are a few points I'd like to make, being one of the people here going through [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)'s from the community!

(Note: I'm **not** the only one)

Here's my process:

I'm subscribed to [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) at the SE network level, and I go through every single post in that daily email (it's not that much, usually ~10) every day. So, if you tag something [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request), it's actually being read (note that I joined last June, so if your request is older than that, I might not have read it).

As I do this, I re-tag things that aren't actually feature requests (bugs, discussions), and add [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) to things that aren't well-defined or are simply unrealistic.

Now, looking at feature requests a day after they're posted isn't perfect, since I get to them before there's a measurable community response.

So, every couple of weeks, I go through recent highly-upvoted feature requests (usually anything that has a score greater than > 40). There's also a large backlog I'm trying to go through.

I acknowledge that I don't usually answer, comment on, or even tag all of them (or even a sizable portion of them). I'm sincerely sorry about that; I'll try to do better.

---

As far as [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)'s go, we do have one developer going full time through them (rotating every two weeks).

Comment: I have close voted 24 bugs last night that were either no-repro, solved or a duplicate. I'll go over all those bugs the next few days to clean-up and close when appropriate.

Comment: It's often easy to remember the bad examples and overlook the good.  Thanks for all the work you're already doing!

Comment: @rene - If you cannot repro a bug, that does not mean that the bug is fixed. You are not the only person in the world.

Comment: @NicolasBarbulesco sure, I'm happy to re-open if I missed reports that prove that the bug still exists. Drop me link in the SOCVR chatroom if I made a mistake.

Comment: It was mentioned on the new [Teams](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/308601) post that SO is aware of this and is shifting developers around to devote more time to Q&A dev.  If you want to edit that in here, I would accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 17):

Shog9 has wisely said that ["The single best way to drive someone away is to ignore them, to give them no response whatsoever."](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271863/misuse-of-off-topic-closure-reason#comment96622_271863) [Further reading from that comment](http://cs.stanford.edu/people/jure/pubs/disqus-icwsm14.pdf).

See also the last half of [this graph of user disengagement rates from a while back](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/216700/274165):
[image]

Syllogism:

- Many well-received requests are visibly ignored
- Visibly ignoring a post is the best way to get that poster to go away, (possibly) short of banning them
- SE policy is that it's impractical to do anything other than visibly ignore many requests
- Therefore…

Comment: Just like mum used to say about bullies. "Ignore them and they'll go away".

Comment: @user3791372: And teeth. Pretty sure it works for girlfriends/boyfriends and jobs, too.

Comment: We should really think about letting folks besides employees reply to these posts, I guess. Y'all tend to have better ideas anyway.

Comment: I appreciate that people are trying to rhyme about why a large company with - as stated earlier - millions of dollars of investments should now behave in a totally different way and do something else at its expense because a small handful of people without millions of dollars say so. But really, the gamification is designed to draw you in - for free. If you do go away simply because you're ignored you'll be walking away from all your lovely "badges" (can __you__ do that?) and, lots more people will arrive in your place. Personally, I don't see the fuss. Also, BULLET POINTS!

Comment: @user3791372: This answer is about the users posting *well-received suggestions*, not random questioners or answerers. That's several orders of magnitude smaller and a far more valuable population, individually.

Comment: @user3791372 you seem to have a personal bone to pick with badges, reputation, and meta discussion that is unrelated to this discussion. I suggest you make a post of your own dealing with these thoughts if you want real discussion. Please do not continue shoehorning it into these posts.

Comment: The second graph is weird. "Came back" on the left? It looks wrong.

Comment: @NicolasBarbulesco: It's not ideal, but essentially, the horizontal axis is measuring likelihood of returning relative to the mean.

Comment: @Nathan - So the title is in the wrong order, no?

Answer (score 15):

I have to agree with this, if somewhat grudgingly.

A few years ago we had Jeff, who would almost always weigh in to a discussion on a bug report or feature request. Inevitably, of course, he'd then slap the [status-goaway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/status-goaway) on it and that would be that.

Now there's no Jeff, and the queue of feature requests and bug reports is a little longer. That's fine. Even if I were to suggest that devs spend more time going through that than on bold enterprises like:

- [duplicating all open source documentation through crowdsourcing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/306213/560648)
- [creating opportunities that actively discriminate against those with the "wrong" gender](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269992/560648)
- [starting a TV channel so that budding developers can learn in the least effective way possible](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/270574/560648)
- [hiring roving gangs of developers to add blood to the SO multiplayer mode](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/307513/560648)

(which I'm not, particularly) it would be a different question entirely.

For the here and now, I think the issue is one of engagement. Nobody's asking for "okay, I've read this" on every post — Shog, you're right in that this would be utterly pointless and irritatingly noisy.

But on my company Bugzilla, when someone posts a new bug against products I own, even when it's a meaty one that I'm not going to be fixing right away, or a feature request that requires further discussion and thought, I *always* post my initial thoughts on it as soon as possible. This may just be a sentence like "we're unlikely to end up doing this because *X*", or "personally I think this is a fairly good idea", or "yeah, this doesn't sound like expected behaviour to me either".

You don't have to go into massive detail or commit to anything, but acknowledging the post begins a cycle of feedback that helps the quality assurance team to feel like they're not just talking to a brick wall. And, on Stack Exchange, we're your quality assurance team.

*(Disclaimer: This does already happen, of course, in a bunch of cases. And frankly I'm not particularly bothered by any of this. I think overall the devs do pretty well on meta. But the above is my cold and calculating analysis of the question at hand…)*

Comment: Some*what* begrudgingly?

Comment: @Cupcake: Whoops ;p

Answer (score 12):

There are [489](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbug%5D+closed%3Ano+answers%3A0+-%5Bstatus-*%5D+) bugs on MSO without a status and answer and [652](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbug%5D+closed%3Ano+answers%3A0+-%5Bstatus-*%5D+) Feature requests without a status/answer. Let's assume a bug takes 15 minutes to judge and a FR 30 minutes. That is a lot of minutes to spend ONLY to give feedback as: [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) (or leave a non-robotized *we have seen this* comment)

And mind you that is only MSO. I didn't do the same math for the other 130 site meta's.

A dev team doesn't scale well. We have enough users around to write the bug reports and feature requests quicker than any team can fix them. And as with any sort of product we use, we have wishes and hopes for tools that better suit our dire needs. On top of that some of us are smart enough to provide the fix or envision a relative easy solution.

And that team is also dog-fooding. They love this site as much as you do, so they see the quality of posts, they see the moderation efforts, they feel the passion users participate on meta. That team must have a very thick skin given the high-demand to not be overwhelmed by all these requests.

I'm very reluctant to ask for more feedback as I expect the team is dedicated to their job. Introducing a feedback loop takes away time. Feedback loops doesn't lead to more productivity. In fact I often see a negative effect on team morale. I don't want to be the one responsible for causing that effect.

Nevertheless I would love to see the internal total bug list and the fix-rate. I like to be impressed by the people that made this site to what it is today.

Does that mean we now all wait for an official response on this question? That is probably how it goes. We spend with 5 users a total of 60 minutes debating the deafening silence from the team. One user deemed it necessary to write an lenghty answer. Instead I could have cleaned the tags: [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) and [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) of posts that no longer make sense.....

Comment: Any particular reason you didn't run the numbers for some arbitrarily-chosen minimum score threshold?

Comment: @NathanTuggy it doesn't change much in my of line of reasoning. Whatever number you find, multiply by 130...

Comment: Keep in mind that MSO has probably about as much traffic as MSE plus the next ten site metas, *combined*. The actual total is probably somewhere around 4-10 times as many posts, very roughly.

Comment: @NathanTuggy: ... but is nowhere as old, as MSE got most posts from before the split. Which (somewhat) reduces that effect.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Fair enough. In other words, it might actually be substantially less than ten times, seemingly.

Comment: I don't want to be precise on the numbers, the exact numbers are not important.

Comment: It wouldn't be necessary for devs to mark requests as declined or planned. "We've seen it" would be enough in many cases, and the fact that this doesn't happen can be extremely discouraging

Comment: @Pekka웃 they do see them, all bugs go to the internal tracker. I personally would be very sad if a dev comes by to routinely leave a [meta-tag:status-seenit] on my bug reports but I can imagine other users might value that kind of feedback.

Comment: [Why are there so many feature-request with no official response?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40434/why-are-there-so-many-feature-request-with-no-official-response) with an answer by user1.

Comment: I've seen this exactly before. If you don't like how it's run, then leave. Maybe people will start listening then if everyone started leaving. However, as the "bugs" and feature requests you hark on about seem to be liveable without them being replied to, you will quickly be replaced and forgotten. There are bugs, and "bugs". I'm sure bugs are fixed, quickly.

Comment: But the team never said they don't listen .... they don't see a viable way yet to get a feedback loop in place that adds value to both the team and the OP's.

Comment: @rene `But the team never said they don't listen` ... that seems a bit like "she never said she doesn't want to see me, she just didn't find a way to respond to my texts." :)

Comment: @user that is understood, anyway. Still nothing wrong with occasionally complaining. If you don't like to see that, then leave.

Comment: If all people want is a "seen it" update, then let's set up a bot to post a seen it message after x minutes / hours and just don't tell anyone about it. Happiness all around.

Comment: I have already ruled out that option in my answer...

Comment: @user Looking at your contributions to the site, it looks like you are the least invested person here. I can see how it would be easy for you to not g̶i̶v̶e̶ ̶a̶ ̶c̶r̶a̶p̶ care about the outcome. But the truth is that without all of the contributions from all of the users, there wouldn't be a Stack Overflow. So yes, we are invested in Stack Overflow (while not monetarily) even if *you* are not.

Comment: @user You're quantifying "investment" solely as monetary investment. I'm quantifying *everything else* that we contribute to Stack Overflow as investment. How is that an oxymoron.

Comment: *"I personally would be very sad if a dev comes by to routinely leave a status-seenit"* since they all go to the internal tracker, that can probably be automated, but that's really no different than it is now. If it has the tag `bug`, devs have `seenit`. :)

Comment: Feature requests on the other hand... The majority of the ones i see are complete garbage, and/or repeats of things that have been suggested and rejected many times over. All the dev would be doing is re-iterating what the meta community already says. Why do we need someone *official* to back it up?

Comment: @KevinB but those FR's should be close voted and deleted/Roomba-ed then...

Comment: @KevinB That's why we have asked for posts over a certain score (like 20) to get a response. (not specifically on this question but in the past) Of course we don't need a dev to respond to every single garbage feature request, but we hate seeing feature request gather a large number of upvotes, then sit ignored for years.

Comment: One of my bug reports was made almost half a year ago, still awaiting response. It's about the mobile website, something that used to work and is now broken. I realise I'm overreacting, but I just can't get rid of the thought "they don't care about Windows Phone as a platform to make an app, and now they don't even care about their mobile website".

Comment: @Stijn I'm not trying to make you happy but I [feel](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221614/loading-next-item-from-the-close-vote-queue-takes-longer-and-longer) [your](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244335/loading-next-item-from-the-close-vote-queue-ends-in-an-error) [pain](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/261424/158100)

Comment: So, basically, the developers don't give a f*ck? Well, everybody knew that already...

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel not sure where you get that impression from.

Comment: @rene Well, the whole answer has an athmosfere surrounding the "developers don't care" thing. And their atempts to solve issues have been nearly null. So, yeah, there's where I took it from.

Comment: Definitely not my message @IsmaelMiguel. They push new versions almost daily and those include bug fixes. I tried to explain that the dev-teams are time-constrained. They favor pushing new version out instead of keeping the administration up-to-date and I can live with that decision. I personally think *the developers don't care* is  not true for this team.

Comment: @rene I agree with your statement, but they almost never fix bugs

Comment: @rene It is. Finally a year-long bug is (possibly) fixed. I hope.