# The Goal of Teams: Our Follow-Up to Your Questions

Tags: discussion, old-teams

A few weeks ago, we came to meta with [an idea called Teams](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307513/the-power-of-teams-a-proposed-expansion-of-stack-overflow?cb=1).

For those who didn’t read the first post (we can’t blame you: it was a *long* read!), the idea behind Teams is to **give users of Stack Overflow a way to showcase their team projects and achievements on a shared page** and check out what other teams are building.

We also shared longer term ideas for Teams, including Q&A, job openings, and — yes — following (more on that below).

First, we’d like to **thank everyone who took the time to add answers and comments, or sign up for the private beta. Your feedback is valuable and we appreciate it.** There were a number of questions and concerns, and we’d like to address those here.

### What problem(s) are we trying to solve?

Teams started from an observation that one of the most common use cases for the *About Me* section of the user profile on Stack Overflow is to showcase your projects and achievements, which breaks down when...

- … A majority of your programming work is done as a Team. Individual user profiles have trouble reflecting this (after all, your profile is about *you*). With Teams, we’d like to make it easier for you to show your association with others on the projects you work on.
- … Your programming work isn’t mono-dimensional. You probably have a day job, but you may also contribute to one or two open-source projects, or be a member of a handful of user groups or communities. With Teams, we’d like to give you an easier way to represent your role in all these different things in a more structured way (rather than flattening all this information in your individual profile).

In their initial iteration, a Team will simply be a page on Stack Overflow where a group of developers can tell the community about who they are and showcase their best work. Just like a user profile, but for multiple people (i.e. a free form about section, links to your website, GitHub, Twitter, and a team roster).

Teams are *not* a new site. They’re much more modest:

[image: The initial Teams page will be place for you share about your team, what you build, and your team members.]

### Who are Teams for?

We envision Teams to be used for professional teams, open-source projects, user groups, or even programming communities endemic to Stack Overflow working towards a common goal (e.g. organizing question lists, analyzing Stack Overflow data, writing bots, etc.).

So far, it’s encouraging to see that a wide range of teams that have signed up for the private beta. We’ve had companies (some large, some small), major open-source projects, single-person OSS projects (e.g. [YouCast](http://youcast.i3arnon.com/)), user groups (e.g. Git, Docker), and even Stack Overflow communities (e.g. sopython).

Of course, you might be wondering, "but why would *my* Team ever want to showcase its work on Stack Overflow?" In the original meta post, we heard:

- My team already has a company or project website.
- I’m just not interested.

In any case, that’s fine: Teams are functionally and socially optional, and you won’t need to be a member of a Team to participate on Stack Overflow (you don’t have to check out anyone else’s Team, either).

### What about authenticating teams?

Regarding **authenticity**, it’s already a hypothetical problem on Stack Overflow (e.g. you can easily pretend to be Guido Van Rossum if you want to), but it hasn’t been a practical problem.

We realize that just like user profiles, Teams as a feature must be resilient to misinformation and trolling. In the short term, we might surface user reputation on Team pages as a solution to communicate trustworthiness. In the longer term, we’d like to explore other ways to establish trustworthiness for Teams (maybe including "verified" Teams), but it’s too early to talk about those in detail.

### What about teams disparaging *other* Teams / offensive content / spam?

The same argument applies here as well. Users can already disparage others and post offensive content on their user profile,  but this hasn’t been a major problem on Stack Overflow so far.

For the most egregious cases (i.e. offensive content), Teams will have to support some form of flagging and moderation. We still have some work to do here (and we need to ensure we don’t create more work for our moderators), so we’re not quite ready to discuss the details.

As far as the private beta is concerned, we’ll take on moderation ourselves. Moderation tools will however be an integral part of our work as we move towards public beta.

### What about conflicts *within* teams?

Dealing with conflict is inherently a personal thing, and it’s difficult to anticipate how we’ll deal with conflicts we haven’t seen yet (and maybe they won’t even be a problem — one can always hope!).

Either way, we understand that this is probably a problem we’ll have to deal with sooner or later. We *think* it’s reasonable to go into private beta without a more detailed strategy (as noted above, we’ll take on moderation ourselves for now), but we’ll make sure to return to meta and discuss this before we launch into public beta.

### Can you be a member of multiple teams?

Yes.

### Is this for Stack Overflow only?

For the time being, yes. We’ll consider expanding Teams to other Stack Exchange communities based on how successful it is on Stack Overflow.

### Is Stack Overflow becoming a social network?

No. One fear that was raised in the comments was that Teams introduces a way for users to form around non-programming interests on Stack Overflow. While these interests may apply to a wide range of developers (gaming, books, movies, etc.), that is not our intention with Teams.

Our intention is that Teams will form around programming-related groups (companies, open-source projects, or programming communities endemic to Stack Overflow). We don’t want to encourage groups which form around non-programming related topics (that’s what the broader Stack Exchange network is for!). If this becomes an issue, then we will address it.

Okay. Now as far as "following" goes, **this is a mistake on our part**; we jumped the gun here. Originally we thought of “following” as a feature we *might* introduce later on if we added Team job openings. That is, if you’re interested in a Team, then you could be notified when they post new jobs.

At some point we started thinking that "following" could be expanded to possibly other team content. To be honest, we didn’t really think it all the way through; **thanks for bringing it up in the meta responses**.

Following won’t exist until we have job openings on Team pages (more on that below). Once we do, following (which is probably not the best name for this feature) will only be used to be notified of new openings. We don’t have further plans around following at this time.

### How is Team Q&A going to work?

Judging from the feedback we received on Team Q&A, we realize we have a lot more thinking to do (e.g. a better idea of what content is acceptable and why, a plan to ensure Teams aren’t used for spam, a strategy to address abandoned Teams).

Team Q&A wasn’t going to be a part of the beta (we hoped to ship it in Q1 next year), so we have time to revisit and perhaps rethink it (maybe with an emphasis around product and end-user support). In hindsight, we probably should have made that clearer in the initial announcement.

Team Q&A may be complex enough to deserve its own beta. We’ll return to meta when we have thought through some of the issues surrounding it. **Once again, thank you for highlighting the issues we need to explore further.**

### Is this an attempt to integrate the Careers product with Stack Overflow?

It’s not our *only* goal (we think Teams can be useful for groups that aren’t going to use our Careers products, such as OSS projects), but it is indeed one of them. Here’s why:

If you’ve been around Stack Overflow for a while (even a short one), you probably noticed a few folks you admire. If they took the time to fill out their profile, you might also know what they work on, and you might even want to work with them if the opportunity arises.

On the flipside, *they* might be looking to hire someone like you (they might even be hiring *on Stack Overflow’s Careers platform*). But, you don’t know that, because developer hiring is broken, and relegates to an afterthought some of the things that matter the most in a development job: who you’ll work with, and on what projects.

Teams is thus our attempt to cut to the chase and let you start your job search with a team and its projects (which is a bit similar to how you might become interested in a job at a conference or meetup, after watching someone present their work).

In that regard, Teams are something we’re building *upon the foundation* of Stack Overflow Q&A. They don’t *change* Q&A. Teams are something new that you can decide to be a part of if you’d like, but we won’t expect you to be a member of a Team in order to participate fully in the Stack Overflow Q&A you love.

Nonetheless, we do realize that many of you are concerned that pain points in Q&A aren’t getting solved because our engineering resources are diverted towards projects like Teams. We agree, and it’s why we’re transitioning members from the Careers team to the Core team to help work on those new projects ([Roberta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/411343/rla4?tab=profile) was our first developer to transition, I did so too).

---

That’s all we have for now. I’m sure there will be more questions and comments. As we move into this private beta phase, we’ll learn more and have more answers for you. **Once again, thank you to everyone who’s provided feedback so far.** We appreciate the passion you have for Stack Overflow and its community.

### You can still sign up for the private beta.

The private beta will start soon (end of October). If you would like to help us test this, please sign up at the form link below. We will need to know the following things about you:

1. Your Stack Overflow profile URL
2. Your email address
3. Your team name
4. Your team size (team size especially helps us because we will want to see how teams of varying sizes will utilize the team page).

### [Sign up for the private beta](http://goo.gl/forms/nosBAAcbvG)

Comment: This makes the new feature seems better suited for the community now.  Gotta love the built-in feedback engine that is meta.

Comment: -1 I still don't see any value added with this social feature.  Aside from you guys putting a careers type feature into stackoverflow and burdening it.

Comment: This looks like it has some real potential, unfortunately I don't see myself using it at all. I'm just not getting how this helps me. I'd say this looks like a solution in search of a problem, but I'm guessing that it's just me (as usual) and that based on the feedback you received others find this something they'd use often.

Comment: @j08691 - It's not just a problem for you, its for a LOT of folks on SO.  Just look at the other post.  I personally find this a feature that disrupts SO in general.

Comment: You can easily name yourself Guido van Rossum, but unless you're Martijn Peters I don't think you're going to convince anyone. =)

Comment: @JonH: Part of the goal of teams is that it not disrupt the workflow of people not interested in team pages. I think we will learn a lot in the private beta about how to achieve that goal. The biggest unknown that I see is that team pages might impact moderators (who are already overworked). We just won't know how that will play out until we get some actual teams using the feature.

Comment: "We get some actual teams using the feature" but what is that "Actual Teams" I don't know about you but I highly doubt anyone is going to get all of their co-workers to join a team or branch into teams just because of their likes?  I mean to me this is social networking - and for a site like this it's asinine.  I mean you guys have posted twice about this and none of it is convincing.  Is this like GitHub where developers become "Contributors".  You guys keep saying the key word "think" this tells me and others that you guys don't even know what this is.

Comment: @j08691 We (I work on this with Hynes) understand that Teams aren't going to be immediately useful to *everyone* on SO (that's a tall order!). We hope to start building some structure around Team pages (which can be compelling as-is to some users, but not necessarily to a *majority*), and progressively add new features to make them compelling to more people (e.g. maybe by addressing the support use case Shog mentioned in his response on the last post with Q&A, etc.). Exactly what those should be is undetermined as of yet (that's what the beta's for, among other things).

Comment: What did Jeff have to say about this proposal?

Comment: @JonH: I haven't even used the feature yet. As you can see, the scope has been scaled _way back_ which means there are fewer things we don't know by default. It's the nature of building a new thing that we can't know how it's going to be used until we try. (That said, we can make a bunch of educated guesses and design the feature to be less open to undesirable behavior. I don't think we have a concept of "likes" for instance.)

Comment: @ThomasOrozco - Why don't you guys spend the time fixing all the current issues with SE in general instead of making up some random features that your users are telling you you don't need. For instance, search is one prime example, why not build on that...search is pivotal in any application - especially one like this.  The current search engine and search UI in general lacks.  Stop building features and start improving the user experience and core important things related to questions such as search.  If you can make search solid people won't even bother searching google.

Comment: So the main problem this feature solves is that it makes you able to showcase your team accomplishments. And then you tout that as *not* being socially motivated? I don't think showcasing personal achievements is a problem that Stack Overflow needs to solve, nor that developers in general have a problem with on a daily basis.

Comment: @TravisJ - No one will use it...mark my words...the people that will use it will either be employees of the company or teams that no one will be interested and they'll fade away because programmers don't really care about this sort of stuff.  Careers is the right place for this not stackoverflow.

Comment: @JonH That's a fair point. As we mentioned in the post we're working on getting more developers to work on the Q&A stuff so that there doesn't have to be a decision between Teams (docs, etc.) and Q&A improvements. This is slower than we'd want, and the frustration there is understandable.

Comment: @JonH To your point regarding no one using Teams: it's not worthwhile for us to work on things no one is using, so if that turns out to be the case, we won't blindly push forward.

Comment: @ThomasOrozco - If it's a fair point pull up your sleeves and send an email to joel and tell him you guys have work to do on the search.  Forget about teams and docs fix what sucks in general.  What sucks right now is search and when users are interested in a site like this about questions and answers and search doesn't work then BOOM. The questioners who post new questions are then greeted with "Closed as a duplicate" and down voted to God knows where is a telling tale that search doesn't work.

Comment: @ThomasOrozco - So you'd rather spend time building on a beta than fixing search?  That is how I see your responses.

Comment: @TravisJ A lot of Stack Overflow users already use their profile this way. I'd argue that does not mean Stack Overflow is a social network (in the same way that e.g. Twitter might be), but I understand you have a different perspective. Do you mean to say that Teams might be actively harmful to Stack Overflow, or just not that useful?

Comment: @ThomasOrozco - I have no crystal ball so I cannot say if it would be actively harmful, Stack Overflow is resilient and that would be a rather large claim to make. However, I do think that it would perhaps detract from the focus or perhaps draw users into just being job shop workers for obscure teams. I don't think it would be that useful. I could be wrong. I don't think it will help a majority of users, or even more than a third. The main issue I have with Teams is that it takes time from the Stack Overflow team that could have been spent better in my opinion.

Comment: @JonH just use `site:stackoverflow.com search term` on google when searching... that works _way_ better for me than in site search.

Comment: @TravisJ I understand; thanks for taking the time to answer! The best I can say right now regarding resources is that we realize it's a problem, and we're trying to address it by moving developers and designers over from Careers to work on "Core" (i.e. Stack Overflow)... and hiring (surely this will be easier once we have a Team page! ;D — too soon?). Regarding Team pages being perhaps harmful: we'll probably have more posts about them during the beta (to announce changes, etc.), if you see things going sideways... ping us there and let us know (we *really need* to know).

Comment: You took the original response to heart and came up with a much more reasonable feature in both scope and presentation.  I'm part of sopython, and while I'm still hesitant about this, I think at this point participating in the beta will be the most productive way to determine if it will be beneficial.

Comment: Thanks @davidism, the best / most useful feedback is the feedback that comes from those that aren't convinced. Keep it coming, you know where to find me / us!

Comment: Saying "you can already do this on your profile" is not really an argument. A conclusion: **Spending time, brain power, and good will building Teams will improve SO.** does NOT follow from, "People post information about themselves in their profiles."  Today I can easily ignore who the poster is and focus on the content. The fact that I can already envision the recommendations, and the "Hey come see my team page!" sidebars should be an indication that these are not equivalent.  We can't even get a post that fails to adhere removed on Careers, maybe because everyone is busy pushing this?

Comment: Hey @JoshuaDrake, I'm not sure what you mean by recommendations and "Hey come see my team page!" sidebars? Would you mind expanding a little bit? I understand you're concerned about we *might* to with Teams (which makes sense; in the long term it may be a big change), but I'd like to make sure I grasp the specifics.

Comment: Folks, these things will exist, and they will be easy to discover, but nobody is going to be pushing "come join our team" down your throat, nor will we be pushing careers on anyone that has no interest there - beyond the job ads that you normally see, and have seen for quite a while. This stuff is there for you if you want or need it, it will _not_ be getting in your way otherwise. I think we have a pretty good record that speaks for itself when it comes to not forcing anything on anyone that doesn't want it, starting in the very early days with reduced ads. Let's not imagine the worst?

Comment: I was one of the (somewhat) vocal critics on the original post, and I would like to say, that while some of my concerns still stand, I'd really like to thank the team for not blindly ignoring the community on this. I was (and I'm sure many others) concerned that the company would ignore the (frankly, quite large) backlash against the original posting, and that it would spell the beginning of the end of the great record of dialogue between the company and the community. I don't that that's the case anymore, so hooray!

Comment: @TimPost: I can't speak for the others who opposed the initial proposal, but  this post I think at least address the other half of the resistance to the proposal -- not its problems, but it being representative of a shift from the core vision and all of the problems that would come from that. I think that was the "worst" that most people where imagining, and it's been addressed now.

Comment: @TimPost Since we have you here...where in the world is my SO mug I was promised months ago?  We're now past the 6-8 weeks...

Comment: @Linuxios This is great to hear, and it's encouraging for us to see that we correctly identified and understood at least *some of the feedback* that was provided last time! : )

Comment: @JonH We _just_ finished collecting responses from that after chasing down folks that didn't reply, and we had the annual product summit fall right in the middle of that (which I failed to account / plan for). The final list is going out to our warehouse tomorrow. _Some_ stuff was shipped, the rest of it is going out Monday / Tuesday of next week.

Comment: @ThomasOrozco: It just feels like were back to *dialogue*, rather than the other post, which felt like a battle. I'm still skeptical, and I do think that Travis [got it right](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308601/the-goal-of-teams-our-follow-up-to-your-questions?noredirect=1#comment261870_308601): "So the main problem this feature solves is that it makes you able to showcase your team accomplishments. And then you tout that as not being socially motivated?", however, I'm not really worried about SO as a whole anymore.

Comment: @TimPost - You're a gentleman and a scholar - I dont care what your boss says about you ;-).  Thanks!

Comment: @JonH I would ask "which boss", but you'd probably reply "yes" which would only heighten my paranoia. I'm therefore going to thank you for your patience, and find a foil remnant that might make a good hat.

Comment: @TimPost - LOL :-)

Comment: @Linuxios That's a fair point; thanks for taking the time to expand. I think this *might* come down to disagreement over words (i.e. we don't think the same thing when we say "social"), but if you don't mind I'll make the same request of you that I made of Travis earlier: we'll be monitoring the posts about Teams. If you see something going sideways, tell us, and tell us early (comment, or my email's in my profile). When we're heads down in a project, it's easy to lose track of things that matter (example: the "following" kerfuffle). External input helps us stay on track.

Comment: @ThomasOrozco: Happy to. Quick question -- do I need to join the beta just to watch (without joining a team)?

Comment: @ThomasOrozco: Also, just so you have it, I can at least give the one other reason I think it struck me (and others) wrong: for a long time a mantra on SO (and SE in general) was "Vote on the content, not on the user", or more generally, "It's about the content, not the user". This feature felt like a complete reversal of that mantra.

Comment: @Linuxios No, you don't need to join the beta to watch. Actually, the only thing beta access will gate is **creating** a Team (you'll even be able to join one without having access). We're doing it this way to ensure we don't get overwhelmed in moderation (as mentioned in the post, we'll be taking that one ourselves during the beta period until we understand how moderation *should* work).

Comment: @ThomasOrozco: Perfect. And my "monitoring **posts**", I assume you mean meta posts in the [teams] tag?

Comment: @Linuxios Shog9 hammered that point home (that on SO/SE you should vote on the content not the poeple). We want Team pages to be something you go to when you want to learn more about the person behind the content, but we don't want Teams to be where you go to find content. It's a fine line, but you can be reassured that we have some great people here keeping an eye out for it. As to monitoring posts: yes I mean posts in the [meta-tag:teams] tag, though to be honest a comment on a post we own will notify us.

Comment: @ThomasOrozco: And with Team Q/A now much diminished in the proposal (thankfully), at least this is firmly on the "person" side of the line, like the About Me, rather than strangely straddling that line and threatening to actually harm SO by draining and fragmenting questions, and by creating hard-to-moderate havens for bad questions.

Comment: @ThomasOrozco - Anyone can join (by structure to be determined) a team. However, there seems to be no limits on what can happen once joined. If someone is trying to get a feel for the culture, perhaps they shouldn't be editing the main page, blogging through the team page, etc. What I am trying to get at here is, perhaps the Team shouldn't be a round table. Have you considered adding in a small tier of authorization/roles/access to differentiate between a team owner/founder, some sort of established part of the team, and new members who may just be looking around or "pledging" so to speak?

Comment: @ThomasOrozco:  I will say, however, that while Teams doesn't sound that bad to me anymore, I am still ***completely*** against Team Q&A, unless totally revamped *away* from product support. I'm on the fence about the idle curiosity technical questions, but not product support.

Comment: Wouldn't this undermine revenue from Stack Overflow’s Careers?

Comment: @TravisJ Yes, initially everyone will have the same permissions (that's how it'll be when the private beta ships), but permissions (or maybe tiers of memberships as you're suggesting!) are indeed one of the first things we plan to work on after private beta ships. We're not 100% sure of what it'll look like yet, though!

Comment: @Linuxios duly noted; thanks!

Comment: @PeterMortensen As noted in the post, one of the goals in the long term is to complement Careers with things like Teams that allow for a hiring experience that works better for developers (i.e. starting with the people, not the HR-authored job ad). We're not there yet, though (we have a lot of thinking left to do), so it's hard to share a lot more detail!

Comment: @ThomasOrozco Just go look at linkedin, facebook, or any one of another million websites. No one wants to be experts-exchange. Even The New York Times is starting to look like the side bar should read "1 surprising trick to remove belly fat", etc.

Comment: I do not see how any team gets this feature right when they hand wave fundamental concerns.  Sprinkling community on it does not solve the problem, if it did SO would never started in the first place.  Technology is fundamental.  I am even more concerned that, twice now, the value has not been communicated clearly. I do admit that I can see some value in having the ability to ask product specific questions that are no longer welcome on SO, but that assumes that the "right" teams participate and that fact points to the lack of general usefulness.

Comment: "Teams started from an observation [...] which breaks down when [...]" Out of curiosity, who has been reporting problems with profile flatness? Recruiters on SO Careers? I'm just wondering whether there's actually a business motive for this before you decided to do it, or if you decided to do it hoping it would mesh well with the business operations.

Comment: @TylerH No, to my knowledge (disclaimer: I joined *after* this idea was formed), there was no pressure from e.g. recruiters on SO Careers to build something like Team Pages. Hynes might have something to add here, since he was one of the original people behind the idea.

Comment: @ThomasOrozco Ok, thanks

Comment: Honestly, I can't see the point. That's not to say there isn't one, just I can't understand why I'd want or need to  join a team as described. Unless it's team "Don't use regex to parse XML" or similar.

Comment: I honestly have never seen such a project with so much uncertainty.  There is so much uncertainty and ambiguity in this entire proposal.

Comment: @JonH Please don't make this argument about *the people* working on it. I understand that you think there is too much uncertainty (and I respect your opinion), but let's keep it civil. Thanks!

Comment: @JonH - we don't have **project** managers, as such at Stack Overflow. Never had 'em, never needed them. A project can be spearheaded by anyone - we have pretty smart people here, regardless of what their title is, and they can all manage a project pretty well.

Comment: @Oded maybe that's the problem?  Could the fact that not having a pm who leads a project contribute to all the "bug" and "feature-requests" on meta.  I know myself when I used careers found tons of issues.  I made several posts about them, some of which have never been resolved.  You can check my meta-stackexchange posts with tags on careers.  My point is as annoying as it might be, it may be a good idea to have core people manage these sites.  This avoids the number of issues and bugs that show up on the sites that are quickly patched.  If there was someone who had the role of "Team"...

Comment: (cont...) functionality manage that part of the project there might be a clearer direction.  The 2 posts concerning teams always seems to say "..we dont know how it will work..." and that is pretty concerning.

Comment: @JonH *Product* managers are involved at various stages as well, but they're not the only ones allowed to come up with, be passionate about, or spearhead ideas around here. You're clearly not comfortable with the way we work where we don't figure out every detail upfront. That's fair enough. But, Thomas is right - this is not the place to debate *who* is working on any given project or feature.

Comment: @AnnaLear - Your right my appologies - I get what you mean there is passion in it.  I only mentioned PM to maybe be the goto contact to avoid issues like the one you guys are facing - not knowing exactly what this product does.

Comment: @ThomasOrozco - Earlier you mentioned you could look at but not necessairly create a team (unless you join the beta).  Can you provide instructions on where this can be found within the current site?  Or is that not available and I misread something?

Comment: @JonH Not live yet. I or Hynes will post an update when the beta starts and that is live.

Comment: @ThomasOrozco - So joining the beta means you have the ability to "create" a team.  Not joining the beta means you can still look at parts of the team pages?  Ok thanks.

Comment: @ThomasOrozco I removed my comment - I'll humble myself and give this a try.  I mean you got the best programmers working on this stuff...its only fair to give it a try.  I'll also remove my -1.

Comment: I was worried that SO would digest itself for short-term gain in a misguided effort to create a social platform. That fear has been allayed somewhat. I'm still not convinced of the utility of this idea, but believe that SO is engaged in productive thought instead of trying to generate a panting fanboi webgasm over a pointless social feature. I still don't think anyone has *clearly* identified a *concrete* problem that this solves; this is a stab in the dark at *something* but you still don't know *what*. SO will not destroy itself any faster than it already is because of this. So good.

Comment: So it's basically like a tag with two levels of subscription? (being a member and being a subscriber) Only members can edit the wiki freely and tag things with the group tag.

Comment: On a meta level (we are on the meta site after all) this Team Thingy™ is going to get rehashed until people lose interest in responding. The good ol' *illusion of choice*...

Comment: Is this still happening.........................................?

Comment: A week or so ago I added a request to create a Team.  I have not heard any kind of reply.  Anyone know the amount of time I should expect to hear anything back?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The Un-shipping of Teams](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/330427/the-un-shipping-of-teams)

Answer (score 89):

### Call it *Projects*.

I read your post and got a much better idea what problem "Teams" should solve. However, all you are writing about is showcasing work and displaying (open source) projects. If this feature was named "Projects", some of the concerns raised in the comments would be better addressed.

- *Can you work on multiple projects?* instead of *Can you be a member of multiple teams?* (the answer is obvious and the same)
- *Is Stack Overflow becoming a social network?* No, we care about content more than people.

In case you want to show your affiliation with an organisation, you can still put that in your (careers) profile.

Comment: But in some definitions project is something that needs to be done within limited scope for a set amount of time. Teams is not that, it is scoped but not within a set amount of time, right?

Comment: @rene Hm, I didn't mean it in the management sense. I'd define a project primarily by its *goal*, not by a deadline.

Comment: Some teams would not have projects but just an ongoing goal. AKA the SOCVR Team. It would be kind of lame to have a Close Vote Project that never gets finished. Also Stack Overflow cares about content, but SO Careers and this feature suggestion are clearly focused on people.

Comment: @TylerH: I don't see why every project would need to get "finished".

Comment: Even if this isn't the perfect name, I think the possibility of rethinking the "branding" of the feature is worth considering - in the original post, a few unfortunate choices of words emphasised parts that are explicitly de-emphasised here. "Teams" do still sound very social to me, even now I know that's not what "Stack Overflow Teams" are intended to be.

Comment: @Bergi It's kind of an inherent goal of a project, which is a discrete unit of work. Do you not complete projects?

Comment: @TylerH: Complete is hard to define. First major release? First point release? Something that doesn't have releases? Major open-source library that is still having major features built?

Comment: @TylerH: I've got many open-ended projects. Of course they have milestones that are completed and so, but the project doesn't really end until the product is no more used anywhere and the last bit of my code is rotten.

Comment: @Bergi: Which is *exactly* when we want you to make a page for it. :-P

Comment: A problem "teams" solves for Q&A is large companies *finally* getting it right by sending us a single contact to work with as they shift support over to SO properly. That's happening on a pretty big scale, I'm not sure if "projects" fits the use case as well. Not really saying it's a bad idea, just kinda thinking out loud.

Comment: I don't think the issue here is with the name. It definitely conveys what it is doing, and the main problem with this feature that people address is what it is doing, not what it is named. Changing the name would not have a large impact, and for what it is worth, I like the name "Teams" for this proposal even if I am highly skeptical of the feature itself.

Comment: @TimPost if company support contacts is a main goal, add the word *"Support"* to Bergi's *"Projects"*

Comment: @TimPost huh?  Now we are all about one feature that was not even clearly spelled out in the original post?  Are the Tellericks and AWSs of the world really reaching out to the SO staff and saying: "We want you to take over our Q&A, please."  Given how terrible IBM's help for MQ Broker, now IBM Service Bus, and Clear Case/Quest are I would love to see it, but then why not just a branded version of SO, no **Team** necessary.

Comment: @JoshuaDrake: Because of how Facebook.SO went. Not saying I like this better, but...

Comment: @TimPost Wait, so you're saying Teams is an attempt at making an official interface for 3rd party libraries/APIs to do bug support here?

Comment: I find it funny that the objecters don't object to e.g. GNU being a "project". Do you expect it to finish? Soon? What exactly are the success criteria?  Etc.  The word has a broader meaning than in the strict line management lingo. (I'm not sure *Teams* isn't actually good enough, or possibly better -- like many others here, I don't really see the need for this feature, and don't care strongly what you choose to call it.)

Comment: A somewhat relevant example of "projects" which have no intention of being "completed", check out [Wikipedia's "WikiProjects"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:WikiProject). Note that they're also very content-focussed, so while people are members of the "team" working on the "project", it's their actions that are emphasised.

Comment: The sopython *team* has at least five bigger *projects*. Do you want us to create five minimal project pages now that contain little content when we actually want to highlight the persons that are part of the team?

Comment: Support of products is an _incidental_ goal, but also a nice one, It's just _one_ problem teams helps to solve, not the main goal, just a use case that eases a bit of pain. Please don't read more into it than that :)

Comment: @TimPost funny, because it was the ONLY problem I saw that Teams might solve...

Comment: @TimPost: Again, can you explain why support is something you *want* people migrating? I understand stuff like API support, but do you really want "Why did you ban me i hate your TOS?" support questions?

Comment: I have to agree with this. I think the fact that this is called Teams seem to carry an implicit secondary meaning that was fairly detrimental to this entire idea.

Comment: @Bergi, Calling it "projects" makes sense. After all, the way "Teams" is described above, it sounds *exactly* like a chip off [WikiProjects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:WikiProject), except with a programming focus.

Answer (score 26):

You still haven't answered what **problem** you are trying to solve, you've only addressed what Teams is meant to do. How will Teams benefit ***me***?

Let's take this point by point:

---

> ...the user profile on Stack Overflow is to showcase your projects and achievements, which breaks down when...

#### *How* does showcasing projects and achievements break down?

What do you mean "break down"? Obviously the content is visible and rendered correctly. So what do you mean by "break down"? What goal is unachievable, considering there's enormous flexibility to include links, images and a large amount of text?

And how does your solution solve this "break down"? It seems the only usable addition you've provided is the ability to query these relationships, because the "About" page for projects doesn't look that different from the "About" page for profiles.

---

> ...programming work is done as a Team. Individual user profiles have trouble reflecting this...

#### What *trouble*, exactly, is encountered in reflecting that I work on a team?

It's not difficult, at all, to add "I work at XYZ" with a link to the company or project website. The proposed Teams feature does not have anywhere near the power or flexibility necessary to showcase the actual product (with about, demo and documentation pages) or to manage a team (with communication channels, backlogs, sprints or Gantt charts), so what exactly is the point of the Teams page other than to group some user profiles together? And what problem does that solve?

---

> With Teams, we’d like to make it easier for you to show your association with others on the projects you work on.

#### What benefit is there to *me* to show my association with others? And this only works for other SO profiles, right?

Many of my co-workers don't have SO profiles. They aren't interested in SO profiles. So really I'll only be showcasing my association with other SO users. But why do I want to do that? What benefit is there for me? A company or project About page can easily list everyone involved on the project, with links to all of their social media profiles (Twitter, Facebook, Linked In, etc), so how would a separate, more limited and less representative "About" page on a different site help our team? It seems like any marginally successful project (in terms of usage) would quickly outgrow the very limited nature of Teams.

---

> ...we’d like to give you an easier way to represent your role in all these different things in a more structured way...

#### Why do I need a more structured representation of my various roles?

The use of "structured" points again to the seeming primary point of this project... to build a database. I don't see how such a database would provide any benefit to *me*.

---

> In their initial iteration, a Team will simply be a page on Stack Overflow where a group of developers can tell the community about who they are and showcase their best work. Just like a user profile, but for multiple people (i.e. a free form about section, links to your website, GitHub, Twitter, and a team roster).

#### Conclusion

At least on a service like Facebook there is some trade off, in that providing structured data about my social network gives me access to tools that I can use to enhance communication, etc, within that network.

Teams doesn't seem to provide any real benefit to its users while giving SE all the goodies... a big database of relationships between users. While I don't necessarily have a problem with that (I like and trust SE, so I'm willing to give you that information), you're going to have to give me more of reason to provide and update this data than just "so you can show off". And more importantly, you're going to have provide some serious incentive if you expect my co-workers who don't have SO accounts to create accounts and agree to keeping our project page updated. Because time we spend on this feature is time not spent on our product.

I guess I just don't see "*Individual user profiles have trouble reflecting programming work done as a Team*" as a problem in and of itself. Individual user profiles also have trouble facilitating conversations between users (though it could theoretically be done).

So the question I'd like answered is: **What problem are we addressing by creating a structured way of grouping Teams, beyond the problem that it's currently not possible to create a structured way of grouping teams.**

Otherwise you're just saying that we should do something because we can't currently do it, which could be said of a *lot* of things on SE. (Or, put another way... [*why*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/5_Whys)?)

Comment: _Many of my co-workers don't have SO profiles._ Perhaps the point is to convince them to _make_ SO profiles through your "join my team---for completeness" nagging.

Comment: @Michael - Yes, that's the point... SO needs to provide a value prop for Teams beyond just "here's *another* thing you need to maintain."

Comment: Thanks for pitching in, JDB! We do realize Teams aren't going to be immediately useful to *everyone* on the site. The beta sign ups we have so far suggest they'll be useful to *some* people, though. Now, if that's any reassurance, in the long run, you can be confident that if Teams turn out not to be useful to *anyone*, they won't be useful to us, either (and they won't be worth dedicating a lot of effort to).

Comment: @ThomasOrozco - I'd still like to know what the actual problem is. There will always be people who will sign up for betas, just because new === exciting. But it's going to have to solve an actual problem if it's going to be successful.

Comment: @JDB I think we disagree on what "problem" should mean. We explained in the original post what the problem we'd like to solve is, but you don't view it as one; that's entirely fine, and understandable (presumably, it's not a problem *for you*, or at least not one you feel is worth solving), but I'm afraid it means I can't really give you a better answer here. Please let me know if I'm misreading you.

Comment: @ThomasOrozco - See my edit at the bottom of my post.

Answer (score 24):

That was long, and it kinda had to be.  If you've ever played with Lego Bricks, you probably understand the understated importance of things that look like this:

[image: It's important]

Of interest are the parts that form intersections. And that's what we've got here, along with a lot of talk about what's going to be built there, how it's going to be easy to get to, but not get in your way as you go about getting what you came here to do done. It's new, it's kinda big and we're at the point where we have to tell you that *something* is coming as we start building it in plain sight. You know everything about it that we do, and we'll make sure that stays true.

Maybe it's a new stadium, or a library, or something that town planners have decided is essential in order to bring more people into the town. Whatever it might be, there will *always* seem like there are more important things we could be doing other than building *that thing*. What about the potholes a block away? What about all that graffiti on that other side of town?

#### We're not putting any of that off. But we can't put this off any longer, either.

Sometimes there is just *never* a good time to do something *and* fully respect everyone's expectations at the same time. Core Q&A is *never* going to become a second class citizen when it comes to the amount of attention and resources we're committed to putting into it. But we really need the foundation for this laid so that *a lot* of other problems **in *and* beyond** Q&A can be solved, so that *none* of our products function like bolted-on afterthoughts.

But there are lots, and lots of things in the air, and not all of them are mutually exclusive. Deciding not to do this right now would not magically give us everything we need to solve other problems, like refining search, beefing up the spam protection layer, or the two dozen other things I really want to work on right now - and I see what I feel are quite a few assuming that we're diverting. That's not the case, we'd be obligated to announce this even if everything else was perfect, please don't read so much into the timing. Things block for *many* other reasons than hands needed to do them.

#### You can't appreciate what you don't see

What we *positively must* do a better job of, and it's been quite clear for some time (and broadly my fault that I've lagged the last two weeks) is being more responsive to the plethora of requests that we're currently serving in addition to what we're talking about here.

There are ***three of us*** 100% dedicated to making sure Stack Overflow as a Q&A product continues to thrive and grow. They are:

- Myself
- Shog9
- Bluefeet

.. and more might be coming on this team. Our *primary* focus has been making sure long-standing and well-received community needs are met, and continue to be met timely. If you're not seeing that, it's *my* fault, and we'll do better.

We can't make super complicated problems magically simple enough to solve in a week, and before we fix problems, we need to figure out *how*. But (and this keeps repeating, which is something else I'm paying attention to) we can do a better job of letting you know what we know, even if we don't yet know very much. Some problems are just *that* hard at our scale.

Please don't read more into this than there is. It's new, it's big, and we wanted to tell you about it. We didn't wander off into the weeds chasing rainbow uni-squirrels, no matter how excited we seem. But we do have a lot going on, and while we promise to continue to be as transparent as we can possibly be, we humbly ask for your patience and support.

I'll be working on a series of posts here on MSO to shine some more light on what team SO has been up to lately, even if it's not as close to shipping as we'd like, because it's pretty clear to me that many would appreciate things like this more if they were more up to speed on the .. less glamorous endeavors that task us.

Comment: **You know everything about it that we do**, and that is why I am concerned.

Comment: "There are three of us 100% dedicated to making sure Stack Overflow as a Q&A product continues to thrive and grow." - On the community team, this is great. I do however have to ask how many devs are involved with this push, as I imagine creating mockups for Teams, Documentation, and working on Careers also involves quite a few developers.

Comment: @JoshuaDrake - nothing has been completely built, or rolled out. We have the same concerns, which is why we're talking about it here, now, so we can be more certain of not sucking :)

Comment: @hichris123 It varies. A significant effort is in all of those things, but we also have bandwidth to work on stuff that the community wants. Right now, we're working on making figuring out what happened to your flag much less confusing, overhauling the review history stuff so you can better see the longer-term effects you have on the site through review, overhauling the vote fraud scripts to be _much_ smarter and a bunch of other stuff. As I indicated, I need to be more vocal about it. Constrained? Yeah. Starved? no.

Comment: @hichris123 Also, as I indicated, there's _never_ a good time to be constrained for the short term. But this is something we _have_ to do, and getting this out of the way lets us look at bigger problems in a world where all of this is just another part of Stack Overflow. I can't emphasize how important that is going forward, for quite a few things we've yet to do.

Comment: All we want is to know *why* you can't wait any longer for this. You say it as if the need for it is self-evident. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @TimPost: It's just not very reassuring when the answer to every (and I mean *every*) concern voiced on the other post was "Well, we'll just find out, won't we!".

Comment: @Linuxios If it came across like that, it's our fault. What was meant was "We're glad we brought this up much sooner than later, even if we feel a bit foolish for giving the impression that we're not quite certain of some directions to take". It's a process of vetting as _much_ as getting feedback  that tells us "Don't go that way, that way might be bad.", and the only way to get that early on is to ask :)

Comment: The short answer, @Linuxios, is "because we've been doing too much talking and not enough doing." We've been talking for a long time here at Stack Overflow about providing devs a way to show off what they do outside of Q&A and a small text area on the profile, and we've talked for a long time about bringing Careers and Stack Overflow a bit closer together. (We haven't talked too much publicly about this in years past because we had no good concrete ideas for how to do that.) Team pages move us closer to both of those goals, both of which we think are good for the developer community. cont'd...

Comment: ...(cont'd) We want people to show off work they're proud of, be able to ask questions about other people's work, and to find jobs they love. We know from our annual user survey that many, many developers consider "what would I be working on" as one of the most important deciding factors when evaluating a new job. We also know that it's highly unlikely for recruiters to provide this information, and that devs like hearing from other devs. We've postponed actually building anything for a long time because we wanted to get it perfect. (cont'd..)

Comment: ...But you know how we get to perfect? By building an MVP, getting feedback from you all, and iterating until it's better than we could have ever thought to make it on our own.

Comment: @Laura: OK. Two questions: 1) What make you think that team pages will be "safe" from HR/Marketing? It can end up being a public face for a company, and as discussed at length on the old post, that raises some problems. 2) Given that this seems so focused on jobs, why isn't it just part of Careers?

Comment: @Linuxios 1) I don't think Team pages necessarily have to remain "safe" from HR/Marketing. Sometimes our customers on Careers are technical people who have to hire their own team. Sometimes non-technical recruiters *do* understand devs. Sometimes...the two might even work together on things! 2) It's not part of Careers because jobs are just *one piece* of what we envision team pages to be, but for people on SO who *are* looking for jobs, it's a way better experience to see jobs in a context where they might actually be tempted to apply than it is to shuffle them off to another site to search.

Comment: @Laura If you've been doing "too much talking" then maybe you should reconsider.  There has clearly been nothing to spur action.  It appears that you all are simply bored.  Some users are incredulous that you could be so given that issues they have raised persist on SO itself.

Comment: @TimPost how can it be something you "_have_ to do"?  It sounds a little too much like "We must destroy this village in order to save it!"

Comment: @Laura: Sure it might be slightly useful for the 1% of visitors that are actually looking for a job, but it degrades the experience for the 99% of visitors that don't and that came here for the Q&A. And even those 1% likely went to SO in search for Q&A and you are only distracting them. This distraction part is of course the intention, since you want more people to use careers, but it still makes the main site worse for the vast majority of users.

Comment: "There are three of us 100% dedicated to making sure Stack Overflow as a Q&A product continues to thrive and grow" -- you should make it clear that those are only the community managers. There are around 6 devs (me, m0sa, cky, Oded, Marc Gravell and one person on bug duty) whose primary job is improving Q&A and I don't see those numbers change anytime soon.

Comment: @sth How is it distracting for people who just come for Q&A? If people aren't interested in Teams, they don't have to navigate to any team pages. It's not like we're going to be putting pop-ups in people's faces saying "hold on, before we let you see that answer, go check out this team!"

Comment: @Laura: Obviously there will be some kind of teams integration, where people will have to find out what it's all about and how it works and if it's important. People need to familiarize themselves with all that. Teams won't be completely disconnected form the main Q&A site.

Comment: @Laura - You say you've been talking about it, yet the original posters of these posts always state "We dont know how it will work..." so than how much have you really thought of this?  And I don't believe that it will be so separated from Q&A.  You make it seem like this sort of integration will not interrupt our workflow whatsoever, that just doesn't happen with large systems like this.  When facebook came out with a timeline millions of users didn't want it.  Guess what everyone has a timeline now.  Please don't make it sound like teams will be so separate because you cant do that.

Comment: @Sklivvz: To there are 9 people working on Q&A? Out of how many?

Comment: @sth Out of... seven billion humans? :-)

Comment: @Laura "We want people to show off work they're proud of" but... do _people_ really want a special place on [so] for that? AFAIK, most people are more than happy with that "textarea". It's simple, and lets me showcase whatever I want. In-fact the `<!--summary` thing for the hover card is excellent too. [so] profiles can already link to the corresponding careers.so profile, where showcasing projects is a special feature. Maybe try to get more people to join careers, not just those who are desperately looking for a job?

Comment: @TimPost - I still got no mug or shirt after last week.  I thought these were shipped!

Answer (score 6):

> Following won’t exist until we have job openings on Team pages (more
>   on that below). Once we do, following (which is probably not the best
>   name for this feature) will only be used to be notified of new
>   openings. We don’t have further plans around following at this time.

Let's see, a feature that will only be used for notification of new job openings...

Am I crazy, or is it really not worth spending time thinking about what to name this very basic feature? We already have notification preferences, just put it there (please excuse the hackish devtools mockup):

[image: An added "Teams" section in /users/preferences/userid with options to receive inbox and email notifications for team jobs]

If it's really important that this be discoverable from within a Teams page and/or when signing up for Teams, just instruct users to [follow a link to their preferences page to manage Teams notifications](http://www.example.com).

The only thing this doesn't do is let you get notifications from some Teams and not others. You could just as easily do that by adding another section at the same level as "Preferences" (what are these sub-tab things called? drawers, maybe?). throw it into "Applications", etc.

Comment: Yep, this is indeed pretty much what "following" was meant to be (with a tweak that you'd want to know about jobs available in *other* teams)!

Comment: Given that your wording in the proposed screenshot is "your Teams", one of us has entirely misunderstood the feature.

Comment: @Ben: Most concrete quote I can pull up from the Android app in an elevator is from the announcement: * Eventually we will also add a list of teams you’re a member of onto your profile, but it won’t be in the beta.*

Answer (score 3):

While reading through the [previous post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307513/the-power-of-teams-a-proposed-expansion-of-stack-overflow), I thought that this proposal could be of value to StackOverflow except for just one area where it lacks

You mentioned that

> Here’s why we’re excited about teams:
>
> - Teams allow for a new kind of Q&A that wouldn’t be allowed right now
> - Teams let you show off more of what you do professionally
> - Teams help you hire developers or recruit for your open source project

Exploring all these one by one,

#### Teams help you hire developers or recruit for your open source project

I think this is a good feature for those who use SO Careers to have. This would just serve the purpose of giving you the information about people currently involved in a company/project which may make you want to join that project, just like the current system where your profile may make a company want to hire you.

I don't think this proposal will cause problems for users who want to use just the Q&A feature any more than existence of SO Careers does.

#### Teams let you show off more of what you do professionally

I think this would be a perfectly legitimate extension to the current system where users' profiles show off their

- reputation
- badges
- an "about me"
- all their questions and answers

and somewhat useful stats such as

- member for [duration]
- [number of] profile views
- last seen [x minutes ago]
- visited x days, y consecutive

Maybe a team page could show a meaningful aggregate of all this information, and a team "about me".

This just adds more information about the people that are involved in Q&A on StackOverflow and I don't think this generates any noise.

In fact, These might even work to motivate people to partake in Q&A like reputation and badges currently do.

---

But there is one area where this **proposal lacks**, which is the abuse of SO Q&A system.

#### It introduces a new kind of Q&A.

> We’re looking to provide a place for questions such as:
>
> - "How does [Company X] run PostgreSQL at an enterprise scale?"
> - "What's a typical budget for [Company Y] when they upgrade their data centers?", or
> - "How does [Company Z] keep their distributed team working together even though they’re spread across multiple time zones?"

I think that the concept of asking a personal question to a person or a bunch of persons is foreign for StackOverflow where questions that are allowed are supposed to be answerable by anyone with knowledge in that domain.

For example, the current SO way is to ask that question like

> How do I run PostgreSQL at an enterprise scale with my specific requirements that are included in the question?

And one of the answers from a representative of team that belongs to [Company X] could be

> At [Company X], we doodled foobar so that baz does not overflow in PostgreSQL and thus achieved enterprise scale

along with other answers from other experts in that domain.

So perhaps one way that the teams feature could help SO Q&A is by contributing to the **discoverablitiy problem*** - a team may want to subscribe to a specific tag, or may be summoned by a @mention when a question regarding intricate implementation details about a project comes up.

One specific case that I do know that this feature may help is the [openshift tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openshift).
openshift is a PaaS service which closed down their forums and recommended all their users to ask questions on SO instead, with the `openshift` tag.

Maybe cases like these may want to form support teams on SO and subscribe to all the questions tagged about their service and answer them quickly to show off the badges and stats earned by their support team's page as a proof of quality of the support that they offer to developers.

Other than this, like many have pointed out, if the teams are going to have their own "Team Timeline" where anyone can "post" questions to which they can "reply", then that is a bit social network-y,
Because unlike Q&A that SO is built on, this is more of a Ask Me Anything kind of thing, which I'm not saying is bad, but is just foreign to what SO currently is and is more fitting on social networks.

---

* See [How do active answerers find questions to answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254592/how-do-active-answerers-find-questions-to-answer) and [Help build a good "Find The Next Question To Answer" query](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289702/help-build-a-good-find-the-next-question-to-answer-query)

Answer (score -20):

## Keep an option for Pairs

That could be a very cool boost for the  by mentorship and personal development as a software engineer, currently receiving too little attention in the SD world in general. If a nice tool was there and maybe support by others would somehow add to this it might be more likely that more people get incentivized to act as mentors. It would also be nice to see an option for people to move from Teams to Teams as Pairs.

Comment: I don't think this proposal _excludes_ pairs, but I think we can do something better for a mentoring relationship. In particular, I'm working on a [mentoring system](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/262292/1438) that would allow mentors to monitor the progress of their mentees while also giving them a small bonus to get started. (My thinking on the details of mentoring has changed somewhat, but this is the basic outline.)