# The Teams Private Beta is Starting

Tags: discussion, old-teams

The [Teams private beta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308601/the-goal-of-teams-our-follow-up-to-your-questions) is starting now! Here’s what [a Team page](https://stackoverflow.com/teams/1/stack-overflow) looks like:

[image: Stack Overflow Team Page]

### What’s Happening Now?

#### For Users That Are Enrolled in the Beta:

If you are enrolled in the beta, you should have received (or will shortly receive) an email with instructions regarding how to create your Team. You will be able to create your own Teams, and invite other users to them.

#### For Users That Aren’t Enrolled in the Beta:

If you aren’t enrolled in the beta, you can still browse the Teams beta members have created (at [stackoverflow.com/teams](https://stackoverflow.com/teams)), and accept invitations to join a Team.

Please note that we will be letting in more users in over time, so if you’d like to try out Teams, there’s still time to sign up! [Use this form to register](http://goo.gl/forms/nosBAAcbvG).

### Questions and Answers

(We’ll update this section as more questions come up)

#### What should my Team be about?

We encourage you to create Teams that are primarily about programming-related topics.

We’d rather not create too many rules before the private beta has started, but broadly speaking, **we’d like Teams to be primarily about contributions to one or multiple software projects or ecosystems. We mean both those terms in the broadest sense possible:**

- Your Team’s contributions do not need to be code. E.g. standards, specifications, docs, designs, tutorials, trainings, data science, etc. are all in scope.
- The software projects your Team contributes to do not have to be accessible to other users. E.g. closed-source software, web applications, internal software, etc. are all in scope.

In other words: companies, open-source projects, user groups, consultancies, tutorial authors, standards groups, etc. are all welcome on Teams. However, interest groups (e.g. "Fans of Linus Torvalds") and Teams that form primarily around non-programming topics (e.g. “Sci-Fi writers on Stack Overflow”) are not.

*Of course, we expect to refine  those policies as the beta progresses (or maybe even completely change them!)... That’s what a beta is for. Let us know if you have any doubts or questions.*

#### What content should go on Team pages?

Provided your Team meets the general guidelines laid out above, you’re encouraged to expand on how your Team contributes to its projects or ecosystem in your Team content. You can talk about your Team’s projects, culture, tools, work environment, etc.

Of course, keep it civil: the ["Be Nice" policy](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) applies on Team pages too.

#### How do invitations work?

After creating a Team, invite others by sharing the Team’s invitation link (click on "Invite Others" next to “Members” to reveal it). **Users you invite do not need to be enrolled in the beta to accept your invitation.**

For the time being, anyone that joins your Team can:

- Edit the Team’s description and links (to your website, Github, Twitter)
- Invite new members and remove existing ones
- Delete the Team (other members can undelete it)

So, make sure you keep your invitation link safe, and regenerate it if it’s compromised!

#### How do I access my Team after creating it?

- Once you join a Team, it will be linked from your public profile, so that you can go back to it, and so that other users can learn more about the Teams you are a member of.
- You can browse all teams at https://stackoverflow.com/teams. This page isn’t currently linked through site navigation, but it soon will be.

#### Can I create a 1-person Team?

Provided you meet the guideline above, of course (e.g. you’re developing an app or open-source project on your own, you run your own consultancy, etc.).

#### Can I create as many Teams as I want?

During the private beta, the number of Teams you can create is limited to 5, but note that this isn’t a hard-and-fast number, and that we’re open to increasing it if needed (so let us know if you feel you need more!). This limit will most likely go away once the private beta is over.

#### How is moderation going to work?

Throughout the private beta, we (i.e. the Stack Overflow team) will be moderating Teams. We plan to eventually transition moderation to the community.

#### How long will the private beta period last?

We expect the private beta period to last 1 to 2 months. Once the private beta is over, we’ll launch a public beta period (which might last for about as long, or longer), and where the limitations on creating a Team will be lifted.

### Providing Feedback

Beta member or not, your feedback is welcome! To share your feedback, just [create a meta post using the teams tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?tags=teams).

### Changelog

We will be updating this post throughout the beta with updates on Teams functionality, so check back often!

Comment: Awesome! Really looking forward to finally trying this out.

Comment: Moderator meagar created [a chatroom for Teams testing](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94632/stack-overflow-teams) if anyone wishes for such a thing.

Comment: Again sorry to open this up again, what exactly does this serve?  I looked over it and went to several team pages where I read an about section, I see some twitter / website links, and some profile pics but not much else.  What is this trying to solve?  I see nothing of interest, nor is there anything for me to do besides just look at it.  It's rather dull and boring and again nothing jumps out at me and says "wow what an awesome feature".  No, rather I see some basic information, some people, and some urls.  What gives????  What is the purpose of this and what does it help me solve?

Comment: @JonH Right now Teams are basically just decoration on your profile. There's more features coming though.

Comment: Is there any expectation on how soon one would hear back after registering to join the beta, regardless if they were accepted or rejected?

Comment: Giving the Moderation ability to Every team member really puts me off and I almost don't want to invite anybody until I get that feature. It makes a lot of situations a lot complex and not necessarily IMHO.

Comment: This all smells of exclusivity, which is the complete opposite of what I feel Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange is about. That is, helping each other on an individual basis. A nicely setup, democratic, free for all.