# Unable to view "Pending Requests" after deleting (and un-deleting) a team

Tags: bug, status-completed, old-teams

Our team ([SOCVR](https://stackoverflow.com/teams/11/socvr)) was recently deleted and un-deleted by accident; following this incident we are no longer able to view the "Pending Requests" tab as we are shown the generic "Oops! Something Bad Happened!" error page. We are still able to access the "History" tab though.

I've attempted to reproduce this bug by creating a [test team](https://stackoverflow.com/teams/325/testy-mctesttests-team-for-testing) and deleting/un-deleting it, so far without success.

Comment: What is that nice "Teams" beta? Where can I read more about it?

Comment: @AlonEitan [here it is](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309716/the-teams-private-beta-is-starting)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been fixed and will go out in the next deployment.

Interesting bug. The issue was that the user that requested the deletion of the team, also deleted themselves afterwards. This meant that the page could not find their role to display anymore and would panic.

I've since fixed it to use "*former member*" for all such users.

Comment: Just an aside... if a moderator chooses "delete team" (I've no reason to do so and don't want to experiment) - does it go to vote (as I can see on the history of the team related to this question) or is it immediate/binding like other mod actions?

Comment: @JonClements for now, mods have no special powers on teams