# Link teams page to company profile on Careers

Tags: discussion, status-planned, old-teams

The company I work for has multiple teams at various clients, as well as internal project teams. The problem (with regards to the new teams feature) is that we don't all use the same tech stack or use the same methodologies as the client based teams are expected to fully integrate with the clients working environment and practices, as such we can't all fall under one team.

The only potential way I can see to "relate" the teams is to do something like this:

- Each team creates a name with a similar name E.G:

  - BSG - Client A Team
  - BSG - Client B Team
  - BSG - Internal Product Team

I thought it could potentially make sense that we link up the Careers page even if its just another box where we can add a link to a the careers page for Companies that have active teams/members on StackOverflow

[image]

**Disclaimer:** I guess I could argue the inverse, being that it's much of a muchness if I link it to the careers page / our companies personal website... but I do think there is a difference in that the Careers page still falls under the <strike>StackExchange</strike> StackOverflow umbrella.

Comment: This question is about the *old* Teams feature, which has been deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do have plans to eventually let you group Teams in organizations (in your example, you'd have a "BSG" organization).

Eventually, you should also be able to tie those organizations to companies in Careers in order to e.g. advertise an opening directly on a Teams's page (this is something we mentioned in [The Goal of Teams: Our Follow-Up to Your Questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308601/the-goal-of-teams-our-follow-up-to-your-questions)).