# Stack Overflow Teams Sign-up?

Tags: support, old-teams

Following [The Goal of Teams: Our Follow-Up to Your Questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308601/the-goal-of-teams-our-follow-up-to-your-questions) I wanted to create a Team page for the Hibernate team (hibernate.org).  So I followed the instructions in that post and submitted the linked form.  However, over a week later I still have not heard anything back about the request.

Is there something else I need to do?

How long should I expect to wait to hear something back in regards to the Team request?

P.S. It might be a good idea to mention something about further steps, expected wait-time, etc on the sign-up form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've added your user to the beta - you should be able to create a team now by going to `/teams` on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Is asking a question on Meta the appropriate way to get added to the beta? I submitted a request to join a couple weeks ago but haven't heard back.