# When/how should you request an "official response" to a popular feature request?

Tags: support

If you have a highly-upvoted feature request (e.g. a score of 100+), is it appropriate to request an "official" response on whether it'll be implemented or not? If so, how do you do it?

Comment: You just wait another 6-8 years ;-)

Comment: We don't have a [guaranteed pipeline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263662/can-we-have-a-guaranteed-pipeline-for-responses-from-stack-exchange) to get a response.

Comment: Can someone explain the downvotes? Downvote as in "no, you shouldn't ask"?

Comment: @EJoshuaS You know about dv's at meta? They're just given away like candy here.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yes - they're a little ambiguous, too. For feature requests, upvotes/downvotes clearly mean "I agree" or "I disagree," it's a little more ambiguous what downvotes on support questions mean.

Comment: See also: [Feature requests and bugs need more feedback from Stack Overflow developers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307614/feature-requests-and-bugs-need-more-feedback-from-stack-overflow-developers)

Comment: @EJoshuaS Most likely lack of research, as with any question on the site.

Comment: @Servy It's not clear how you'd research the topic (unless there's something else on Meta that already answers this)

Comment: @EJoshuaS "(unless there's something else on Meta that already answers this)" The fact that you don't know means you didn't do your research.  You just assumed (incorrectly) that nobody else could have possibly ever asked the question.  You assume incorrectly.

Comment: @bluefeet I do understand that there's no guaranteed feedback, but it would be nice if heavily upvoted feature suggestions would get some kind of feedback. For example, I recently had a [feature request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348560/reduce-the-number-of-votes-required-to-close-a-question-to-4) earn a score of 102 but it didn't receive any response.